# What's the time, chap?

Tags: code-golf, date

I honestly cannot believe that this is not a question yet on Code Golf, but....

Print the local time (with a.m. or p.m.) as a string to the console, preceded by "It's ".

Example:

```
Run code....
```

**Output:**

```
It's 12:32p.m.
```

Shortest code wins.

Code away!

#### Leaderboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=57552,OVERRIDE_USER=42854;function answersUrl(e){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Are builtins allowed?

Comment: @UndefinedFunction - yes, you can use builtins

Comment: What is the output format? Does it matter?

Comment: @mbomb007 - see edit

Comment: No, I mean, should it be `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss UTC` or does that date format not matter?

Comment: @mbomb007 - it should be hh:mm a.m./p.m.

Comment: in what way is this [tag:kolmogorov-complexity]

Comment: I really wanted to put up an answer that prints `It's beer o'clock`, but I resisted.

Comment: I expect a Pyth or CodeJam answer of no more than one byte at some point!

Comment: Can we use `12:32 PM` or `12:32PM`? Instead of `12:32p.m.`?

Comment: Is it 02:32 or 2:32 if it's less than 10:00?

Comment: @StewieGriffin - no. You must use p.m or a.m. For your second comment: it doesn't matter. Whichever you want

Comment: Can we use 24 hour notation?  e.g.  23:00p.m.

Comment: @LukStorms - no. It should be like 11:00p.m. not 23p.m. However, if many people already answered with 24 hour notation already, I might have to change the rule. Anyhow, that's no the case I think.

Comment: This is one of the rare questions where a CJam answer is not on the top.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Bash, <s>39</s> 33 bytes

```
date "+It's %I:%M%P."|sed s/m/.m/
```

Wasted a bunch of chars because the spec requires `a.m.` or `p.m.` while `date` outputs `am` or `pm`. Thanks to @DigitalTrauma for saving 6 bytes!

This might not be very portable. It works on Ubuntu 15.04.

A solution that uses essentially the same method in Ruby<s>, which is surprisingly the exact same length</s>:

### Ruby, 39 bytes

```
$><<`date "+It's %I:%M%P"`[0..-3]+'.m.'
```

Comment: `%P` gives me uppercase AM or PM. I'm on a mac if it makes a difference.

Comment: @flodel Works On My Machine™. On Ubuntu 15.04, `%P` gives lowercase, and `%p` gives uppercase (which is a bit... unintuitive).

Comment: GNU `date` (on Linux et al.) and *BSD `date` (where OSX is one BSD variant) have wildly different options and behaviors when you venture outside of the feature set specified by POSIX.  So perhaps this answer should specifically mention Bash on Linux. (That goes for `sed` too; but this particular invocation is firmly within the safe and portable feature set.)

Comment: On my machine (zsh or bash on Linux) it prints "It's 04:17." when the time is 16:17. No "a.m." or "p.m."

Comment: `echo -e "It's $(date +%I:%M%P)\b.m."` - instead of `sed` uses backspace. Doesn't look like a separate answer to me. Also I don't have any am/pm but I think it's because of locale.

Comment: @aragaer That's actually 36 bytes. You can shave off a char by using backticks instead of `$()`, but it's still longer than my version. Interesting idea though!

Comment: Aww, used flawed method to count characters... My bad.

Comment: You can save a byte by using Bash + [rs](https://github.com/kirbyfan64/rs): `date "+It's %I:%M%P."|rs.py m/.m` (yes, this is a shameless plug to get an answer with rs that I didn't write).

Comment: I find on my Debian system, that `%P` (or `%p`) gives the abbreviation with dots in, if `LC_TIME` is set to `es_CR`.  So I've got `LC_ALL=es_CR date "+It's %-I:%M%p"` for 34, but if you can count the locale as part of the environment, then it goes down to 21 bytes.  (Found using `for i in $(locale -a); do LC_ALL=$i date "+$i: It's %-I:%M%P" | fgrep .m.; done`, of course).

Answer (score 13):

## AppleScript, 198

Because AppleScript.  Because why not:

```
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {":"," "}
set d to (current date)'s time string's every text item
"It's "&d's item 1&":"&d's item 2&string id ((d's item 4's first character's id)+32)&".m."
```

That was painful.

Comment: AppleScript is the new Java.

Answer (score 8):

## PHP, <s>35</s> 33 bytes

Using the wrong tool for the job!

```
It's <?=trim(date('h:ia'),m)?>.m.
```

It simply removes the `m` at the end of `am` or `pm`, to allow to add the dots. The date comes as `00:00am`, and with `trim` it becomes `00:00a`.

---

**Old answer (PHP 5.4+ only):**

```
It's <?=date('h:i'),date(a)[0]?>.m.
```

This works because you can de-reference a value returned from a function. This isn't possible in PHP5.3 or older.

Comment: Ah, clever! You beat my php answer

Comment: @DankMemes It took me quite a while. And lots of experimenting.

Comment: You used a string literal without quotes. Is it OK to use those without the `@` operator  and assume people will run it with `error_reporting(0)`?

Comment: @DankMemes You can indirectly assume that error reporting is disabled. Here's a good read: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1655/14732

Answer (score 5):

### Visual Basic 6 / VBA, <del>42</del> 41 bytes

```vb
MsgBox"It's "&Format(Now,"h:mma/p")&".m."
```

Using `MsgBox`, as VB6 does not have a console (unless you intercept the linking, link as a console executable, use some Windows API hacks, and do some other *dodgy* stuff).

Comment: Why don't you just replace `m` by `.m.`?
_i.e._ `Debug.Print Replace(Format(Now,"hh:mm am/pm"),"m",".m.")`

Comment: Nice @toothbrush, I sort of expected this to be a one-byte solution in CJam ;)

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, <s>74</s> <s>54</s> 43 bytes

```julia
print(strftime("It's %I:%M%P\b.m.",time()))
```

You can [try it online](http://goo.gl/4ZU9F8)!

The `time()` function returns the current time. When passed to `strftime` with the format `%I:%M%P`, this results in `HH:MMam/pm`, where the hours are per a 12-hour clock. We back up one character with `\b` to remove the `m`, leaving a trailing `a` or `p`, then tack `.m.` onto the end.

Saved **31 bytes** thanks to Glen O!

Comment: Might I suggest this? `print("It's ",strftime("%r%P",time())[[1:5,12]],".m.")` - uses `%P` to add the lowercase am/pm, to avoid the comparison and the split command.

Comment: No problems regarding the help. And don't talk yourself down - you do fine. I just get enjoyment out of trying to squeeze every last byte out of the code. In this case, I just figured that trying to bypass the split command and the conditional statement would be beneficial, and then went looking at the functions you used. I probably wouldn't have found strftime myself (I'd have tried to extract the time directly from `time()`)

Comment: @GlenO If you get enjoyment out of squeezing every last byte out of code, PPCG is certainly the right place for you!

Comment: Incidentally, I've found a way to squeeze a few more bytes out: `print(strftime("It's %I:%M%P",time())[1:11],".m.")`

Comment: Actually, even better: `print(strftime("It's %I:%M%P\b.m.",time()))`

Comment: @GlenO That's a great solution, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## R, <s>68</s> ,<s>59</s> <s>62</s> <s>60</s> 55

```
cat("It's",sub("m",".m",format(Sys.time(),"%I:%M%P.")))
```

(Thanks to @Alex.A. and @flodel for the comments) Takes the current system time (`Sys.time()`), formats it correctly using `%I:%M%P` combination, adds a dot at the end, and replaces the `m` with `.m.`.

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, <s>38</s> 36 bytes

```
s["It's "|%J.d6K12K\:.d7?gJK\p\a".m.
```

Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Jakube!

Comment: @Sp3000 On the online interpreter or locally?

Comment: @Sp3000 I think I know the issue. It's giving the time of the location of the Pyth server, and I'm not handling midnight correctly. Hold on...

Comment: @Sp3000 Fixed!!!

Comment: You're almost beating my PHP answer and Doorknob's Bash answer!

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica <s>49 90 92 90</s> 84 bytes

-6 bytes thanks to user202729

The solution is straightforward, but a bit wordy, in Mathematica.

```
(d=DateString)@{"It's ","Hour12",":","Minute"}<>(d@"AMPM"/."AM"->"a.m."/."PM"->"p.m‌ .")
```

Comment: (Although this post is quite old) `StringReplace` can be eliminated, save 6 bytes. `(d=DateString)@{"It's ","Hour12",":","Minute"}<>d@"AMPM"/."AM"->"a.m."/."PM"->"p.m."`

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 135 bytes

```
import Data.Time.Format
import Data.Time.LocalTime
main=getZonedTime>>=putStr.(++".m.").init.formatTime defaultTimeLocale"It's %I:%M%P"
```

I found a much more amusing `main` that's five bytes longer:

```
getZonedTime>>=putStr.formatTime(TimeLocale[][]("a","p")""""""""[])"It's %I:%M%P.m."
```

Or 66 bytes on Unix:

```
import System.Cmd;main=system"date \"+It's %I:%M%P.\"|sed s/m/.m/"
```

Answer (score 3):

## Perl 5, 74 bytes

A small showcase of how the variables are evaluated from right to left.

```
($s,$m,$h)=localtime;printf"It's %d:%02d%s.m.",$h<13?$h:$h%12,$m,$h<12?a:p
```

#### Using POSIX: 80 bytes

```
use POSIX;$_=strftime"It's %I:%Mx.m.",@_=localtime;$x=$_[1]<13?a:p;s/x/$x/;print
```

#### Using POSIX with time locale dependence & switches :  54 bytes (48 + 6)

```
$_=strftime"It's %I:%M%P",localtime;s/m/.m./;say
```

**Test**

```
$ export LC_TIME="en_DK.UTF-8"
$ perl -MPOSIX -M5.01 whatsthetimechap.pl
It's 3:09p.m.
```

Comment: You can save some bytes on your POSIX solutions by using `-MPOSIX` instead of `use POSIX;`, dropping the parens in your call to `strftime`, and replacing `print` with `say` ([`-M5.010` is free](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/274/31388)). Which brings your last solution down to 54 bytes!

Comment: Thanks. I used your advice for the shortest POSIX solution.

Comment: You still have to count `-MPOSIX` (6 bytes), but you can save 2 bytes by dropping the parentheses: `$_=strftime"It's %I:%M%P",localtime;`. That gives 54 bytes total, which is still better than my 57-byte POSIX solution. Well done!

Comment: Heh, thanks again for rescuing a few bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## MATLAB, 59 bytes

```
disp(sprintf('It''s%s\b.m.',lower(datestr(now,'HH:MMam'))))
```

> It's 5:38p.m.

If it's allowed to have a whitespace between time and a.m./p.m., then it could be as low as **52 bytes**:

```
disp(sprintf('It''s%s\b.m.',lower(datestr(now,16))))
```

> It's 5:39 p.m.

Comment: I think the output must be `05:38p.m.`

Comment: According to OP's comment, the leading zero doesn't matter.

Comment: You're right. Here, have my upvote!

Comment: Nice! Didn't know I could use `\b` like that... You need an extra space btw.

Answer (score 3):

## Perl 5.10+, <s>58</s> 62 bytes

```
localtime=~/(..)(:..)/;say"It's ",$1%12||12,$2,$1>11?p:a,".m."
```

Must be run with the `-M5.010` command line flag to get `say`.

I didn't account for a couple of edge cases in my original solution (namely, `00:**` and `12:**`); fixed at a cost of 4 additional bytes.

### How it works

In scalar context, [`localtime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) returns a string like this:

```
Sat Sep 12 03:13:22 2015
```

The minutes field is already zero-padded, which saves some bytes (in list context, `localtime` returns numbers instead of strings, so you have to pad them yourself).

Here it is ungolfed:

```
localtime=~/(..)(:..)/;  # Store hour in $1 and minutes in $2
say"It's ",              # Print "It's " followed by...
   $1%12||12,            # hour in 12-hour format
   $2,                   # minutes
   $1>11?p:a,            # "p" if hour > 11, otherwise "a"
   ".m."'                # ".m."
```

---

## Perl 5.14+, 57 bytes

(Just for fun, since it stretches the rules a bit.)

```
say"It's ",(strftime"%l:%M%P",localtime)=~s/m/.m./r
```

51 bytes + 6 bytes for `-MPOSIX`. Must also be run with the `-M5.010` command line flag to get `say`.

This solution is dependent on your locale, so will not work on all systems. It also uses the POSIX module, which might be stretching the definition of a "built-in", even though it is a core module.

Perl 5.14+ is required for the non-destructive `r` modifier to the substitution operator. An equivalent solution that works on 5.10+ is:

```
$_=strftime"%l:%M%P",localtime;chop;say"It's $_.m."
```

This is also 57 bytes (51 bytes + 6 bytes for `-MPOSIX`).

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, 40 bytes

```
"It's "et3=CmdCe|\'p'a?':et4=s2Ue[@".m."
```

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22It's%20%22et3%3DCmdCe%7C%5C'p'a%3F'%3Aet4%3Ds2Ue%5B%40%22.m.%22).

#### How it works

```
"It's " e# Push that string.
et3=    e# Select the fourth element of the date/time array (hours).
Cmd     e# Push quotient and remainder of the hour divided by 12.
Ce|     e# Logical OR with 12 to map 0 to 12.
\'p'a?  e# Select 'p' if the quotient is 1 and 'a' if it is 0.
':      e# Push that character.
et4=    e# Select the fifth element of the date/time array (minutes).
s2Ue[   e# Cast to string and left-pad with zeroes to a length of 2.
@".m."  e# Rotate 'a' or 'p' on top of the stack and push ".m.".
```

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL (2012+), <s>67</s> 65 bytes

SQL Server 2012 finally gave us a reasonable formatting function for dates.  I still had to muck around with the AM/PM to get the format right though.

```
PRINT 'It''s '+LOWER(STUFF(FORMAT(GETDATE(),'hh:mmtt.'),7,0,'.'))
```

In previous versions it would have needed something like this (93 bytes)

```
PRINT'It''s'+LOWER(STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),109),15),6,7,''),8,0,'.'))+'.'
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 49 bytes

If only it were `am/pm` instead of `a.m./p.m.`...

```
It's <?=@preg_replace(~Ð¤ž’¢Ð,~ÛÏÑ,date(~˜Å–ž));
```

I used a lot of nasty bytes to save a bit of length so here's the hex:

```
00000000: 49 74 27 73 20 3C 3F 3D - 40 70 72 65 67 5F 72 65 |It's <?=@preg_re|
00000010: 70 6C 61 63 65 28 7E D0 - A4 9E 92 8F A2 D0 2C 7E |place(~       ,~|
00000020: DB CF D1 2C 64 61 74 65 - 28 7E 98 C5 96 9E 29 29 |   ,date(~    ))|
00000030: 3B                      -                         |;|
00000031;
```

Readable version:

```
It's <?=preg_replace("/[amp]/", "$0.", date("g:ia"));
```

Answer (score 2):

## SQL (PostgreSQL), <s>42</s> 41 bytes

Another SQL variant, however this one is in a query.

```
select to_char(now(),'"It''s" HH:MIa.m.')
```

As a note either p.m. or a.m. works to get the am/pm part.  The formatting options in PostgreSQL are really quite flexible.
Thanks to @manatwork for the tip to move the `it's` into the format string.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/3173/0)

Comment: So you need to adjust am/pm it manually?

Comment: @DavidArenburg, no it gets it right with either ... but I had to check it out, because it didn't seem right.  If you add `+ time '12:00'` after the `now()` in SQLFiddle it should change the am/pm.

Comment: 1 character shorter: `select to_char(now(),'"It''s" HH:MIa.m.')`

Comment: @manatwork, very nice thanks.  I wouldn't have thought of trying that.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, 103 bytes

Javascript executed from the console.

```
d="It's "+new Date().toLocaleTimeString();l=d.length;d.slice(0,l-6)+d.slice(-2,l-1).toLowerCase()+'.m.'
```

## C#, 63 bytes

C# executed from the immediate window.

```
?"It's "+System.DateTime.Now.ToString("h:MMt").ToLower()+".m.";
```

Comment: Also runs as F# ;)

Comment: You don't need to calculate `d.length`, you could just write `-n` and it will calculate from the end, just an FYI. `d="It's "+new Date().toLocaleTimeString();d.slice(0,-6)+d.slice(-2,-1).toLowerCase()+'.m.'` 90 bytes. And you can save one byte by moving the `"It's "` string. And a few bytes from a little string shortcut in there. `d=new Date().toLocaleTimeString();"It's "+d.slice(0,5)+d[9].toLowerCase()+'.m.'` 79 bytes.

Comment: And if the answer needs to be locale-independent (as some have posted), just use `toLocaleTimeString("en-US")` 86 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## C, <strike>103</strike> 94 bytes

```
int main(){time_t r;char b[80];time(&r);strftime(b,80,"It's %I:%M %p",localtime(&r));puts(b);}
```

**Ungolfed**

```
int main()
{
  time_t r;
  char b[80];  
  time(&r);
  strftime(b,80,"It's %I:%M %p",localtime(&r));
  puts(b);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 41 bytes

`It's <?=strtr(date('g:ia'),['m'=>'.m.']);`

First time I've played this.  Not sure if I'm supposed to update/edit the previous PHP answer (49 bytes) or just add my own...

Comment: You should **always** add your own. You only comment on someone's answer if you see something that can save them a few bytes. But other than that, nice answer!

Comment: By the way, you can write `[m=>'.m.']`, which saves 2 bytes. (Warnings can be ignored, so, don't worry about them.)

Answer (score 2):

## C, 154 bytes

```
#include <time.h>
#define l localtime(&r)
main(){time_t r=time(0);printf("It's %02i:%02i%c.m.",(l->tm_hour+11)%12+1,l->tm_min,(l->tm_hour>=12)?'p':'a');}
```

In contrast to the other C answer, this one uses the correct "a.m."/"p.m." format.  The other poster omitted `#include <time.h>` – if your compiler allows this, we get down to 136 bytes.  Which one should we count?

Comment: You're right, in fact all I got was a warning – I got it confused with an error from trying to do without `time.h`. Editing.

Answer (score 2):

## Bash, 44 characters

Pure Bash, just shell builtins, no ***utils.

```bash
printf -vt "It's %(%I:%M%P)T"
echo ${t%m}.m.
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ printf -vt "It's %(%I:%M%P)T";echo ${t%m}.m.
It's 01:04p.m.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Powershell, 49 bytes

```
"It's {0:hh:mm}$("ap"[($d=date).hour/23]).m."-f$d
```

`(date).hour/23` seems to work as an index for `"ap"` because it rounds to `0` for hours less than 12 and `1` for 12 and above.

Comment: Should be able to golf off a few characters by instead treating the "p"/"a" as string turned into an implicit char-array -- 51 bytes -- `"It's $(date -f hh:mm)$("pa"[(date).hour-lt12]).m."`

Comment: Your latest `"{0:hh:mm}$("ap"[($d=date).hour/23]).m."-f$d` misses the `It's ` at the beginning. If you tack that onto the front, it's the same 49 bytes as `"It's $((date -f hh:mm)+"ap"[(date).hour/23]).m."`

Comment: My bad. I've fixed it. Anyway, this version is more "correct", as it only makes a single call to `date`

Comment: For what it's worth, I stumbled across the following while researching something else. Apparently `[datetime]` casts are [always en-US](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2009/01/13/datetime-casts-are-language-primitives/). That means something like this `"It's $(("{0:h:mmt}"-f[datetime](date)).ToLower()).m."` is possible ... which, granted, is 54 bytes and longer than your current solution, but still an interesting quirk of the language.

Comment: @TimmyD Interesting, but it seems it's only [casting to DateTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359053/why-does-powershell-always-use-us-culture-when-casting-to-datetime) that's en-US, not formatting.

Answer (score 2):

## Locale-dependent

For browser environments that have the locale set to `en-CA` or any locale that outputs a 12-hour time by default:

### CoffeeScript, 81 bytes

```coffee
alert "It's #{(x=(new Date).toLocaleTimeString().toLowerCase())[..4]} #{x[9]}.m."
```

### JavaScript (ES5), 90 bytes

```js
alert("It's "+(x=(new Date).toLocaleTimeString().toLowerCase()).slice(0,5)+' '+x[9]+".m.")
```

## Locale-independent

### CoffeeScript, <s>113</s> 96 bytes

```coffee
alert "It's #{(h=(d=new Date).getHours())%12}:#{('0'+d.getMinutes())[-2..]} #{'ap'[+(h>11)]}.m."
```

Previous:

This one works in all browser environments regardless of locale. Requires Chrome 24+, Firefox 29+, IE 11+, Opera 15+ or any derivatives of such. Does not work in Safari. See [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat).

```coffee
alert "It's #{new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en',{hour:f='2-digit',minute:f}).format(new Date).toLowerCase()[..-2]}.m."
```

Comment: The javascript answer gave me: `It's 2:59: m.m.`

Comment: @Mwr247 Which locale is your browser in?

Comment: @rinkattendant6 My locale is `en-US`

Answer (score 2):

### **Swift - <strike>124</strike> 102 bytes**

```
import Cocoa
var f=NSDateFormatter()
f.dateFormat="hh:mma"
print("It's \(f.stringFromDate(NSDate()))")
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>117</s> <s>87</s> 79 bytes

```python
from datetime import*
print(datetime.now().strftime("It's %I:%M%P")[:-1]+".m.")
```

This gets the hours and minutes from a 12-hour clock using the format `%I:%M`, plus `am` or `pm` using `%P`. We then select everything but the last `m` and append `.m.`.

Saved a few bytes thanks to Ruth Franklin!

Comment: As you're only using `datetime` once, it's 6 bytes shorter to use `from datetime import*; h=datetime.now() ...`

Comment: @RuthFranklin Thanks for the suggestion! I also found a few other ways to shorten it.

Answer (score 1):

### Moonscript - 56 bytes

```
print "It's "..(os.date'%I:%M%p'\gsub 'M','.M.')\lower!
```

Unfortunately the Lua standard library only implements %p for uppercase AM/PM, so I have to call the method lower.

Answer (score 1):

## SpecBAS - 64 bytes

```
PRINT "It's ";LOW$(REPLACE$(TIME$(TIME,"h:mm p$"),"M",".M."))
```

The built-in `p$` of the time function returns AM or PM, so this then has to be formatted with `REPLACE$` to change it so it has a full stop before/after that letter.

Then the time output had to be converted to lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>75</s> <s>67</s> 66 bytes

```
import time;print"It's %s.m."%time.strftime("%I:%M%p")[:6].lower()
```

old version, 75 bytes

```
import time
t=time.strftime("%I:%M%p")
print"It's",t[:5]+t[5].lower()+".m."
```

old version, 75 bytes

```
import time
print"It's",time.strftime("%I:%M%p").lower().replace("m",".m.")
```

Comment: @AlexA. Not working in Python 2 [time.strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) at least under windows gives "ValueError: Invalid format string"

Comment: @AlexA Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32  
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.  
>>> import time;print"It's %s.m."%time.strftime("%I:%M%p")[:6].lower()  
It's 01:30p.m.`

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB, 66 bytes

```
['It''s' lower(datestr(now,'HH:MMam'))];disp([ans(1:end-1),'.m.'])
```

Displays:

```
It's 2:48p.m.
```

Answer (score 1):

## AutoIt, 73 bytes

Even though AutoIt is generally a verbose language, this is quite short (converts time from 24h format):

```
$h=@HOUR>12
ConsoleWrite("It's "&@HOUR-12*$h&":"&@MIN&($h?"p":"a")&".m.")
```

## [ß](https://github.com/minxomat/-S-), 56 bytes

```
H=@HOUR>12µ€"It's "&@HOUR-12*H&":"&@MIN&H?"p.m.":"a.m.")
```

Answer (score 1):

### Excel VBA, 33 bytes

```vb
?"It's "format(now,"h:ma/p")".m."
```

Related to [toothbrush's VBA6 solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/57556/40948), but written before I saw it, so I'm allowing myself to post it here.

Most of the code is perfectly explicit: *now* returns a system timestamp, *format* forces the timestamp to the desired format, whilst *It's* and *.m.* are just text strings.

I abused/took advantage of a few things here:

- Implicit concatenation : VBA assumes that when something is put next to a string that a concatenation operation is desired.
- Immediate window printing : This is why I don't claim this is a complete VBA solution, as it relies on being executed from inside an immediate window. The *?* replaces *debug.print* for Excel VBA in an immediate window. This is an obvious gain for VBA where most of the byte cost comes from descriptive/user-friendly function and method names. Toothbrush's solution for example calls *Msgbox* which is 5 bytes more expensive.
- Format abuse : based on Dopapp's comments in this puzzle, we don't need to have double-digit hours. I'm also not forcing double-digit minutes, which might be slightly against the rules of the game, but can easily be corrected by adding an extra *m* between *:* and *m*, but costs 1 byte more.

I might have missed some other tricks, but I think this is about as low as Excel VBA can go. From what I can see so far, I'm pretty surprised that it's scoring so well, but a lot of the very concise languages haven't been used yet...

Answer (score 1):

## x86-16 machine code, IBM PC DOS, <del>64</del> 62 bytes

**Binary:**

```
00000000: bf34 01b4 2ccd 218a c5d4 0c75 02b0 0ce8  .4..,.!....u....
00000010: 1400 478a c1e8 0e00 b870 0980 fd0c 7c01  ..G......p....|.
00000020: aaba 2f01 cd21 d40a 86c4 0530 30ab c349  ../..!.....00..I
00000030: 7427 7320 3030 3a30 3061 2e6d 2e24       t's 00:00a.m.$
```

Build and test using `xxd -r` with above.

**Listing:**

```
BF 0134     MOV  DI, OFFSET HH      ; DI point to hours in output string
B4 2C       MOV  AH, 2CH            ; DOS get time function 
CD 21       INT  21H                ; CH = hour, CL = minute 
8A C5       MOV  AL, CH             ; put hour into AL 
D4 0C       AAM  12                 ; AL = AL mod 12, ZF = (AL == 0) 
75 02       JNZ  NOT_12             ; is hour 0? 
B0 0C       MOV  AL, 12             ; if so, make it 12 
        NOT_12: 
E8 0126     CALL ACONV              ; ASCII convert AL to [DI] 
47          INC  DI                 ; skip ':' in output string 
8A C1       MOV  AL, CL             ; put minutes into AL 
E8 0126     CALL ACONV              ; ASCII convert AL to [DI]
B8 0970     MOV  AX, 0970H          ; AL = 'p', AH = 9 (DOS write string)
80 FD 0C    CMP  CH, 12             ; set up compare for 12 
7C 01       JL   OUTPUT             ; is hours > 11?
AA          STOSB                   ; if so, write 'p' to output string 
        OUTPUT: 
BA 012F     MOV  DX, OFFSET IT      ; beginning of output string 
CD 21       INT  21H                ; display output 
        ACONV: 
D4 0A       AAM                     ; BCD base 10 convert
86 C4       XCHG AL, AH             ; endian convert
05 3030     ADD  AX, '00'           ; ASCII convert 
AB          STOSW                   ; write to output string buffer 
C3          RET                     ; return to caller/DOS

        IT  DB  'It',27H,'s '
        HH  DB  '00:'
        MM  DB  '00'
        AP  DB  'a.m.$'
```

I had imagined this being shorter in my head when I started it, but alas.  No date "built-ins" at least!

Standalone PC DOS executable `TIMECHAP.COM` file.  Output to `STDOUT`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>39</s> 37 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
"It's "ža<12%>žb‚T‰J':ý„apža13@è….m.J
```

-2 bytes thanks to *@ovs*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fybNEvVhB6ei@RBtDI1W7o/uSHjXMCnnUsMFL3erw3kcN8xILgHKGxg6HVzxqWKaXq@f1/z8A)

**Explanation:**

```python
"It's "     # Push string "It's "
ža          # Push the current hours (24 format)
  <         # Decrease it by 1
   12%      # Modulo-12: (hours-1)%12
      >     # Increase it by 1: (hours-1)%12+1
            # (so if the hours was 0, it's now 12; the [1,11] remained the same)
žb‚         # Pair this with the current minutes
   T‰       # Get the divmod-10 of each
     J      # And join the two digits together to a single string
            # (`T‰J` is used to format the hours/minutes with a potential leading 0)
      ':ý  '# Join them together with ":" delimiter
„ap         # Push string "ap"
   ža       # Push the current hours again (24 format)
     13@    # Check if it's >= 13 (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
        è   # (0-based) index that into the "ap"
….m.        # Push string ".m."
J           # Join all strings on the stack together
            # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: I'd never noticed before but TIO seems to cache the output in the link too, since when I clicked on your link the time was wrong until I re-ran. Guess that makes sense because for most cases the output only changes with a code change. Learn something new everyday.

Comment: @640KB Yep. It's actually pretty useful for programs that run let's say 40 seconds. When someone else visits the same link, they don't have to wait 40 seconds to see the result if someone else has already run it prior. :)

Comment: [37 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fybNEvVhB6ei@RBtDI1W7o/uSHjXMCnnUsMFL3erw3kcN8xILgHKGxg6HVzxqWKaXq@f1/z8A) by using `(hours-1)%12+1` for calculating 12-hour hours.

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 58 bytes

-6 thanks to @ovs

```apl
⎕←∊'It is '(⍕h-12×12<h)':'(⍕5⌷⎕ts),'ap'[1+12<h←4⌷⎕ts]'.m.'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1Hf1EdtEx51dKl7lihkFiuoazzqnZqha2h0eLqhkU2GproVWMT0Uc92oNKSYk0d9cQC9WhDbZAsUKcJTCJWXS9XT/3/fwA)

Original:

```apl
∊'It is '((':',⍕5⌷⎕ts){⍵>12:∊(⍕(⍵-12))⍺'p'⋄∊(⍕⍵)⍺'a'}4⌷⎕ts)'.m.'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1Hf1EdtEx51dKl7lihkFiuoa2ioW6nrPOqdavqoZztQtqRYs/pR71Y7QyMroCoNoAQQb9U1NNLUfNS7S71A/VF3C1QCKA4WS1SvNYFrVtfL1VP//x8A)

Comment: [58 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1Hf1EdtEx51dKl7lihkFiuoazzqnZqha2h0eLqhkU2GproVWMT0Uc92oNKSYk0d9cQC9WhDbZAsUKcJTCJWXS9XT/3/fwA) as a full program without any dfns

Answer (score 0):

## PowerShell, 61 bytes

```
"It's "+(Get-Date -Format HH:mmtt).ToLower()-replace"m",".m."
```

My very first PowerShell experiecne // because my linux machine is in the other room.

**EDITED** to be culture-settings robust. Thanks to all commenters below, credit goes to @NeilD

Comment: This also depense on system setting. I don't get am or pm. (24:00 format)

Comment: Ouch. Ok I will fix it.

Comment: @TimmyD Format string `t` is culture-dependent and may return other characters than `a` or `p`, or an empty string for cultures that do not use am/pm designators.

Comment: @DankoDurbić Indeed you're correct. Mea culpa.

Comment: `"It's "+(Get-Date -Format HH:mmtt).ToLower()-replace"m",".m."` works for me (62 bytes)

Comment: That's 61 bytes. @NeilD

Answer (score 0):

## Octave, 75 bytes

```
disp(["It's " strrep(lower(strftime("%R%p",localtime(time()))),"m",".m.")])
```

Comment: This shoiws: `ans = ...`. A lot of MATLAB / Octave answers could be a lot shorter if that was legal.

Comment: @StewieGriffin Yes, that's true...

Comment: @AlexA. Of course. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

## Windows Batch, 113 bytes

```
@set h=%time:~0,2%&@set z=a&@if %h% gtr 11 set z=p&if %h% gtr 12 set /a h-=12
echo It's %h: =0%:%time:~3,2%%z%.m.
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 88

*Edit* Missing "It's"
*Edit 2* Fixed 0 instead of 12
*Edit 3* Added an output statement. I was trying to be in line with other JavaScript answers that I felt ugly, but rules are rules

Test in any EcmaScript 6 compliant browser console (works in Chrome and Firefox).

```js
alert(`It's ${1+((h=(d=new Date).getHours())+11)%12}:${d.getMinutes()+'ap'[h>11|0]}.m.`)

// With no ES6 features : 92

alert("It's "+(1+((h=(d=new Date).getHours())+11)%12)+':'+d.getMinutes()+'ap'[h>11|0]+'.m.')
```

Comment: This doesn't output leading 0:s if any number is below 10. F.e `It's 0:9a.m.`

Comment: @Jan indeed. That's not requested: see answer to @StewieGriffin's question: `You must use p.m or a.m. For your second comment: it doesn't matter. Whichever you want`

Comment: Talking about hours, yes. Regarding minutes, looking at another reply `It should be like 11:00p.m. not 23p.m.` I'd very much suspect it's required, but you could ask. Also noted another thing: `It's 12:32p.m.`, so not `0:32p.m.`

Comment: My first comment was from the console output of running your script.

Comment: @Jan Right. It's broken. Fixing it

Comment: Neat little trick with the a/p selector by the way. Nice.

Comment: I believe you need an alert (or similar output) in JavaScript for it to be considered valid by code golf conventions.

Comment: @Mwr247 right, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

## BASH, 50 bytes

```
date +"It's %I:%M%p"|sed s/AM/a.m./|sed s/PM/p.m./
```

Just `date` and two easy `sed`s.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, <s>88</s> 75 bytes

```
use POSIX;$d=lc strftime"%R%p",localtime;$d=~s/m/.m./;printf("It's %s",$d);
```

Comment: POSIX automatically exports *everything*, so you can shave off 13 bytes by dropping the `qw(strftime)`.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 182 bytes

These solutions are horrendously long. =(

Note: These print in local time, and suppresses leading zeros for the hour. `java.util.Date` has deprecated API.

```
// 183 bytes when linebreaks and indentation are removed
import java.util.Date;
class T{
  public static void main(String[]a){
    Date d=new Date();
    int h=d.getHours();
    System.out.printf("It's %d:%02d%c.m.%n",
      (h+11)%12+1,d.getMinutes(),97+h/12*15);
  }
}
```

---

Alternate solution:

```
// 182 bytes when linebreaks and indentation are removed
class T{
  public static void main(String[]a){
    System.out.println("It's "+new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("h:mma").format(
      new java.util.Date()).toLowerCase().replaceAll("[apm]","$0."));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## C# - 160 bytes

```
using System;class C{static void Main(string[] a){var n=DateTime.Now;int h=n.Hour,m=n.Minute;Console.Write("It's "+(h<13?h:h-12)+":"+m+(h<12?"a":"p")+".m.");}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, <s>60</s> 58 bytes

```
"It's "3et=Cmd\'p'a?".m."+\_0>{}{;C}?\":"\4et=_A<{0\@}{\}?
```

#### Explanation

```
"It's "                                                         e# Print the string "It's ".
        et                                                      e# Push the local time to the stack.
       3  =                                                     e# Select the third item. (hours)
           C                                                    e# Push 12 to the stack.
            md                                                  e# Push the top stack item modulo the second stack item.
              \                                                 e# Swap the top two stack items.
               'p'a?                                            e# Push "p" or "a" to the stack.
                    ".m."+                                      e# Tack on ".m." to the above.
                          \                                     e# Swap the top two stack items.
                           _                                    e# Duplicate the top stack item.
                            0>                                  e# Determine if the top item is > 0.
                              {}{  }                            e# An if-then statement.
                                    ?                           e# If the top stack item is true.
                                 ;                              e# Remove the top stack item.
                                  C                             e# Push 12 to the stack.
                                     \                          e# Swap the top two stack items.
                                      ":"                       e# Push ":" to the stack.
                                         4  =                   e# Select the fourth item. (minutes)
                                          et                    e# Push the local time to the stack.
                                             _                  e# Duplicate the top stack item.
                                              A<                e# Determine if the top item is < 10.
                                                {   }{ }        e# An if-then statement.
                                                        ?       e# If the top stack item is true.
                                                 0              e# Push 0 to the stack.
                                                  \             e# Swap the top two stack items.
                                                   @            e# Rotate the top three stack items.
                                                      \         e# Swap the top two stack items.
```

You can test it online, [here](http://goo.gl/ep3wO3).

Answer (score 0):

## TI-BASIC, 58 bytes

```
getTimeStr(12
"It's "+sub(Ans,1,length(Ans)-2)+sub("ap",2-not(inString(Ans,"P")),1)+".m.
```

An ugly hack to build the correct output from the built-in `getTimeStr(`, which gives something like "8:59 PM". (By the way, the `12` means "12-hour format".)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 95 bytes

```
x=(new Date+"").substr(16,5).split(':')
alert(`It's ${x[0]%12||12}:`+x[1]+(x[0]<12?'a':'p')+'.m.')
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Hassium](http://HassiumLang.com), 125 Bytes

```
func main(){print("It's "+date().hour%12+":"+date().minute);if(date().hour%12!=date().hour)print("p.m.");else print("a.m.");}
```

Run it (and for expanded) [here](http://HassiumLang.com/Hassium/index.php?code=27a03dba8c8a3afa68b2be3e81c3c792)

Answer (score 0):

## Octave 54 bytes

5 bytes shorter than the shortest MATLAB submission and 21 bytes shorter than the shortest Octave submission. Uses Octave's "index everywhere" functionality.

```
disp(['It''s ',lower(datestr(now,16))([1:5,7]),'.m.'])
It's 12:34p.m.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Bash, 32 bytes

```bash
printf "%(It's %H:%M:%S%P^H.m.)T"
```

Where `^H` is a literal backspace character. Here's a hex dump (use `xxd -r` to reverse it):

```
0000000: 7072 696e 7466 2022 2528 4974 2773 2025  printf "%(It's %
0000010: 483a 254d 3a25 5325 5008 2e6d 2e29 5422  H:%M:%S%P..m.)T"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `j`, 36 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ʋ.m.`apkL12®ikKkL⁻12%⁺,TȷḋẸ':s"It's
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDQSU4Qi5tLiU2MGFwa0wxMiVDMiVBRWlrS2tMJUUyJTgxJUJCMTIlMjUlRTIlODElQkElMkNUJUM4JUI3JUUxJUI4JThCJUUxJUJBJUI4JyUzQXMlMjJJdCdzJTIwJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9JmZsYWdzPWo=)

##### Explanation

```python
ʋ.m.`apkL12®ikKkL⁻12%⁺,TȷḋẸ':s"It's    # Full program

                              "It's   "# Step 1 (get the prefix string):
                              "It's   "#  Push the string "It's "

             kKkL⁻12%⁺,TȷḋẸ':s        '# Step 2 (get the time):
               kL                      #  Push the current hours (24-hour format)
                 ⁻                     #  Decrement it
                  12%                  #  Modulo by 12
                     ⁺                 #  Increment it
             kK       ,                #  Pair with the current minutes
                        ȷ              #  And to each one:
                       T ḋ             #   Divmod it by 10
                          Ẹ            #  Dump both onto the stack
                           ':s        '#  Push a ":" between the two pairs

ʋ.m.`apkL12®i                          # Step 3 (get the suffix string):
       kL                              #  Push the current hours again
         12®                           #  Check if it's >= 12
    `ap     i                          #  Index this into the string "ap"
ʋ.m.                                   #  Push the string ".m."

                                       # Join the stack into a string, joining
                                       # lists on the stack implicitly as well

                                       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pascal, 83 B (subject to implementation characteristics)

Extended Pascal, ISO standard 10206, furnishes Pascal with some time-related routines and a data type `timeStamp`.
However, the specific behavior of `getTimeStamp`, whether it populates a `timeStamp` with the ”local time“, UTC, wall time or else, is *implementation-defined*.
Similarly the format `time` returns is implementation-defined, too.
For instance, it could depend on the value of the `LC_TIME` environment variable if the implementation says so.
It is therefore not guaranteed that the following implementation meets all task specification requirements in all ISO-compliant Pascal implementations.

```pascal
program t(output);var t:timeStamp;begin getTimeStamp(t);write('It''s ',time(t))end.
```

Note, it is not checked that `t.timeValid` is `true` but in a real-life application it is advisable.