# Primes, as efficiently inefficient as possible

Tags: code-golf, number, primes

Write a program that tests if a number `n` is prime by checking that none of the integers between `2` and `n-1` (inclusive) divide `n` (you must use *this* algorithm!). The input to STDIN should be an integer `n` (strictly) greater than 1. The output to STDOUT should be `prime` if `n` is prime and `not prime` if `n` is not prime.

Even though you are intentionally writing an inefficient program, this is still code golf, fellas. Standard CG rules apply. Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Define inefficient. Is `O(n)` inefficient enough? Or do you just mean by following your specific algorithm?

Comment: The specific algorithm of iterating from `2` to `n-1`.

Comment: Naïve implementations of Wilson's Theorem are a lot less efficient...

Comment: There are already many answers [on this question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/57617/14215) that use this method (or one with very trivial changes).

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 25 bytes

```
li_,2>f%:*!"not "*"prime"
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=li_%2C2%3Ef%25%3A*!%22not%20%22*%22prime%22&input=16)

Explanation:

```
li    Get input and convert to integer.
_,    Create range [0 ... n-1].
2>    Slice off first two elements, to get [2 ... n-1].
f%    Apply modulo with all range members to input.
:*    Calculate product of the results. This will be 0 if one of the modulo
      results was 0, non-zero if the input is prime.
!     Negate. We now have 0 for primes, 1 for non-primes.
"not "*
      Push "not " 0/1 times based on value.
"prime"
      Push "prime".
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - <s>25</s> 23 bytes

Heavily golfable, uses filter.

```
+?f!%QTr2Q"not "k"prime
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2B%3Ff%21%25QTr2Q%22not+%22k%22prime&input=7&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=7%0A10&debug=0).

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 22 bytes

```
+*}0%LQr2Q"not ""prime
```

[Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2B%2a%7D0%25LQr2Q%22not+%22%22prime&input=17&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 59

```
i=input()
print"not "*any(i%n<1for n in range(2,i))+"prime"
```

Thanks Alex! One day I will remember.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, way too many bytes (95, to be exact)

```
n=input();x=0 
for i in range(2,n):
 if n%i==0:x+=1;print'not prime';break
if x==0:print'prime'
```

Heavily golfable for sure.

Answer (score 0):

## R, 59 bytes

```r
n=scan();cat(if(n>2&sum(!n%%2:(n-1)))"not ","prime",sep="")
```

Ungolfed:

```r
# Read n from STDIN
n <- scan()

# Test primality and write to STDOUT
if (n > 2 & sum(!(n %% 2:(n-1)))
    cat("not prime")
else
    cat("prime")
```