# Alternested numbers

Tags: code-golf, sequence, array, integer

Consider the array of positive integers:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, ...
```

Then, concatenate them:

```
1234567891011121314151617181920212223242526...
```

And then split them into chunks of variable length, each length being equal to the **N**th positive integer:

```
[1][23][456][7891][01112][131415][1617181][92021222][324252627][2829303132] ...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  2    3     4     5       6       7        8          9          10      ...
```

## Task

Given an integer **N** (positive for 1-indexing or non-negative for 0-indexing), your task is to output the sum of the deltas of the digits in the **N**th chunk (the differences between consecutive digits).

- [Default-forbidden loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.
- [Standard Input and Output methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) apply.
- You may choose either 0 or 1-indexing for **N**.
- The sequence must start with **1**.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest code in bytes wins.

## Examples & Test cases

1-indexed test cases. If you want 0-indexed ones, just decrement N.

```
N, Chunk, Deltas, Sum

1  -> 1          -> []                               -> 0
2  -> 23         -> [1]                              -> 1
3  -> 456        -> [1, 1]                           -> 2
4  -> 7891       -> [1, 1, -8]                       -> -6
5  -> 01112      -> [1, 0, 0,1]                      -> 2
6  -> 131415     -> [2, -2, 3, -3, 4]                -> 4
7  -> 1617181    -> [5, -5, 6, -6, 7, -7]            -> 0
8  -> 92021222   -> [-7, -2, 2, -1, 1, 0, 0]         -> -7
9  -> 324252627  -> [-1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4, 5]     -> 4
10 -> 2829303132 -> [6, -6, 7, -6, -3, 3, -2, 2, -1] -> 0
```

<sub>**[Puzzle 2](https://github.com/Mr-Xcoder/CodeGolf-Hackathon/blob/master/Puzzle%202/Puzzle%202.md) on [CodeGolf-Hackathon](https://github.com/Mr-Xcoder/CodeGolf-Hackathon) (I am the original author there too, so I am allowed to repost). [Related, Inspiration](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/145883/binary-prime-chunks). [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/145421/the-binary-square-diagonal-sequence).**</sub>

Comment: [Kinda related but not really](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/128895/alternest-a-string)

Comment: The sum of all the differences between consecutive digits is just the difference between the last and the first.

Answer (score 6):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
ΣẊ-!SCṁdN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9zih7u6dBWDnR/ubEzx@///vwkA)

My solution to the Hackathon.

Explanation:

```
ΣẊ-!SCṁdN⁰
    S      (x -> y -> z):f -> (x -> y):g -> x:x :: return f(x, g(x))
     C      f= [num]:x -> [x]:y -> [x] :: cut y in pieces where each piece has its respective length in x
      ṁ     g= (x -> [y]):f -> ([x]:x -> [y]) :: maps f over x then concatenate
       d     f= num:x -> [num] :: return decimal digits of x
        N   x= sequence of natural numbers [1..]
   !     ⁰ [x]:x -> num:y -> x :: get yth (impl. input) element of x (above result)
 Ẋ         (x -> x -> y):f -> [x]:x -> [y] :: map f over overlapping pairs of x (above result)
  -         f= num:x -> num:y -> num :: return y - x
Σ          [num]:x -> num :: return sum of x (above result)
```

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>54</s> <s>53</s> <s>51</s> 50 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @tsh*

0-indexed.

```js
k=>-(n=1,g=s=>s[x=k*-~k/2]-s[x+k]-n||g(s+n++))``-n
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

k=>-(n=1,g=s=>s[x=k*-~k/2]-s[x+k]-n||g(s+n++))``-n

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log('a(' + i + ') = ' + f(i));
}
```

Comment: Zero-indexed: `k=>-(n=1,g=s=>s[x=k*-~k/2]-s[x+k]-n||g(s+n++))""-n`

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 32 bytes

```apl
{+/2-⍨/⍎¨⍵↑(+/⍳⍵-1)↓' '~⍨⍕⍳+/⍳⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RqbX0j3Ue9K/Qf9fYdWvGod@ujtoka2kDeZiBb11DzUdtkdQX1OqCKR71TgaIwqVqgdgWQhs0KhgYA)

**How?**

`+/⍳⍵` - sum of `1` to `n`

`⍳` - make range of that

`' '~⍨⍕` - into string, without spaces

`(+/⍳⍵-1)↓` - drop first (sum of `1` to `n-1`) chars

`⍵↑` - keep the next `n` chars

`⍎¨` - make every char into integer

`2-⍨/` - differences list (backward subtraction for every 2 items)

`+/` - sum it up.

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>61</s> 60 bytes

```hs
l=fromEnum<$>(show=<<[1..])
f n|t<-sum[2..n]=l!!t-l!!(t-n+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P8c2rSg/1zWvNNdGxU6jOCO/3NbGJtpQTy9WkytNIa@mxEa3uDQ32khPLy/WNkdRsUQXSGiU6OZpG2r@z03MzFOwVchNLPCNV9AoKMrMK9FL01QAaTc0iP0PAA)

#### Explanation:

The sum of the deltas of a list is the same as the difference between the last and the first element.

The last element (zero-indexed) is `t`, `triangle(n)-1 = sum[2..n]`. The first element, then is `t-n+1`, as the list has `n` elements.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 80 bytes

```python
n=input()
s=map(int,''.join(map(str,range(2**n))))
print s[n*-~n/2]-s[~-n*n/2+1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYqxCoAgAAV3v6ItNS2SVr9EHByiDHqK2tDir5vddAcX33IGqNagPeJTKCNZ3y5SjyLGcb6CB/07lySSw7FTxTlYh8TUpyEbcFmxKCuzqRK867Ta1rYP)

`2**n` is way overkill, of course, but it’s a byte shorter than something like `n*n+1`.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 71 bytes

```
Tr@Differences[TakeList[Join@@IntegerDigits[Range[#^2]],Range@#][[#]]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcYxCsMwDADArxgMmTI02QMasrR0CMWbUEAE2RUlKtj6vwO56U72r5zsenDPYQk9VVg1Z6lihzRM/JO3NsfXXw3gaS5F6qpFveGHrQjGfSYa70MkxEhEQ9@qmgfIOD2oXw)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
∞LJā£è¥O
```

0-indexed.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/e/mZ69kpaBk7@fy/1HHPB@vI42HFh9ecWip/3@d/4YGBgA)

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>60</s> <s>57</s> 53 bytes

```js
f=(n,s=i='',m=n*-~n/2)=>s[m]?s[m]-s[m-n+1]:f(n,s+i++)
```

```html
<input type=number min=1 oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><pre id=o>
```

1-indexed. Previous 60-byte nonrecursive version:

```js
f=
(n,s=[...Array(n*n+1).keys()].join``)=>s[m=n*-~n/2]-s[m-n+1]
```

```html
<input type=number min=1 oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 87 bytes

```python
n=input()
a=map(int,''.join(map(str,range(1,n*n))))[n*~-n/2:][:n]or[0]
print a[-1]-a[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5BDsIgFET3nOKHTaFpVbok4SSExbdFxdgPoZjoxqsjNXF2M8m8mfQut0hTnePiDee8kgmUnkVIhmbFJAKVoesO9xhI7H4rechIVy/UQD3JJkv9Z6TjpJ3V5GK2J8dSbkVAOyo3YgtqY7NLzBAgEPwBSknNAH6LYOCB63lBDaFl/uVn2F/VLw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 11 bytes

```
²ɾṅ?ʀʀÞṁi⌊¯
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzIiwiIiwiwrLJvuG5hT/KgMqAw57huYFp4oyKwq8iLCIiLCI3Il0=)

0-indexed

### Explained

```
²ɾṅ?ʀʀÞṁi⌊¯
²ɾ           # the range [1...input**2]
  ṅ          # joined into a single integer - call it x
   ?ʀ        # the range [0...input]
     ʀ       # [range [0...n] for n in that]
      Þṁ     # reshape x to the shape of that
        i    # get the input(th) item of that
         ⌊   # convert each item to integer
          ¯  # and take the deltas of that
             # the -s flag sums that
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 104 bytes

```python
def f(N):A=map(int,"".join(map(str,range(1,N*N)))[~-N*N/2:][:N]);return sum(a-b for a,b in zip(A[1:],A))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY89TsQwEIVrcoqnVB40WZKw7I9RilwgF4hSeIUDRlo7GnsLKLh68EZQzfv5NNJbvtJH8O26vtkZsxpI993VLMr5xGW5@wzOq7uPSViMf7eq4eFxIKLxp8riqdXTqIeJXsWmm3jE21WZ6oI5CAxf4Dy@3aL6sdET90TrvXCM8N8UD/klWsYzA3vGC@PAOGZzYpwZTU2cmTqrDasO28lkjqrjplBTQRomRispz3CErkMoFsk7UA7hr3LBw4oEibty/QU)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>58</s>  55 bytes

```perl6
{[+] ($_=(1..*).map(|*.comb).rotor(1..*)[$^a])[1..*]Z-@$_}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJaYU5JalJdaXJKaomD7vzpaO1ZBQyXeVsNQT09LUy83sUCjRksvOT83SVOvKL8kvwgiEa0SlxirGQ1ix0bpOqjE1/4vKMrMK0lTUFI1AhpkpwCkYvKUdBRU4nUUkOwAmq2pkJZfpBBnaPAfAA)

```perl6
{[+] ($_=(1..*).map(|*.comb)[^$^a+[+] ^$a])[1..*]Z-@$_}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJaYU5JalJdaXJKaomD7vzpaO1ZBQyXeVsNQT09LUy83sUCjRksvOT83STM6TiUuURukIE4lMVYzGqQiNkrXQSW@9n9BUWZeSZqCkqoR0BQ7BSAVk6eko6ASr6OAZAHQYE2FtPwiBaBWQ4P/AA)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{ # bare block lambda with placeholder parameter ｢$a｣
  [+]  # reduce using &infix:«+» the following


    (
      $_ =                # store into ｢$_｣ for later use

        ( 1 .. * )        # Range of all positive integers
        .map( | *.comb )\ # split into digits and flatten into single list

        [                 # index into the sequence (1 based)

          ^$^a            # Range up to (and excluding) the input
                          # ｢0 ..^ $a｣ or ｢0 .. $a-1｣

          +               # shift it up by
          [+] ^$a         # the sum of the values up to (and excluding) the input

        ]

    )[ 1 .. *]            # skip the first value

    Z-                    # zip using &infix:«-»

    @$_                   # ｢$_｣ used as a List
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>163</s> 147 bytes

```php
$v=$argv[1];for($i=1;$i<=$v*$v;$i++){$s.=$i;$j+=$i<$v?$i:0;}$s=array_slice(str_split($s),$j,$v);for($i=0;$i<$v-1;$i++){$k+=$s[$i+1]-$s[$i];}echo$k;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxBCoMwFEQvMwutVsyy/QYPIiJibf0qTciXQClevWkQ3My8Wcyzkw1VbWPCa/Tu5RvV0tO4BKwVgSsNf4GPlGXpF1JoMGHOYlXwNfhe0g7RvXP9p5OVhzGRzXViV94SSJpjzuHT01nScbyq07hElTRxqPZ6QEv7OEwGC4XwM3Zj85ZQDOYxFpHD7Q8)

My first attempt at code golfing... have a feeling that this can be shorter

Edit: saved 16 bytes by removing several instantiations

Comment: Welcome to the site! You may want to look through [these](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2913/tips-for-golfing-in-php) tips for golfing in PHP

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 79 + 1 (`-p`) = 80 bytes

```perl
$_=substr join('',1..$_**2),$_*($_-1)/2,$_;1while s/(.)(.)/$r+=$2-$1;$2/e;$_=$r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYxLCoAgFACv4uKBWn5QaiWeRQiEDElRo9v3EgZmVlNjyzsiBN@fo49GrpJuRqkwSkFYFsvFFIMgDdd2tjPvmXIkXTPFJxra6sFKMA6sjm6eoCFuX6kjlbujrD8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>29</s> 27 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Mr.Xcoder.

```
s.+msdc:sm+hd""U*QQKsUQ+QK1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v1hPO7c4JdmqOFc7I0VJKVQrMNC7ODRQO9Db8P9/EwA)

Comment: [27 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v1hPO7c4JdmqOFc7I0VJKVQrMNC7ODRQO9Db8P9/EwA) pretty sure it can be golfed further...

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
²RDFṫ³ḶS‘¤ðḣIS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9qZWxsef//wrJSREbhuavCs@G4tlPigJjCpMOw4bijSVP///8xMA)

**Explanation**

```
²RDFṫ³ḶS‘¤ðḣIS    Main Link
²                  Square input
 R                 Range: [1,2,3,..,n^2]
  D                Digits: [1,2,...,[1,0],[1,1],...]
   F               Flatten list
     ³ḶS‘¤         n(n-1)/2+1
    ṫ              Remove the first n(n-1)/2+1 elements from the list of digits
          ðḣ       Take the first n digits of the list. ð is needed to prevent I from acting on n.
            I      Increment. Take the diferences
             S     Sum
```

I originally started by taking the range( n(n+1)/2 ) but since you can have extra digits at the end of the list before slicing it I changed it to range(n^2). You have extra digits after 1-9 anyway.

Comment: `+²HRDFṫÐ€³ḶḣÐ€RS€‘¤ṪðḣIS` original (successful but long) attempt