# Code ladder, Cops

Tags: code-golf, cops-and-robbers

> Note: This challenge is finished. Submissions are still welcome but can not win.

This is the cops' thread. The robbers' thread [goes here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99547/code-ladder-robbers).

Write a code that outputs the integer `1`. If you add, remove or substitute a single character (of your choosing), the code should output the integer `2`. Change one more character (the same or another), and the code should output `3`. Continue like this as far as you can, but maximum up to 10. Default output formats such as `ans = 1` are accepted. You can ignore output to STDERR (or equivalent).

You must reveal the language, byte count of your initial code, the number of integers it works for, as well as an optional number of characters of the initial code. Note: You don't have to reveal any characters, but remember that revealing characters might make it harder for the robbers as they must use the same character in the same position. You can choose which character you use to denote unrevealed characters (for instance underscore), but make sure to specify this.

Cops can provide the uncracked code after one week and call the submission "SAFE". The winning submission will be the shortest uncracked submission that produces the number 10. If no uncracked submissions are able to print 10, the shortest code that produces 9 will win, and so on. Note that the robbers don't have to make the same changes as you do, and they don't have to reproduce the exact code (unless you reveal all characters). They must only reproduce the output.

Submissions posted later than November 24th are welcome but not eligible for the win (because there will likely be fewer robbers around).

---

**Example post:**

The following post is a submission in the language `MyLang`, it is 9 bytes long, and it works for numbers 1 - 8.

## MyLang, 9 bytes, 8 numbers

This submission works for 1 - 8. Unrevealed characters are indicated with an underscore: `_`.

```
abc____i
```

#### Leaderboard

Disclaimer: The leaderboard is not tested and uncracked submissions might not appear in the list.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><style>table th,table td{padding: 5px;}th{text-align: left;}.score{text-align: right;}table a{display: block;}.main{float: left;margin-right: 30px;}.main h3,.main div{margin: 5px;}.message{font-style: italic;}#api_error{color: red;font-weight: bold;margin: 5px;}</style> <script>QUESTION_ID=99546;var safe_list=[];var uncracked_list=[];var n=0;var bycreation=function(x,y){return (x[0][0]<y[0][0])-(x[0][0]>y[0][0]);};var byscore=function(x,y){return (x[0][1]>y[0][1])-(x[0][1]<y[0][1]);};function u(l,o){jQuery(l[1]).empty();l[0].sort(o);for(var i=0;i<l[0].length;i++) l[0][i][1].appendTo(l[1]);if(l[0].length==0) jQuery('<tr><td colspan="3" class="message">none yet.</td></tr>').appendTo(l[1]);}function m(s){if('error_message' in s) jQuery('#api_error').text('API Error: '+s.error_message);}function g(p){jQuery.getJSON('//api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/' + QUESTION_ID + '/answers?page=' + p + '&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=!.Fjs-H6J36w0DtV5A_ZMzR7bRqt1e', function(s){m(s);s.items.map(function(a){var he = jQuery('<div/>').html(a.body).children().first();he.find('strike').text('');var h = he.text();if (!/cracked/i.test(h) && (typeof a.comments == 'undefined' || a.comments.filter(function(b){var c = jQuery('<div/>').html(b.body);return /^cracked/i.test(c.text()) || c.find('a').filter(function(){return /cracked/i.test(jQuery(this).text())}).length > 0}).length == 0)){var m = /^\s*((?:[^,;(\s]|\s+[^-,;(\s])+).*(0.\d+)/.exec(h);var e = [[n++, m ? m[2]-0 : null], jQuery('<tr/>').append( jQuery('<td/>').append( jQuery('<a/>').text(m ? m[1] : h).attr('href', a.link)), jQuery('<td class="score"/>').text(m ? m[2] : '?'), jQuery('<td/>').append( jQuery('<a/>').text(a.owner.display_name).attr('href', a.owner.link)) )];if(/safe/i.test(h)) safe_list.push(e);else uncracked_list.push(e);}});if (s.items.length == 100) g(p + 1);else{var s=[[uncracked_list, '#uncracked'], [safe_list, '#safe']];for(var i=0;i<2;i++) u(s[i],byscore);jQuery('#uncracked_by_score').bind('click',function(){u(s[0],byscore);return false});jQuery('#uncracked_by_creation').bind('click',function(){u(s[0],bycreation);return false});}}).error(function(e){m(e.responseJSON);});}g(1);</script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/codegolf/all.css?v=7509797c03ea"><div id="api_error"></div><div class="main"><h3>Uncracked submissions</h3><table> <tr> <th>Language</th> <th class="score">Score</th> <th>User</th> </tr> <tbody id="uncracked"></tbody></table><div>Sort by: <a href="#" id="uncracked_by_score">score</a> <a href="#" id="uncracked_by_creation">creation</a></div></div><div class="main"><h3>Safe submissions</h3><table> <tr> <th>Language</th> <th class="score">Score</th> <th>User</th> </tr> <tbody id="safe"></tbody></table></div>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand... given an arbitrary code in CJam that produces `1`, how can I prevent the robbers from [adding `)` repeatedly](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=MSkpKSk&input=) to generate the rest of the numbers? The same would be valid for quite a few languages

Comment: If that's possible for any program that outputs `1` then it appears CJam is a bad choice of language for this challenge. There's no way to prevent robbers from doing that.

Comment: Got it, thanks. As I said, that rules out quite a few golfing languages (an "increment" operator is very common)

Comment: @LuisMendo Well, it will certainly make this more interesting...

Comment: So a robber is allowed to simply add characters to the code (thereby increasing the byte count)?

Comment: @Dopapp, yes. The initial code must have the same length though.

Comment: I really want to do something with [JSFuck](http://www.jsfuck.com/)y code, but I have neither the time nor the confidence it would even be a good fit for this environment

Comment: "maximum up to 10." Does this mean that the code to output 10 must not be modifiable under the given rules to output 11? Would a possible output of 12 be OK?

Comment: @DanielJour It can be modifiable up to any number, but the maximum number the robbers need to find is `10`. That rule is in place because many submissions can probably be extended to infinity (in theory), so scoring based on the highest achieved number wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Snippet added. I haven't tested it properly so there might be uncracked submissions that don't appear in the list.

Comment: Re: snippet testing, consider a submission ([e.g.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99787/16766)) where someone has posted a crack that is invalid, but hasn't removed their comment. I would consider these uncracked, but they do not appear in the list.

Comment: You may want to try only disqualifying an entry if the header contains `cracked` in some form. This is what the [redesign userscript](https://github.com/vihanb/PPCG-Design) currently does.

Comment: Does the same character have to be changed?

Comment: @CrazyPython, no. From the challenge text: _"Change one more character (the same or another),"_. Note that the changes are incremental. So, to get to `6` you should alter the code you had for `5`, not the code you used for `1`. Makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 18 Bytes, 10 numbers, SAFE

This submission works for 1 - 10. Unrevealed characters are indicated with an underscore: `_`.

```
.__{_]5[$@.;=@$!!1
```

[You can try Hexagony online over here.](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/)

## My solution:

```
1:   .<[{8]5[$@.;=@$!!10
2:   .<[{8]5[$@);=@$!!10
3:   2<[{8]5[$@);=@$!!10
4:   3<[{8]5[$@);=@$!!10
5:   4<[{8]5[$@);=@$!!10
6:   5<[{8]5[$@);=@$!!10
6:   7<[{8]5[$@);=@$!!10
8:   7<[{8]5[$@);=@$!!10
9:   8<[{8]5[$@);=@$!!10
10:  9<[{8]5[$@);=@$!!10
```

---

**Hex for output 1:**

[Try it Online!](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=ICAuIDwgWyAKIHsgOCBdIDUKWyAkIEAgLiA7CiA9IEAgJCAhIAogICEgMSAw&input=)

```
Full Hex:
  . < [ 
 { 8 ] 5
[ $ @ . ;
 = @ $ ! 
  ! 1 0

Important parts:
  . < .
 . 8 . 5
. $ @ . ;
 . . $ .
  . 1 .
```

1. At the `<` the memory edge is `0`, so it turns up.
2. Hits `1`
3. Jumps to `5`
4. Jumps over `8`, but is reversed at `<` and gets the `8` on the way back.
5. Hits `5` again
6. Jumps over `1`
7. Hits the `<` at this point, the memory value is 1585 which, mod 256, happens to be ASCII `1`
8. Finally prints and exits with `;@`.

---

**Hex for output 2:**

[Try it Online!](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=ICAuIDwgWyAKIHsgOCBdIDUKWyAkIEAgKSA7CiA9IEAgJCAhIAogICEgMSAw&input=)

```
Important parts:
  . < .
 . 8 . 5
. $ @ ) ;
 . . $ .
  . 1 .
```

This follows the same path, but on the way back it hits a `)` which increments the memory edge to 1586, or `2`.

---

**Hex for output 3-9:**

[Try it Online!](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=ICAyIDwgWyAKIHsgOCBdIDUKWyAkIEAgKSA7CiA9IEAgJCAhIAogICEgMSAw&input=)

```
Important parts:
  2 < [
 . . ] .
. $ . ) .
 . @ . !
  . 1 .
```

1. Hits the `2`
2. Now the memory edge is positive when it gets to `<`, so it turn down.
3. The `]` changes the instruction pointer, but is immediately comes back with `[`
4. `)` increments to `3`
5. `!` Prints `3`
6. `$` is left over from the first two numbers so we jump over the end (`@`)
7. `1` changes the memory edge, but that doesn't matter now.
8. `<` reflects the pointer back.
9. Again `1` doesn't matter because we hit `@` to end the program.

Answer (score 11):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 2 bytes, 10 numbers, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99560/8478)

```
_1
```

Works for 1 to 10, `_` is a hidden character. This shouldn't be too hard, but I hope it provides a somewhat interesting puzzle. :)

[You can try Retina online over here.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/)

Comment: Argh, can't figure out 10 :p

Comment: @LegionMammal978 :)

Comment: Cracked by FryAmTheEggman: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99560/32700

Answer (score 11):

## Octave, 55 bytes, 10 numbers, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99834/24877)

```
(o__(O_o_(@(__o)o__-O}_)_(0<O,{_(_o_O-1)+1_@(_1}_)(__o_
```

`_` is the unknown character.

#### Solution

> `(o=@(O,o)(@(O,o)o{2-O}())(0<O,{@()o(O-1)+1,@()1}))(0,o)` %then changing the very last `0` to `1,2,3` e.t.c.
>
>
>  Given `x`, this does recursively calculate `x+1`. It is mainly composed of two anonymous functions. One provides an `if` statement to anchor the recursion:
>
>
>  `if_ = @( boolean, outcomes) outcomes{ 2 - boolean}();`
>
>
>  This is just abusing the fact that a boolean values evaluates to `0` or `1`. This function accepts a boolean value, and a cell array of two functions, and evaluates one or the other of these two functiosn depending on the boolean value. The second part is the actual recursion:
>
>
>  `plus_one = @(n,f) if_(0<n ,{@()f(n-1)+1, @()1})`
>
>
>  As an anyonmous function is anonymous, you cannot directly access it from itsefl. That why we need a second argument `f` first. Later we will provide  a handle to the function instelf as a second argument, so a final function would looks like so:
>
>
>   `plus_one_final = @(n)plus_one(n,plus_one);`
>
>
>  So in this notation my submission becomes:
>
>
>  `(plus_one=@(n,f)(@(boolean,outcomes)outcomes{2-boolean}())(0<n,{@()f(n-1)+1,@()1}))(n,f)`
>
>
>  I asked about recursion anchors for anonymous functions in MATLAB a while ago on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32268411/2913106).

Comment: o_O O____o O_O o_O

Comment: I'm not so sure whether this is really that difficult to crack=)

Comment: Well, it sure as hell isn't _easy_ to crack! Could maybe do it with pen and paper(!)

Comment: I take that as a compliment :) I think you will like my solution, but I'm not gonna reveal anything until it is cracked / it is safe.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99834/30688)

Answer (score 9):

### Python 2, 9 bytes, 10 numbers, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100039/20260)

```python
print 8/8
```

No hidden chars. Can you crack it without brute forcing?

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100039/21487) - that was fun :)

Answer (score 8):

## Perl, 12 bytes, 10 numbers, [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99760/62131)

Underscores represent unknown characters.

```
____;say__-9
```

Probably fairly easy, and it wouldn't surprise me if there were multiple solutions. Still, it might be fun to crack.

(The intended solution was the same as the crack. This is fundamentally just a problem about assigning 10 to a variable in four characters, which is surprisingly difficult in Perl; unlike many golfing languages, it doesn't have a variable that helpfully starts at 10.)

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99760/57100). At first I thought it was something like `$_=1;say;#-9`, but I couldn't figure out how to get 10.

Answer (score 7):

## Perl, 46 bytes, 10 numbers, safe

### The problem

```perl
__b_b_\__}_b_b_b_0_;
$b[0]=10;$b{0}=1;say$b[0]
```

The shorter problems tend to get cracked quickly, so I thought I'd try a longer one. The longer ones also tend to get cracked if people leave enough of a gap to sneak something naughty like `say` or `exit` in, so all the gaps here are short. Hidden characters are represented using `_`.

### My solution

```perl
sub b{\@_}*b=b$b{0};
$b[0]=10;$b{0}=1;say$b[0]
```

To print 2, 3, etc., up to 9, keep changing the number assigned to `$b{0}`  in the second line (i.e. `$b{0}=2`, `$b{0}=3`, etc.). The program for 9 looks like this:

```perl
sub b{\@_}*b=b$b{0};
$b[0]=10;$b{0}=9;say$b[0]
```

Then to produce 10, comment out the first line by prepending a `#` character to it.

### Explanation

The first thing to note is that the solution isn't really golfed apart from removing whitespace: if we lay it out with more readable whitespace, we get this:

```perl
sub b { \@_ }
*b = b $b{0};
$b[0] = 10;
$b{0} = 1;
say $b[0];
```

Normally, when you access the arguments of a subroutine in Perl, you do so via copying them out of `@_`. There's a good reason for this: `@_` aliases the arguments the subroutine is given (so, for example, `(sub { $_[0] = 3 })->($x)` will assign to `$x`), something that isn't normally desirable.

Although `@_` might seem magical, it's actually just using a standard feature of the Perl internals (which is readily available from XS but only comes up in a few weird cases in pure Perl, such as `@_` itself): an array doesn't store its elements directly, but rather by reference. Thus, when we call `b` in the second line below, Perl generates an array (calling it `@_`) whose first element is a reference to the same storage that `$b{0}` uses. (Hash values are also stored by reference; $_[0] and $b{0} are both referencing the same storage at this point.) Because `@_` isn't doing anything special from an internals point of view, we can take a reference to it just like we could with any other array, causing it to outlive the subroutine it's defined in.

Perl variables *also* refer to data storage by reference. A long time ago, people used to use code like `*x = *y;` to set `$x` as an alias to `$y` (via making them reference the same thing), likewise `@x` as an alias to `@y`, `%x` as an alias to `%y`, and so on. That rather breaks the invariant that variables with similar names don't have to act similarly, so modern Perl provides an alternative; assigning a reference to a typeglob overrides only the variable that matches the type of the reference (so `*x = \%y` would alias `%x` to point to the same storage as `%y` but leave, say, `$x` alone). This syntax notably doesn't care about whether the storage you're aliasing to has a name, so when we assign the return value of `b` (which is an array reference that's keeping the array formerly called `@_` alive) to `*b`, what happens is that `@b` is changed to alias the argument list to the call to `b` (while leaving `%b` unchanged). This means, notably, that `$b[0]` and `$b{0}` now point to the same storage, and assigning to one will therefore change the other. Everything from then on is completely straightforward.

The Perl documentation doesn't really talk about this sort of detail, so I'm not surprised anyone got the crack; the nature of `@_` as not quite being like other arrays isn't something that's really emphasised, and most coding styles aim to minimize the effects that this has rather than amplifying them.

Comment: I'm so intrigued by this. I've learnt about pseudo-hashes and refreshed my memory on referencing and de-referencing but I can't seem to figure it out!

Comment: @DomHastings, ... and I've been fooling around with various demarcation characters for `q` and `s` and `y` and `m` (mostly trying to get them to end after the `$b[0]` assignment), but nothing's working for me (yet).

Comment: You were both on the wrong track, but admittedly, there's not much help given by the language or by my submission as to what the right track is (I had to leave one clue to avoid leaving too large a gap, but there are plenty of reasons that a program might contain a backslash, it's not always related to references).

Comment: I feel like I was frustratingly close. I had `sub b{\@_}` cemented in my mind, and, although I experimented with `*b` I couldn't get it! Thanks for the explanation. I might have glossed over it in your explanation, but why does `sub b{\@_}*b=b$b[0]` not do the same?

Comment: You're trying to make the array element and the hash element share memory, so you need to mention both. The array element's implicitly mentioned when you assign an array reference (`\@_`) to `*b`, but you have to mention the hash element explicitly yourself. With `*b=b$b[0]`, you're basically just aliasing the new `$b[0]` (after changing where `@b` points) to the `$b[0]` that existed at the start of the program, which is useless.

Comment: Of course, that makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript, 30 bytes, 10 numbers, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99566/42545)

```
alert(Array(_)________.length)
```

Shouldn't be too hard, but hopefully it's just hard enough to provide a challenge. :) Unrevealed characters are marked with `_`.

Comment: Nice one! I had a swell time solving this one, it was easy, yet challenging at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

### Perl, 14 bytes, 10 numbers, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99619/55508)

```
say_!"___"%""_
```

Works for 1 to 10. `_` are hidden characters.

I think this shouldn't be too hard to crack. I have an harder one, for 22 bytes, I'll post it if this one is cracked.

---

Original code :

```
say"!"=~y"%""c
```

And replace the `"!"` by a string of the length of the number you wish to print, for instance `!`, `!!`, `!!!`, etc.

However, [ais523](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62131/ais523) found another way :

```
say"!"+1#"%""r
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99619/62131). I suspect this isn't what you were going for at all. (I was trying to do something using regex, but this was much simpler.)

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript, 22 bytes, 10 numbers, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99759)

Probably rather easy to crack.

```
alert(__14_337__xc_de)
```

`_` being a hidden character

Comment: I'd be shocked if `xc_de` was anything but a red herring

Comment: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99759)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page), 10 numbers, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99666/53748)

```
“1‘ỌȮḊ‘
```

No wildcards.

The crack achieved (to use an eval with an argument) was, as many seem to be in this thread, not the intended one.

The intended crack was:

```
“1‘ỌȮḊ‘ - (prints 1)
“1‘     - code page index list of characters "1": [49]
   Ọ    - cast to ordinals: ['1']
    Ȯ   - print (with no line feed) and return input: effectively prints "1"
        -     (but if left at this would then implicitly print another "1")
     Ḋ  - dequeue: []
      ‘ - increment (vectorises): []
        - implicit print: prints ""

“1‘ỌŒḊ‘ - (prints 2)
“1‘Ọ    - as above: ['1']
    ŒḊ  - depth: 1
      ‘ - increment: 2
        - implicit print: prints "2"

“1‘ỌŒḊ‘‘ - (prints 3)
“1‘ỌŒḊ‘  - as above: 2
       ‘ - increment: 3
         - implicit print: prints "3"

... keep adding an increment operator to print 4 - 10.
```

Comment: I would be able to crack it if the '‘' was on the next line. So close... :)

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99666/58765) but could you explain what happens for `10`, because I got lucky on this one while trying things that might work.

Comment: @Hedi Ninja'd me too quickly, I was working on it.

Comment: @Hedi - yours was an unintended crack. The way `10` is working for you is, I believe, by evaluating the jelly code in the string `9` with an argument of `0` (the default value of the input), which you then dequeue (no effect) and then increment.

Comment: ...actually I think the way `10` is working for you is by evaluating the jelly code in the string `9` with an argument of `[]` - the default value of the input, `0`, dequeued - which you then increment., Like `“1‘‘‘‘‘‘‘‘‘Ọv0Ḋ¤‘`

Comment: @Hedi (...or really, more explicitly, like `“1‘‘‘‘‘‘‘‘‘Ọv0RḊ¤‘` I think)

Answer (score 4):

## Octave, 17 bytes, 10 numbers, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99647/24877)

```
_od(3_13_13_7_1_)
```

Original solution

> `mod(3*1361357,10)`
>
>  `...`
>
>  `mod(3*1361357,17)`
>
>  `mod(3*1361397,17)`
>
>  `mod(9*1361397,17)`

`_` is the hidden character.

Comment: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99647/41805) :)

Answer (score 4):

## Befunge-93, 11 bytes, 10+ numbers, [Cracked](/a/99901/21487)

This submission works for at least 1 - 10. Unrevealed characters are indicated with `□`.

```
□□5:**-□-.@
```

[Try it online](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/)

I must say I was impressed that two people could come up with independent solutions for this, neither of which were what I was expecting. While [Martin](/a/99649/8478) got there first, I'm giving the "win" to [Sp3000](/a/99901/21487) as their solution is more portable.

This was my intended solution though:

> `g45:**-2-.@`
> `g45:**-1-.@`
> `g45:**-1\.@`
> `g45:**-1\+.@`
> `g45:**-2\+.@`
> `...`
> `g45:**-7\+.@`
>
> Because a stack underflow in Befunge is interpreted as 0, the `g` just reads from 0,0 returning the ASCII value of 'g', namely 103. `45:**-` subtracts 100, giving you 3. Then `2-` gives you 1.
>
> For the third iteration, the `-` (subtract) is changed to a `\` (swap) instruction, so the 3 becomes the topmost stack entry. And in iteration four, a `+` (add) instruction is inserted, thus adding the 3 to the 1 giving 4.

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99649/8478) I'm curious to see what solution you had in mind. :)

Comment: @MartinEnder As I commented on your answer, I'd like to leave my intended solution hidden for a while in case someone else wants to attempt a more portable solution. Is that OK?

Comment: Of course, that's fine. :)

Comment: `"15:**-6-.@` gives 1, but I'm not sure whether the fact that `"` pushes 32 on top (due to implicit spaces) is an artefact of the TIO interpreter or part of Befunge's spec, because trying a few interpreters it seems not all interpreters do that. Does your intended solution depend on this behaviour?

Comment: @Sp3000 That wasn't my intended solution, but that's perfectly valid Befunge - the interpreters that don't support that are incorrect. If you post an answer with the rest of the sequence I'd definitely consider that a complete crack.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99901/21487). (only saying that in case someone writes a Stack Snippet which looks for the word in comments)

Answer (score 4):

## R, 21 bytes, 10 numbers [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99890/62252)

```
__i___________i______
```

Works for 10 numbers. `_` is hidden character.

Original solution:

> `which(letters%in%"a")`
>
>  `which(letters%in%"b")`
>
>  etc.

Comment: @StewieGriffin This is my first post on this site and I don't know the norms. I have one more R challenge - a bit trickier, I think. Can I add another answer? Or append it to this one?

Comment: Adding a new one it's perfectly fine (as a separate one)  welcome to the site 

Comment: Did I cracked it [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99890/39451) ?

Comment: @Tensibai Cracked :)

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 16 bytes, 10 numbers, [cracked by xsot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100144/6828)

```
x=##/=#%#
)
###x
```

`#` is any character.

Comment: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100144/45268)

Answer (score 3):

## Octave, 32 bytes, 10 numbers. [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99572/36398)

```
_n_(isprime(floor(s____i__ i____
```

`_` is a hidden character.

You can try Octave online [here](https://octave-online.net/).

---

Original solution:

1: `nnz(isprime(floor(sqrt(i):pi')))`

2: `nnz(isprime(floor('sqrt(i):pi')))`

3: `nnz(isprime(floor('sqrt(i):pia')))`

4: `nnz(isprime(floor('sqrt(i):piaa')))`

...

Comment: Very nice! [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99572/31516). Not sure if I reproduced your code though?

Comment: @StewieGriffin Well done! I should have revealed more characters... :-D

Comment: Damn that was clever :) Too bad you couldn't say it was MATLAB... One more character would probably have made it much harder... I enjoyed it though... I used a full 25 minutes :)

Comment: @Stewie Yes, you made good use of non-Matlab features! :-)

Answer (score 3):

## Octave, 17 bytes, 10 numbers, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99618/31516)

```
_i_(__i__(2_5_))
```

Unrevealed characters are marked with `_`.

Intended solution:

> ```
>     fix(asind(2/59))
>     fix(asind(3/59))
>     fix(asind(4/59))
>     fix(asind(5/59))
>     fix(asind(6/59))
>     fix(asind(7/59))
>     fix(asind(8/59))
>     fix(asind(9/59))
>     fix(asind(9/55))
>     fix(asind(9/50))
> ```

Comment: [cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99618/24877) (finally=) but probably not with your original approach, right?

Comment: Nice, added my approach in a spoiler tag :)

Comment: Oh your solution is really clever!!!

Answer (score 3):

## Octave, 19 bytes, 10 numbers, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99631/24877)

```
__sca__1_)___'-_6_'
```

`_` is the hidden character.

Intended solution:

> pascal(10)('a'-96)'

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99631/36398)

Comment: I couldn't remember any function with `sca`. Coming from you, I should have thought of matrix functions :-)

Comment: There is a reason why I made a complete list of Octave function names =)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes, 10 numbers, [cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99657/56258)

Not very hard, but a fun one :)

```
_[==_
```

`_` is a random character. Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=X1s9PV8&input=)

Comment: I could almost get it to work, but then it enters an infinite loop...

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99657/56258)

Comment: @daHugLenny Hahaha, that's neat! I didn't think of that :).

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript, 22 bytes, 10 numbers, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99708/58563)

```
alert(0_6_4_>_0_2_0_7)
```

`_` is the hidden character.

#### Hint about the intended solution

The character that needs to be changed to generate all numbers is always the same.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99708/62131)

Comment: @ais523 Well done!

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes, 10 numbers, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99670/58106)

Attempt 2, this time without the three-char string :p.

```
_ [==_
```

`_` is a random character. Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=XyBbPT1f&input=)

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99670/58106)

Comment: @milk Nice, that was the intended solution :)

Answer (score 3):

## C#, 90 bytes, 10 numbers, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99977/54142)

```
using ______________________________________________;class C{static void Main(){_______;}}
```

I honestly have no idea how hard this is to crack.

Edit: Oops, transcription error. One `_` too few after `using`.

Now [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99977/54142) by [Hedi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58765/hedi), who found the intended (barring the class name) solution.

Comment: d'oh... one too short for write()

Comment: Didnt help... wrong gap. And that semicolon after first gap  thwarted amother idea

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99977/58765)

Answer (score 3):

### Python 3, 19 bytes, 10 numbers, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99811/21487)

```py
print(??bin()?????)
```

Unrevealed characters are marked with `?`. Tested in Python 3.5.2.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99811/30688)

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript 21 Bytes, 10 Numbers [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99817/43545)

```
alert(b_oa_"3____1"))
```

Unrevealed characters are marked with `_`

[Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99817/43545)

My Version:

```
alert(btoa|"3"&("1"))
alert(btoa|"3"^("1"))
alert(btoa|"3"^("0"))
alert(btoa|"3"^("7"))
alert(btoa|"2"^("7"))
alert(btoa|"1"^("7"))
alert(btoa|"0"^("7"))
alert(btoa|"0"^("8"))
alert(btoa|"0"^("8"))
alert(btoa|"2"^("8"))
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99817/58765)

Answer (score 3):

### Python 3, 16 bytes, 10 numbers, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99872/21487)

```py
print(?%??f?r?t)
```

Unrevealed characters are marked with `?`. This is probably a bit easy since there's only five question marks, but I'm hoping it'll be a fun one.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99872/16766)

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript 33 Bytes, 10 Numbers [Cracked x2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100095/43545)

Oops I post posted my line for generating 10 Which Hedi [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100095/43545) as though it was for 1

```
alert(_to__"_Xc0__0_B6____Zp=="))
```

Version intended to post for generating  1

```
alert(_to__"_Xc0__0_Bf____Zp=="))
```

Unrevealed characters are marked with `_`

```
alert(btoa|"0Xc0"-0xBf|!("Zp=="))
alert(btoa|"0Xc0"-0xBe|!("Zp=="))
alert(btoa|"0Xc0"-0xBd|!("Zp=="))
alert(btoa|"0Xc0"-0xBc|!("Zp=="))
alert(btoa|"0Xc0"-0xBb|!("Zp=="))
alert(btoa|"0Xc0"-0xBa|!("Zp=="))
alert(btoa|"0Xc0"-0xB9|!("Zp=="))
alert(btoa|"0Xc0"-0xB8|!("Zp=="))
alert(btoa|"0Xc0"-0xB7|!("Zp=="))
alert(btoa|"0Xc0"-0xB6|!("Zp=="))
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100095/58765)

Comment: I added a crack for the intended version. I'll try to find a way to get to your solution for 10:  `console.log(atob|"0Xc0"-0xB6|("Zp=="))` I think

Comment: I updated my [answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100095/58765) with what should be the intended crack.

Answer (score 3):

## Python, 10+ numbers, 61 bytes, [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99547/code-ladder-robbers/100537#100537)

Here was the code I posted:

```
try:x
except:print(__import__('sys').??c??n??()[????b????e???
```

The original code was:

```py
try:x
except:print(__import__('sys').exc_info()[2].tb_lineno)
```

Basically, it throws an error (`'x' is not defined`) and then prints the line the error was found on. So, just keep adding newlines at the beginning to increment the number.

I knew it wouldn't be hard to crack - I just wanted a funny way to print numbers - but I wasn't expecting Sp3000 to get it so fast, that's some pro skills!

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100537/21487) - amusing, but yeah there aren't really many options :P

Comment: @Sp3000 yeah, I wanted to make sure nobody could squeeze in deleting what's on `STDOUT` and printing a number, but I guess I narrowed it down too much. Ah well.

Comment: Revealing `sys` definitely made it a lot simpler, since it gave a nice starting point for searching :P

Answer (score 2):

### [*Acc!!*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62493/16766), 10 bytes, 9 numbers, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99602/55508)

```
?????????_
```

Works for 1 to 9. `?` is a hidden character.

Comment: Interesting one. [Cracked here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99602/55508)

Answer (score 2):

## 05AB1E, 11 bytes, [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99547/code-ladder-robbers/99580#99580)

```
3628801__0_
```

Works from 1-10. `_` is a hidden character.

#### Intended Solution:

```
3628801R¬0+ # 1
3628801R¬1+ # 2
3628801R¬2+ # 3
3628801R¬3+ # 4
3628801R¬4+ # 5
3628801R¬5+ # 6
3628801R¬6+ # 7
3628801R¬7+ # 8
3628801R¬8+ # 9
3628801R¬9+ # 10
```

Comment: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99580/41805)

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, 25 bytes, 9 numbers. [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99547/code-ladder-robbers/99600#99600)

```
__a__repmat(__one___,__)_
```

`_` is a hidden character.

Comment: @StewieGriffin Sorry!! Only 9. My mistake. I'm really sorry. Edited

Comment: [cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99600/24877)

Comment: Sorry =P I'm gonna post a replacement=)

Comment: @Stewie It's been my fault, sorry! I'll post a modified version later, since my original solution is different

Comment: For the record, my crack was identical to flawr's. I've posted another Octave one [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99604/31516).

Comment: @StewieGriffin I posted the new version [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99630/36398)

Comment: Just found a new, _very simple_ crack: `1%a__repmat(__one___,__)_`

Comment: @Stewie Heh, good catch!

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, 24 bytes, 9 numbers, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99606/24877)

```
_a__repmat(__one___,__)_
```

`_` is a hidden character.

(Inspired by @LuisMendo's [challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99582/24877).)

Comment: Oh you're way too quick!!!

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 9 bytes, 10 numbers, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99612/58765)

```
alert(__)
```

`_` is the hidden character.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99612/42545)

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, 26 bytes, 10 numbers. [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99547/code-ladder-robbers/99637#99637)

```
__a__repmat(_+one___1+__))
```

`_` is a hidden char.

New variation...

---

The intended solution was:

```
>> eval(repmat('+ones',1+''))
ans =  1

>> eval(repmat('+ones',1+2'))
ans =  3

>> eval(repmat('+ones',1+9'))
ans =  10
```

Comment: [cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99637/24877) but probably again nowhere close to what you intended=)

Comment: @flawr I have updated with my solution

Comment: [This](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99654/31516) will be my last (and hopefully best one).

Comment: @Stewie Looks difficult! That is, funny :-)

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, 21 bytes, 10 numbers, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99742/31516)

```
disp(fpr___f__e_(_'_)
```

This works for 1-10. `_` are hidden characters. This will be my last and hopefully best post.

Intended solution:

> `disp(fpr= -fopen(''))` and `disp(fpr=1-fopen(''))` for 2...10

Explanation:

> `disp(fprintf('_'))` will actually print `_1` if executed, so `fpr___f` was chosen to throw people off. The `f` was needed in `fopen` so there was only one additional space. `fopen('')` returns `-1` since it fails to open a file with an empty name. `fpr= -fopen('')` makes `fpr = 1`.

Comment: Last? Forever? For all of PPCG?

Comment: Are you sure nothing is missing here? What `fpr` is is quite obvious, that leaves four spots, that each need a closing parenthesis.

Comment: Nevermind, [cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99742/24877) (but is this what you had in mind??)

Comment: Oooh, the `fopen` is neat=)

Comment: @flawr. thanks :) I like the sequence you found too :)

Comment: To clear up why I was confused: I firs searched for something like `disp(fprintf(det('')))` but that had a character too much and only would have worked up to 9.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 4 bytes, 9 numbers -  [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99661/20080)

```
.__Q
```

Not super difficult, but should hopefully be fun.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99661/34388) :)

Answer (score 2):

### Python 2, 17 bytes, 10 numbers, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99682/20260)

```python
print len([????])
```

The hidden character is `?`.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99682/53748)

Comment: Nice, that was fast.

Comment: ...and the intended crack?!

Comment: Yes, it's what I had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

### [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 7 bytes, 10 numbers, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99774/8478)

```
1<@|!__
```

Works for 1 to 10, `_` are hidden characters. I hope I didn't overlook any cheap way to work around the intended solution (I'm looking forward to clever ways to work around the intended solution ;)).

[You can try Hexagony online over here.](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/)

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99774/57100)

Comment: @Riley Wow, that was fast (and that's more or less the intended solution; I had `_!` for the wild cards and inserted the `)` for 10).

Comment: So 1 would be `1<@|!_!` and 10 is `9<@|!_!(`? That doesn't seem to work for me (for 10, it would hit `9`, `<`, `_`, `@` and not print anything).

Comment: @Riley no, you'd still put the `)` after the first `!` to get `9<@|!)_!`.

Comment: Okay. Thanks .This one was fun :)

Comment: I added a new solution that doesn't increase the size of the hex.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 31 bytes - 10 numbers - [Cracked by ais523](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99919/60884)

```
__e_$a__<__$_;1 while_$__;say$_
```

_ is the hidden character.

I am not posting *my* solution here, because the crack is in a completely different direction from what I did, so I'll be creating a new challenge for that one.  The cracked solution is below:

```
 $e=$a+q<1_$>;1 while!$e ;say$e  #Prints 1 (note the leading space)
 $e=$a+q<1_$>+1 while!$e ;say$e  #Prints 2
 $e=$a+q<1_$>+2 while!$e ;say$e  #Prints 3
 $e=$a+q<1_$>+3 while!$e ;say$e  #Prints 4
 $e=$a+q<1_$>+4 while!$e ;say$e  #Prints 5
 $e=$a+q<1_$>+5 while!$e ;say$e  #Prints 6
 $e=$a+q<1_$>+6 while!$e ;say$e  #Prints 7
 $e=$a+q<1_$>+7 while!$e ;say$e  #Prints 8
 $e=$a+q<1_$>+8 while!$e ;say$e  #Prints 9
 $e=$a+q<1_$>+9 while!$e ;say$e  #Prints 10
```

Comment: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99919/62131)

Answer (score 2):

## R, 22 bytes, 10 numbers, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100298/62252)

```
_et_______)____is_____
```

`_` is a hidden character.

See the [redux version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100342/62252).

Comment: Cracked ( http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100298/10801 )

Answer (score 2):

### C++, Linux platform, 10 numbers, 468 bytes, [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99945/62131)

Ok so previously my puzzle played with technically undefined behavior (and the gimmick was stabilizing it) and had some transcription error. I have improved my process so I expect there aren't transcription errors. This time I am not playing with undefined behavior at all and would rather just reject invoking it. I think I can justify this as being completely defined by either the language or the platform. `$` is the replacement character as I needed real `_` characters in this puzzle.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

$$$$$$$$$$$$$ {
    std::ofstream *garbalgase()
    {
        std::ofstream *golgi = new std::ofstream;
        golgi->open("/dev/null");
        return golgi;
    }

    std::ostream * const jawbone = garbalgase();
    $$$$$ int value = $_$$$$$$;
}

int main()
{
    $$$$$ $$$$$$$$/$$int vl = value;
    if (fork() == 0)
    {
        $$$$$$$$$$$<std::ostream $*>($jawbone) = &std::cout;
        vl -= 4;
        _exit(0);
    }
    (*jawbone) << (vl - 9) << std::endl;
}
```

Edit: Stock solution is based on an incorrect understanding of the rules where you may insert one character to get the 1. As it's already cracked I won't be correcting it. Good luck finding the stock solution though.

Comment: Maybe you should specify the compiler and flags a solution has to work under? I have a crack, but it needs `-fpermissive`.

Comment: @Lynn: There's a way of getting rid of the need of -fpermissive.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99945/62131). I assume this isn't the intended solution.

Answer (score 2):

### Python 2, 26 bytes, 10 numbers, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99871/21487)

Let's try this again.

```
print r___e(3______+_[___]
```

Works for 1-10; `_` is the hidden character.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99871/21487) - also if you're reposting, be careful of newlines, because I feel like something might be workable with those too.

Answer (score 2):

### Java, 10+ digits, 1446 bytes SAFE

Revenge of the Unicode

```
\u___9\u___D\u___0\u___F\u___2\u___4\u___0\u___A\u___1\u___6\u___1\u___E\u___9\u___F\u___E\u___A\u___B\u___3\u___C\u___1\u___3\u___3\u___0\u___D\u___B\u___0\u___5\u___2\u___C\u___9\u___3\u___0\u___3\u___4\u___1\u___4\u___9\u___3\u___0\u___6\u___F\u___9\u___4\u___0\u___D\u___1\u___9\u___E\u___8\u___3\u___4\u___2\u___9\u___E\u___7\u___B\u___D\u___1\u___9\u___4\u___8\u___2\u___F\u___7\u___3\u___0\u___5\u___8\u___3\u___5\u___0\u___4\u___9\u___F\u___E\u___B\u___6\u___9\u___C\u___5\u___4\u___5\u___3\u___3\u___2\u___9\u___0\u___4\u___F\u___2\u___0\u___6\u___4\u___0\u___D\u___0\u___E\u___5\u___7\u___0\u___6\u___9\u___C\u___5\u___4\u___5\u___3\u___3\u___2\u___9\u___0\u___4\u___F\u___2\u___8\u___9\u___B\u___3\u___5\u___E\u___E\u___D\u___9\u___3\u___3\u___E\u___3\u___8\u___1\u___2\u___5\u___4\u___3\u___5\u___3\u___2\u___5\u___4\u___3\u___E\u___7\u___5\u___4\u___A\u___1\u___6\u___1\u___9\u___F\u___6\u___9\u___C\u___5\u___4\u___5\u___3\u___3\u___2\u___9\u___0\u___4\u___F\u___2\u___1\u___3\u___3\u___5\u___3\u___3\u___8\u___9\u___E\u___3\u___5\u___4\u___8\u___6\u___4\u___C\u___1\u___9\u___B\u___E\u___5\u___7\u___0\u___0\u___2\u___9\u___E\u___4\u___3\u___4\u___2\u___5\u___1\u___D\u___8\u___E\u___5\u___7\u___0\u___6\u___9\u___C\u___5\u___F\u___5\u___4\u___0\u___5\u___4\u___3\u___4\u___2\u___5\u___1\u___D\u___8\u___6\u___4\u___9\u___9\u___E\u___0\u___2\u___9\u___E\u___4\u___8\u___7\u1__1\u___7\u___5\u___7\u___1\u___7\u___9\u___B\u___D\u___D
```

No comments this time :P and it only works on the Oracle Java :P

`_` as redaction like usual

Solution:

```
\u0069\u006D\u0070\u006F\u0072\u0074\u0020\u006A\u0061\u0076\u0061\u002E\u0069\u006F\u002E\u002A\u003B\u0063\u006C\u0061\u0073\u0073\u0020\u004D\u007B\u0070\u0075\u0062\u006C\u0069\u0063\u0020\u0073\u0074\u0061\u0074\u0069\u0063\u0020\u0076\u006F\u0069\u0064\u0020\u006D\u0061\u0069\u006E\u0028\u0053\u0074\u0072\u0069\u006E\u0067\u005B\u005D\u0061\u0029\u0074\u0068\u0072\u006F\u0077\u0073\u0020\u0045\u0078\u0063\u0065\u0070\u0074\u0069\u006F\u006E\u007B\u0046\u0069\u006C\u0065\u0044\u0065\u0073\u0063\u0072\u0069\u0070\u0074\u006F\u0072\u0020\u0066\u0064\u0020\u003D\u0020\u006E\u0065\u0077\u0020\u0046\u0069\u006C\u0065\u0044\u0065\u0073\u0063\u0072\u0069\u0070\u0074\u006F\u0072\u0028\u0029\u003B\u0073\u0075\u006E\u002E\u006D\u0069\u0073\u0063\u002E\u0053\u0068\u0061\u0072\u0065\u0064\u0053\u0065\u0063\u0072\u0065\u0074\u0073\u002E\u0067\u0065\u0074\u004A\u0061\u0076\u0061\u0049\u004F\u0046\u0069\u006C\u0065\u0044\u0065\u0073\u0063\u0072\u0069\u0070\u0074\u006F\u0072\u0041\u0063\u0063\u0065\u0073\u0073\u0028\u0029\u002E\u0073\u0065\u0074\u0028\u0066\u0064\u002C\u0031\u0029\u003B\u006E\u0065\u0077\u0020\u0050\u0072\u0069\u006E\u0074\u0053\u0074\u0072\u0065\u0061\u006D\u0028\u006E\u0065\u0077\u0020\u0046\u0069\u006C\u0065\u004F\u0075\u0074\u0070\u0075\u0074\u0053\u0074\u0072\u0065\u0061\u006D\u0028\u0066\u0064\u0029\u0029\u002E\u0070\u0072\u0069\u006E\u0074\u0028\u0027\u1111\u0027\u0025\u0027\u0111\u0027\u0029\u003B\u007D\u007D
```

Deobfuscated:

```
import java.io.*;class M{public static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{FileDescriptor fd = new FileDescriptor();sun.misc.SharedSecrets.getJavaIOFileDescriptorAccess().set(fd,1);new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(fd)).print('\u1111'%'\u0111');}}
```

Entire Thing relies on some dirty Oracle Java classes trickery to link a Filedescriptor object to the 1 Filedescriptor which is stdout

Got the hack from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10090215/1405227)

Comment: Got up to the initialisation of `FileDescriptor fd`, then I got stuck

Comment: timezone checking, need to know if the 7days are over

Comment: @KritixiLithos Solution uncovered since its safe

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 31 bytes, 10 numbers [Cracked by ais523](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100185/60884)

One more go at this, before I reveal my intended solution.

```
__e_$a,_<__$_;1 while_$a_;say$_
```

Original code:

```
open$a,"<",$0;1 while<$a>;say$.  #Prints 1
```

The code must be saved as a file and not run from the command line, but the file name is not important, as it gets stored in `$0`.  This code reads the file as long as there is text left, and prints `$.` which contains the number of lines in the original code.  Adding a newline pretty much anywhere not inside a word or variable will increase `$.` by 1.

```
open$a,"<",$0;
1 while<$a>;say$.   #Prints 2
------
open$a,"<",$0;

1 while<$a>;say$.   #Prints 3
------
```

et cetera

Comment: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100185/62131). This is almost certainly the intended solution.

Answer (score 2):

### [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 15 bytes, 10 numbers, [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100045/59806)

```
[!?>!@!__\!?!!!
```

`_` can be replaced by any characters.

Oh my.. the code is getting angry due to cheap solutions! Will this keep standing when the wall of `!` and `?` are guarding the most hearted secret?

Last submission even if this has got any cheap solutions :)

#### Intended solution

For 1 to 9, there are easy changes:

> `[!?>!@!1#\!?!!!`  With 1~9 replacing the 1

However for 10,

> `1!?>!@!9#\!?!!!`  Which prints the 1 and then use a numerical jump so we run in a reversed fashion, which in turn goes to `?!` prints a 0 and stops.  Really wanted to make some that changes IPs.  By the way, all 3 submissions are with the intention to use `#` to print an 1 and then a 0.  See if I come up with other nice ideas - if yes I hope more people would find it interesting to play in hexagons!

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100045/8478) Is this what you were looking for? :)

Comment: Haha, impressed though not exactly what I have in mind. One more mirror, one more freedom - it seems that only `!` are real blockers :D Enjoyed playing this game!

Comment: Ahhh, I thought you might be printing `1` and `0` separately, using a `?` to get the `0`, but I couldn't figure out a good way to get a `1` back at the end and then move exactly through `!?!@` (plus irrelevant stuff). That's nice. :) (Too bad, it's so hard to constrain the problem sufficiently without giving too much away.)

Answer (score 2):

## ><> Fish 23 bytes [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99547/code-ladder-robbers/100177#100177)

```
"H__;v+2__?
  _  >l?!;n
```

_ is the intended missing characters.
Hopefully a bit more complicated than my last one but probably still easy to bypass.

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100177/8478)

Comment: @Martin Ender - Yep you got it, clearing the stack and using the implicit input being -1 :)

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 38 bytes, 10 numbers ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99547/code-ladder-robbers/100215#100215))

`<?php__n_p___(_n=___(__=1___echo___?>`

`_` marks hidden characters.

May be too easy, might have left too much freedom. Have fun!

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100215/62131). You left way too much freedom, unfortunately.

Comment: Good job, I'll see if I can repost this with less hidden characters without making it too obvious

Answer (score 2):

### ​O​C​a​m​l​ ​(​i​n​t​e​r​p​r​e​t​e​d​)​,​ ​5​1​ ​b​y​t​e​s​,​ ​1​0​ ​n​u​m​b​e​r​s​ ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100251/30688))

​
​B​y​ ​"​i​n​t​e​r​p​r​e​t​e​d​"​ ​I​ ​m​e​a​n​ ​t​h​a​t​ ​i​t​ ​s​h​o​u​l​d​ ​b​e​ ​r​u​n​ ​w​i​t​h​ ​t​h​e​ ​c​o​m​m​a​n​d​ ​`​o​c​a​m​l​`​ ​r​a​t​h​e​r​ ​t​h​a​n​ ​c​o​m​p​i​l​e​d​ ​t​o​ ​n​a​t​i​v​e​ ​c​o​d​e​ ​w​i​t​h​ ​`​o​c​a​m​l​o​p​t​`​.​
​
​T​h​e​ ​h​i​d​d​e​n​ ​c​h​a​r​a​c​t​e​r​ ​i​s​ ​`​^​`​.​

```
^^t^r^^^^-^^^^-^^r^^^^=^^^^^^^r^^^^r^^^^^^^(^^^0/0)
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100251/62131). The same trick still works, even though it's harder to fit everything in this time.

Answer (score 1):

## [아희(Aheui)](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Aheui), 19 bytes (6 chars + 1 newline), 10 numbers

```
봃法희
반_뭉
```

Works for 1 to 10. `_` is the hidden character. Shouldn't be that hard.

Bonus: It works for `0` too.

[Try it online!](http://jinoh.3owl.com/aheui/jsaheui_en.html)

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99601/25180)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 3 bytes, 10 numbers ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99603/53251))

I think it's a very simple one, and will easily get cracked. 

So, it goes like this: (hidden characters: `_`)

```
__Q
```

Comment: Cracked http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99603/53251

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, 21 bytes 9 numbers, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99547/code-ladder-robbers/99610#99610)

```
_a__repmat(_one___,__
```

`_` is a hidden character.

My idea:

> `a=[repmat(bone,0),9]`

Comment: Yes, I'm still trying to solve yours, but it is quite hard so far=) Hint: one of the `_` is just an space.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99610/31516)! =) Couldn't leave it be... That was a really good one! :)

Comment: Man, still not my solution, I'm going insane!! Can you crack `_repmat(_one___,__`? EDIT: Yes you can... `+repmat( ones(),1)` ok I'll post my original solution=)

Comment: @StewieGriffin I just wanted to mislead with the `one` (and I suspect LuisMendo wanted this in his original challenge too=)

Comment: I would never have gotten that... Haven't even heard of `bone`...

Comment: Haha, `bone` is one of a few colourmaps, I knew it from Matlab, as it is used to display x-ray images with the "analog" feel =)

Comment: I just realized several Octave submissions have quite simple cracks: This one for instance: `aa='repmat(_one_';,+1` (works up to `10`).

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 15 bytes, 10 numbers, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99615/42545)

```
alert(_+"+____)
```

Another short one, this time with an unfinished string >:-)

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99615/34388)? :)

Comment: @Adnan Aw man, that was a little easier than I expected... nice job :) My intended solution was `alert("+"+10-9)`, changing the 9 to smaller digits for larger numbers.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 12 bytes, 10 numbers, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99624/58765)

Let's play with arrays:

```
alert(_[__])
```

`_` is a hidden character.

---

I wanted robbers to think that the first hidden character was a `+`, but i didn't realize that would work.

Intended solution :

> alert(-[~0])
>  alert(-[~1])
>  alert(-[~2])
>  ...
>  alert(-[~9])

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99624/42545) (again)

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, 49 bytes, 10 numbers, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99633/60517)

```
y=10__;s='09________';print int(s[8__________:y])
```

`_` is the hidden character.

---

#### [Cracked by boboquack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99633/60517)

The initial code was

`y=10-0;s='0987654321';print int(s[8+y:]+s[y-1:y])`

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99547/code-ladder-robbers/99633#99633)

Answer (score 1):

### C, 10+ numbers, 216 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99660/14306)

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *a, *b;

void x() { ____________ int x; x = __; ________a___d____x_;}
void y() { ____________ int x; fprintf(b,"%d\n",x);}
int main() {a=fopen("/dev/null", "w");b=stdout;x();y();return 0;}
```

If your solution doesn't work with -O1 I will reject it.

[Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99660/14306) by Dada. Original file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *a, *b;

void x() { /**/volatile int x; x = 07; fprintf(a,"%d\n", x);}
void y() { /**/volatile int x; fprintf(b,"%d\n", x);}
int main() {a=fopen("/dev/null", "w");b=stdout;x();y();return 0;}
```

Comment: The maximum is 10 numbers

Comment: I'm not sure that you can arbitrarily add you own rules.

Comment: -O1 needs to stand because works only with -O0 results in too hard to guess what some other machine's undefined behavior does.

Comment: @KritixiLithos: The limit may be 10 but mutating it to get larger than 10 doesn't seem to be blockable.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99660/55508). I guess you had something like that in mind?

Answer (score 1):

### [PowerShell](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9864/42963), 7 bytes, 10 numbers, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99680/42963)

Works for 1 through 10. Hidden characters are `_`.

```
___(__0
```

Intended solution: `+!@()+0` and swap out the `0` on the end for successively larger numbers.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99680/55508). I'm curious to know if this is the original code though.

Comment: @Dada That is not the original code, but a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 70 bytes, 10 Numbers, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99730/41805)

`__________________________ ____(_____________________________)________`

`_` is the hidden character

Edit: major flaw fixed

Comment: Is this a full program?

Comment: yeah :P golfed though

Comment: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99730/41805)

Answer (score 1):

## ><> Fish 5 bytes 10 numbers [Cracked by Emigna](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99547/code-ladder-robbers/99763#99763)

```
_2__;
```

It should be easy to guess but I threw in a little curve ball to make it slightly harder.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99763/47066)

Comment: @Emigna it's very hard to make this not work in Fish but my original was i2+n; maybe I should work on a new one aha.

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript 19 bytes 10 numbers [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99547/code-ladder-robbers/99789#99789)

```
alert((_1*1_10__1_)
```

Unrevealed characters are marked with `_`

[Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99547/code-ladder-robbers/99789#99789) Guess i should have blotted better

```
alert((11*1+10)%10)
alert((11*2+10)%10)
alert((11*3+10)%10)
alert((11*4+10)%10)
alert((11*5+10)%10)
alert((11*6+10)%10)
alert((11*7+10)%10)
alert((11*8+10)%10)
alert((11*9+10)%10)
alert((11*9+10)%11)
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99789/57100)

Answer (score 1):

### QBasic, 13 bytes, 10 numbers, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99852/14306)

```
__I_T__O_(3))
```

Works for 1-10. `_` is the hidden character.

Comment: Cracked! http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99852/14306

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 63 bytes, 10 numbers, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99904)

This challenge is quite fun, so here's one last submission. :-)

```
eval([...(n=0,"l?0?a?(?x?")].sort(_=>[...????+[]][n++]).join``)
```

`?` is a hidden character.

**NB:** similarly to my two other entries, this code is supposed to *print* (not return) `1`.

Comment: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99904)

Answer (score 1):

## R, 8 bytes, 10 numbers, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99902/39451)

```
_a___+__
```

Original solution (as the cracked is a little different, but works):

> cat(1+0)
>  cat(1+1)
>  ...
>  cat(1+8)
>  cat(1+9)

Comment: [Possibly cracked...](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99902)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 26 bytes, 10 numbers [Cracked by ais523](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99934/60884) and [Sunny Pun](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99933/60884)

```
____;@a=($_..10);say$a[__]
```

I'm almost positive there's an alternate solution to this problem, but let's see if anyone else can find it because I haven't been able to see it.

Edit: It looks like two people managed to circumvent what I was trying to do!

ais523's solution:

```
____;@a=($|..10);say$a[+1]  #Prints 1
____;@a=($|..10);say$a[1+1] #Prints 2
...
____;@a=($|..10);say$a[9+1] #Prints 10
```

Sunny Pun's solution:

```
$_=0;@a=($_..10);say$a[+1]  #Prints 1
...
$_=9;@a=($_..10);say$a[+1]  #Prints 10
```

Intended solution:

```
$[=1;@a=($[..10);say$a[$[]  #Prints 1
$[=2;@a=($[..10);say$a[$[]  #Prints 2
$[=3;@a=($[..10);say$a[$[]  #Prints 3
$[=4;@a=($[..10);say$a[$[]  #Prints 4
$[=5;@a=($[..10);say$a[$[]  #Prints 5
$[=5;@a=($[..10);say$a[-$[]  #Prints 6
$[=4;@a=($[..10);say$a[-$[]  #Prints 7
$[=3;@a=($[..10);say$a[-$[]  #Prints 8
$[=2;@a=($[..10);say$a[-$[]  #Prints 9
$[=1;@a=($[..10);say$a[-$[]  #Prints 10
```

While deprecated, `$[` still allows you to modify the indexing of arrays (typically, 0-based).  It prints a warning to STDERR, but OP says that any output to STDERR can be ignored.

Comment: Here's your alternate solution: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99934/62131)

Comment: Please check if [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99933/59806) is an alternate solution or not :)

Comment: I'm guessing Sunny Pun's crack is the intended solution. (Interestingly, starting from Sunny Pun's version of the string, you can get from 1 up to 10 using either of our methods.)

Comment: Surprisingly, neither of you got the intended solution.  I should have added one more byte, which would have made both of your answers wrong.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 31 bytes, 10 numbers [Cracked by ais523](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99931/60884)

```
__e_$a__<__$_;1 while_$a_;say$_
```

My [original post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99824/62131) was cracked with a solution that wasn't even in the realm of what I was going for, so I'm adding a single extra byte that renders the previous solution (hopefully) unsalvageable.

Once again cracked in a way I haven't accounted for:

```
the;$a+=<1\$>;1 while!$a ;say$a #Prints 1
the;$a+=<1\$>+1 while!$a ;say$a #Prints 2
...
the;$a+=<1\$>+9 while!$a ;say$a #Prints 10
```

Comment: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99931/62131). Not quite the same principle this time, but still close enough.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 7 bytes, 9 numbers, [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99971/62131)

```
say$_-_
```

Underscores represent unknown characters.

The solution (as found by feersum) was to use a literal control-F to replace the first underscore, thus finding the predefined variable that has the value 2.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99971/30688)

Comment: Isn't this 7 bytes?

Comment: Yes, it's 7 bytes. Apparently I can't count today.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, 26 bytes, 10 numbers, cracked by [feersum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99964/30688) and [Destructible Watermelon](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99991/16766)

<s>Third try's the charm?</s>

```
print r___e(3_4____+_[___]
```

Works for 1-10, `_` is hidden.

---

Destructible Watermelon got the general idea I was going for. Here's my solution:

> ```
> print r"10e(3246578+9["[0]
> print r"10e(3246578+9["[5]
> print r"10e(3246578+9["[4]
> print r"10e(3246578+9["[6]
> print r"10e(3246578+9["[-6]
> print r"10e(3246578+9["[-7]
> print r"10e(3246578+9["[-5]
> print r"10e(3246578+9["[-4]
> print r"10e(3246578+9["[-2]
> print r"10e(3246578+9["[:2]
> ```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99964/30688)

Answer (score 1):

## [COW](https://esolangs.org/wiki/COW), 51 bytes, 10 numbers [Cracked by Kritixi Lithos](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99960/60884)

```
MoO ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ OOM
```

Original code:

```
MoO Mo_ Mo_ Mo_ Mo_ Mo_ Mo_ Mo_ Mo_ Mo_ Mo_ Mo_ OOM #Prints 1
MoO MoO Mo_ Mo_ Mo_ Mo_ Mo_ Mo_ Mo_ Mo_ Mo_ Mo_ OOM #Prints 2
...
MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO Mo_ Mo_ OOM #Prints 10 (the last two operations were red-herrings)
```

For a Javascript-based interpreter to use for testing, you can go [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20130116215713/http://www.frank-buss.de/cow.html).

_ is hidden character

Comment: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99960/41805)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wentel x87](https://github.com/CrazyPython/wentelx87), 36 bits/8 = 4.5 bytes, 2 numbers

```
____________0110______00____00______
```

Comment: Is there an online interpreter? I'm having some trouble getting it to run from the version on github (I don't use Python much).

Comment: @Riley Download "main.py" and run `python3 main.py`. Type bits in and press enter to start execution. Pass `-d` to activate debugger.

Comment: Thanks, I must have been using python2. In the documentation (and the examples) it looks like `1001` 8 times would print the ASCII value of `11111111`, but when I run it, I need a 9th `1001` or `1000` for it to print. To crack this, which method should I use?

Comment: @Riley Go by the specification, not the interpreter.

Comment: Do you have a chatroom for Wentel x87? I had a few questions about the specs.

Comment: @Riley no, but you can ask them here.

Comment: I don't think I understand the `0001` instruction. If the execution pointer points to `0001aaaaaaaabbbbbbbb` and the value at `memory[current] == memory[aaaaaaaa]` then the instruction pointer is moved to `bbbbbbbb`? And, do you have an interpreter that will print the correct values when the intended solution is run?

Comment: @Riley 1. Yes. This is just a branch. Execution pointer is just what code is run. You can always use the source. 2.Yes - it's `main.py`.

Comment: I ask because output doesn't seem to match the specs (see above) and for `0001` in main.py looks like it moves to that instruction then moves 4 past the provided address.

Comment: @Riley Clarify, please? There's an example of a while loop in the examples md

Comment: In `ifexec`: `execution_pointer = ...` then `execution_pointer += 4` wouldn't this move the pointer 4 places past where it was pointed to? And for the output question, `10001000100110011000100010001001` should print `1` as far as I can tell, but it doesn't. I need to add another `1000` or `1001` (a 9th bit) to get it to print.

Comment: @Riley The array is one bit per entry, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48808/discussion-between-riley-and-crazypython).

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 111 bytes, 10 numbers ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100024/21487))

How about some random digits?

The hidden character is `E`.

```
print +int('''3EE5EE6EE0EE2EE5EE6EE4EE9EE1EE5EE9EE4EE6EE7EE5EE7E''')%int('''2EE0EE9EE8EE9EE2EE3EE5EE0EE3EE6''')
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100024/21487)

Comment: @Sp3000 Nice job, I don't see any `L` since `print` does `str` not `repr`.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that REPL does `repr` and hence wasn't the same as `print` - confused myself for a sec there

Answer (score 1):

### OCaml (interpreted), 51 bytes, 10 numbers ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100179/62131))

By "interpreted" I mean that it should be run with the command `ocaml` rather than compiled to native code with `ocamlopt`.

The hidden character is `^`.

```
^^t^r^^^^-^^^^-^^r^^^^=^^^^^^^r^^^^r^^^^^^^(^^^^/0)
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100179/62131). This works in both the interpreter (specifying the file name on the command line, which I think is what you wanted?) and the compiler, so it can't be the intended solution.

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, 16 bytes, 10 numbers ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100331/10801))

As a cop, it's my [duty](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2N9olXWriM) to keep this site clean and remove any explicit content. I found<sup>1</sup> a piece of code referring to a diabolical body part that I've decided to censor here using underscores, `_`.

```
ev_l('P_NIS'-2_)
```

<sup>1: Well, I found it on the screen after I wrote it.</sup>

Comment: gah... 9 and 10 are tough

Comment: "Krrrrk".... and cracked. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100331/10801

Comment: also: nice red herring at the beginning with the text :P

Answer (score 1):

### QBasic, 12 bytes, 10 numbers, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100354/16766)

All right, let's try this:

```
_INT(_O_(3))
```

Works for 1-10. `_` is the hidden character.

---

Finally, the crack used my intended approach. :P

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100354/25180)

Answer (score 1):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), 5 bytes, 9 numbers, safe

_ are unrevealed chars

```
__xx_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOLcn//z8@vqIi/v9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

### [*Acc!!*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62493/16766), 46 bytes, 10 numbers, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100142/30688)

```
?
Count i while ?????????????????
}
Write ????
```

Works for 1 to 10, with `?` as the hidden character.

---

Original solution:

> ```
> 1
> Count i while _/10 {
> Write 49
> 0
> }
> Write 48+_
> ```
>
> The initial accumulator value goes from `1` to `9` and then to `99`. Whenever it is less than 10, `_/10` is 0 and the loop doesn't execute. When it is greater than 10, the inner loop writes a `1` and sets the accumulator to 0, which breaks out of the loop and writes a `0`.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100142/30688)

Answer (score 0):

### [TI-Basic](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/home), 13 tokens, 10 numbers, cracked

```
DelVar A1→θ
__>A
θ
```

`_` represents a hidden token. Hopefully this isn't too easy xD

Comment: How many `_`s are there?

Comment: Two @KritixiLithos

Comment: Which calculator version of TI-Basic is this? (Keep in mind that only ["free"](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7822/what-constitutes-a-free-language-for-cops-and-robbers) languages can be used in [tag:cops-and-robbers])

Comment: It's TI-83/84 BASIC. Try https://www.cemetech.net/sc/ or https://www.cemetech.net/projects/jstified/

Comment: @Timtech It does seem to require a ROM in order to run, is that correct?

Comment: You should be able to grab 2.55MP from https://education.ti.com/en/us/software/details/en/B7DADA7FD4AA40CE9D7911B004B8C460/ti84plusoperatingsystem EDIT: Here's a tutorial I found online that can emulate based off of the .8xu from the first link http://frewin.weebly.com/ti-calculator-emulator.html

Comment: Is there an free emulator of TI available? The license of the OS says you may only use it with an TI emulator from TI itself (and I only found a non-free one =/  ).

Comment: Quick search shows a wabbitemu emulator. Check it out - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8FbN-iSRiCE

Comment: I only see 12 tokens. Regardless, the byte count should be present.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100146/30688)

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 28 bytes, 10 numbers, [cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99678/41088)

```
_____ (__________)_(_____*4)_
```

Intended solution:

```
print (ord("a"   )-(24   *4))
```

Comment: Cracked (python 2): `print (0+1+0*1000)+(0*0*0*4) `, `print (1+1+0*1000)+(0*0*0*4) ` e.t.c...

Comment: [the official post](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99678/24877)

Comment: Why did you include so much space? I'd consider that dangerous :)

Comment: @flwar to throw you off

Answer (score 0):

## <s>[ASMD](https://github.com/mcparadip/ASMD), 10 bytes</s> [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100253/12537)

```
1_**_**_*÷
```

Hidden characters are denoted by `_`.

This should be really easy to crack.

Works from 1 to 10.

Comment: Why is this non-competing?

Comment: @StewieGriffin The latest commit for ASMD was only a few hours ago and it was created today

Comment: [Cracked?](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100253/57100)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 10+ numbers 126 tokens

`____00________007____________00______________________________t____o_____in_(___"___42________00____00____".___________0)___;__`

`_` is redacted

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99810/30688)

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2, 26 bytes, 10 numbers, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99859/21487)

```
print r___e(_______+_[___]
```

Works for 1-10; `_` is the hidden character.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99859/21487) in a non-intended way, I believe

Answer (score 0):

## [ASMD](https://github.com/mcparadip/ASMD), 8 bytes, [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99908/12537)

```
____+++C
```

Works from 1-10.

Comment: `asmd.py` doesn’t implement `C`, but it’s listed in `commands.txt`. What’s up there? Also, you should specify if `_` is a wildcard (I assume it is.)

Comment: [Cracked, I think](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99908/3852)

Comment: @Lynn Oh. I will fix that

Answer (score 0):

### [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 15 bytes, 10 numbers, [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99961/8478)

```
\!?___<3__!?_<3
```

What kind of love (`<3`) is this? This is the love of Hexagons :P

I believe this is not a hard one but a hearty one (Pun intended).

Comment: Sorry, [cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99961/8478), but definitely not the way you intended.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 81 bytes, 10 numbers, [cracked by feersum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99995/6828)

```
require'digest/md5'
p Digest::MD5.digest('########')[n=0].ord^'straYNpraq'[n].ord
```

`#` is the placeholder character. Is this a standard loophole yet? Not that it's uncrackable I don't think, I've left in some weaknesses intentionally and I'm sure unintentionally.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99995/30688)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 33 bytes, 9 numbers

```
#__________________
riny
________
```

<sub>(how mysterious?)</sub>

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100002/42545)

Answer (score 0):

### [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 12 bytes, 10 numbers, [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100041/59806)

```
[!_>!_!1_@!_
```

`_` can be replaced by any characters.

Seems that love doesn't belong to here should not stay here, to keep the world more interesting :P

Spent time finding cheap alternatives.  So giving out much tips so that it is harder to crack (I hope impossible) with cheap alternatives `!_!`

Comment: Edited to avoid a cheap solution breaking my `<3`

Comment: I'm afraid it's still not secure. [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100041/8478)

Comment: Oh... then I should type up my intended solution - seems I don't have the mind to block all unintended mirrors... Thanks for playing @MartinEnder :)

Comment: Maybe try another one with fewer `_`? To be fair, it seems pretty hard to get a secure cop in Hexagony. I'd love to see one, but I'm not sure yet how to write one myself.

Comment: Mm... Basically the same for me, ready for a post edit? @MartinEnder This should be my final try :P

Comment: Fine by me, but you might want to make a new post at some point. :P

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 109 bytes, 10 numbers

```
from hashlib import *
h=md5()
h.update('__[_')
if h.hexdigest()=='88f4002e27b0902c7018359da9bc5b44':print(0+1)
```

Comment: Hashing functions are discouraged, as they aren't in the spirit of the challenge. http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7627/34718; http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10027/34718

Comment: This is 110 bytes.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100115/30688)

Answer (score 0):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 18 bytes, 10 numbers, [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100136/57100)

This submission works for 1 - 10. Unrevealed characters are indicated with an underscore: `_`.

```
.__{_]5[$@__=@_!!1
```

[You can try Hexagony online over here.](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/)

I posted a follow-up using the same indended solution, but with fewer hidden characters [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100170/57100).

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100136/8478) As I told Sunny Pun, I doubt that a program at this size can be sufficiently constrained with so many wildcards.

Comment: It's hard to not give it away but also not allow trivial solutions. If I had given [something like this](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=ICAuIF8gXwogeyBfIF0gNQpbICQgQCAuIDsKID0gQCAkICEKICAhIDEK&input=) would you have gotten it? `.__{_]5[$@.;=@$!!1`

Comment: That one is definitely a lot harder.

Comment: @MartinEnder I almost went with that one, but because I already knew the intended solution I thought it gave it away.

Comment: Feel free to post that as a new cop, still haven't figured it out.

Comment: @MartinEnder [Posted](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100170/57100) Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 56 bytes, 6 numbers, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99547/code-ladder-robbers/100175#100175)

Quite a simple concept, should be easily crackable. The 'mystery characters' are indicated with underscores.

```py
print(_______(str(ord(x))for x in ________).___________)
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100175/31516). Pretty sure you had something else in mind...? :)

Comment: @StewieGriffin yep, shouldn't have put so many mystery chars :P

Answer (score 0):

### [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 43 bytes, 10 numbers

```
((v(d f(q((n)(i n(s 1(s 0(f(___))))1)))))0)
```

Works for 1-10; `_` is hidden.

Comment: I think this is safe now...? 

Answer (score 0):

### QBasic, 12 bytes, 10 numbers, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100346/16766)

Previous version's red herring created a loophole...

```
_I_T__O_(3))
```

Works for 1-10. `_` is the hidden character.

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100346/25180)

Answer (score 0):

## R, 22 bytes, 10 numbers SAFE

```
_et___e_(_)____is_1___
```

`_` is hidden character

Solution:

> `set.seed(4);rpois(1,1)`
>
>  `set.seed(4);rpois(1,2)`
>
>  `set.seed(4);rpois(1,3)`
>
>  `set.seed(4);rpois(1,4)`
>
>  `set.seed(4);rpois(1,5)`
>
>  `set.seed(4);rpois(1,6)`
>
>  `set.seed(4);rpois(1,7)`
>
>  `set.seed(6);rpois(1,7)`
>
>  `set.seed(6);rpois(1,8)`
>
>  `set.seed(6);rpois(1,9)`