# Count the Unique Rectangles!

Tags: code-golf

In my [last challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/87189/52405), you were asked to find *all* rectangles given a `m x n` grid of them. However, it turned out to be very trivial as there actually was a mathematical formula I did not even know about to solve the problem! So now, for a little bit more of a challenge, how about calculating the number of *unique* rectangles, i.e. find the number rectangles that are all of different dimensions?

For example, consider 4 horizontal, or `y` lines at `[-250,-50,50,250]` and 4 vertical, or `x` lines at `[-250,-70,70,250]`. Graphing these on a coordinate plane with infinite dimensions results in the following `500 x 500` pixel closed grid, in which the length of each segment in pixels and the lines corresponding to their respected values from the arrays are shown:

[image: Example]

which contains the `16` *unique* rectangles shown in this animated GIF:

[image: All unique Rectangles in Example]

However, if the topmost line (`y = 250`) were to be removed, there would only be `12` unique rectangles, as the top 3 rectangles would be factored out since they each won't be fully closed without the `y = 250` line.

### Task

So, as shown above, the task is counting the number of rectangles rectangles with *different dimensions*. In other words, given an input of 2 arrays, with the first one containing all equations of all `x` lines, and the latter containing those of all `y` lines, output the total number of rectangles of *different dimensions* created when the lines corresponding to those equations are graphed on a coordinate plane.

### Rules

- The use of any built-ins that directly solve this problem is explicitly disallowed.
- If either of the arrays have less than `2` elements, the output should be `0`, since if there are less than `4` lines on the plane, there are no closed, `4` sided figures.
- The input arrays are *not* guaranteed to be sorted.
- You can assume that there are not any repeated values in either of the the input arrays.
- A `n x m` rectangle is the same as a `m x n` rectangle. For example, a `300 x 200` rectangle is the same as a `200 x 300` one.
- Standard loopholes are prohibited.

### Test Cases

Given in the format `Comma Separated Arrays Input -> Integer output`:

```
[],[] -> 0
[-250,-50,50,250],[-250,-70,70,250] -> 16 (Visualized above)
[-250,-50,50,250],[-250,-70,70] -> 12
[-40, 40],[-80, 50] -> 1
[10],[10] -> 0
[60, -210, -60, 180, 400, -400], [250, -150] -> 12
[0,300,500],[0,300,500] -> 6
[0,81,90],[0,90,100] -> 9
```

Remember, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!

Comment: `[[0,300,500],[0,300,500]]` should probably be a test case

Comment: @Sp3000 All right. I'll add that one as soon as possible.

Comment: @Sp3000 It's added.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yeah, you're right. There are `6`. I forgot to count the entire square itself! It's updated now.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Okay. Added.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 99

```js
(X,Y,Z=new Set)=>X.map(v=>X.map(t=>t>v&&Y.map(w=>Y.map(u=>u>w&&Z.add([u-w,t-v].sort()+0)))))|Z.size
```

Note: `sort` is not numeric but lexicographic, but in this specific case I don't care

**Less golfed**

```js
(X, Y, Z = new Set) =>
  X.map(
    v => X.map(
      t => t>v && Y.map(
        w => Y.map(
          u => u>w && Z.add([u-w, t-v].sort() + 0)
        )
      )
    )
  ) | Z.size
```

**Test**

```js
F=(X,Y,Z=new Set)=>X.map(v=>X.map(t=>t>v&&Y.map(w=>Y.map(u=>u>w&&Z.add([u-w,t-v].sort()+0)))))|Z.size
  
;[
 [[],[], 0]
,[[-250,-50,50,250],[-250,-70,70,250], 16]
,[[-250,-50,50,250],[-250,-70,70], 12]
,[[-40, 40],[-80, 50], 1]
,[[10],[10], 0]
,[[60, -210, -60, 180, 400, -400], [250, -150], 12]
,[[0,300,500],[0,300,500], 6]
].forEach(t=>{
  var a=t[0],b=t[1],k=t[2],r=F(a,b)
  
  console.log(r==k?'OK':'KO','['+a+']','['+b+']',r)
})
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṢIẆS€µ€ŒpṢ€QL
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bmiSeG6hlPigqzCteKCrMWScOG5ouKCrFFM&input=&args=W1s2MCwgLTIxMCwgLTYwLCAxODAsIDQwMCwgLTQwMF0sIFsyNTAsIC0xNTBdXQ)

A rectangle is uniquely defined by its height and its width.

```
ṢIẆS€µ€ŒpṢ€QL   Main chain, argument: z

     µ€         For each subarray:
Ṣ                   sort
 I                  compute consecutive increments
  Ẇ                 yield all substrings
   S€               compute sum of each substring
       Œp       Cartesian product
         Ṣ€     Sort each
           Q    Remove duplicates
            L   Length
```

Comment: Great job! +1 from me! :)

Comment: @PeterTaylor But it does work for that input...

Comment: @R.Kap, was this just because the test case was wrong?

Comment: Actually, it wasn't producing any output when I entered that test case at the time, but that was because I entered it in the wrong format. My bad. It works really well for that test case. Good job.

Answer (score 3):

### CJam (22 bytes)

```
q~{2m*::-:z0-}/m*:$_&,
```

Takes input as an array of arrays. [Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~%7B2m*%3A%3A-%3Az0-%7D%2Fm*%3A%24_%26%2C&input=%5B%5B-250%20-50%2050%20250%5D%5B-250%20-70%2070%20250%5D%5D), [test suite](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%5B%0A%20%20%5B%5B%5D%5B%5D%5D%0A%20%20%5B%5B-250%20-50%2050%20250%5D%5B-250%20-70%2070%20250%5D%5D%0A%20%20%5B%5B-250%20-50%2050%20250%5D%5B-250%20-70%2070%5D%5D%0A%20%20%5B%5B-40%2040%5D%5B-80%2050%5D%5D%0A%20%20%5B%5B10%5D%5B10%5D%5D%0A%20%20%5B%5B60%20-210%20-60%20180%20400%20-400%5D%5B250%20-150%5D%5D%0A%20%20%5B%5B0%20300%20500%5D%5B0%20300%20500%5D%5D%0A%5D%7B%60%3AQ%3B%0A%0AQ~%7B2m*%3A%3A-%3Az0-%7D%2Fm*%3A%24_%26%2C%0A%0Ap%7D%2F)

#### Dissection

```
q~     e# Parse input
{      e# For each of the two elements in the top-level array
  2m*  e#   Take its Cartesian self-product
  ::-  e#   Map fold subtraction, giving the separations between lines
  :z   e#   Map absolute value
  0-   e#   Remove 0, since trivial rectangles don't count
}/
m*     e# Cartesian product of the two sets of separations
:$     e# Sort so that mxn === nxm
_&     e# Deduplicate
,      e# Count
```

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 22 bytes

```
"@gd&Xfo!s|]Z*!S!Xuz2/
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=IkBnZCZYZm8hc3xdWiohUyFYdXoyLw&input=e1stMjUwLC01MCw1MCwyNTBdLFstMjUwLC03MCw3MCwyNTBdfQo) Or [verify all test cases](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=YAoiQGdkJlhmbyFzfF1aKiFTIVh1ejIvCkRU&input=e1tdLFtdfQp7Wy0yNTAsLTUwLDUwLDI1MF0sWy0yNTAsLTcwLDcwLDI1MF19CntbLTI1MCwtNTAsNTAsMjUwXSxbLTI1MCwtNzAsNzBdfQp7Wy00MCwgNDBdLFstODAsIDUwXX0Ke1sxMF0sWzEwXX0Ke1s2MCwgLTIxMCwgLTYwLCAxODAsIDQwMCwgLTQwMF0sIFsyNTAsIC0xNTBdfQp7WzAsMzAwLDUwMF0sWzAsMzAwLDUwMF19CntbMCw4MSw5MF0sWzAsOTAsMTAwXX0).

#### Explanation

```
"        % Implicitly input cell array of two numerical arrays. For each cell
  @g     %   Push cell contents
  d      %   Difference of its two entries
  &Xf    %   Cell array of all substrings
  o      %   Convert to numerical array, padding with zeros
  !s     %   Sum of each row. Gives a row vector
  |      %   Absolute value of each entry
]        % End for
Z*       % Cartesian product
!S!      % Sort each row
Xu       % Unique rows
z2/      % Number of unique rows excluding zeros. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 0):

**Python, 208 bytes**

```
import itertools as i
def h(x,y):
    s=[]
    k=[p for p in i.product(x,y)]
    for j,(v,w) in enumerate(k):
        for a,b in k[j+1:]:
            q=sorted([abs(a-v),abs(b-w)])
            if 0not in q and q not in s:s+=[q]
    return len(s)
```