# Letter Interpolate

Tags: code-golf, string, alphabet

This is a fairly simple challenge. Given a lower-case word, you must "interpolate" between letters. Here's some examples to hopefully clarify this:

Input: `test`
Output: `tsrqponmlkjihefghijklmnopqrst`

Between letters you must add, in alphabetical order, the letters between those two letters. So if you have `ad`, you must output `abcd`. If you are given `da`, you must output `dcba`.

If the letters are next to each other in the alphabet, nothing happens:

Input: `hi`
Output: `hi`

Assume the input contains a lower-case word consisting of ASCII letters only; no spaces, symbols, etc. The input is also never empty.

Lowest byte count wins; this is code-golf. If you have any questions please comment.

Comment: What is the output for `too`? `tsrqpo`, `tsrqpoo`, `tsrqpooo`, something else?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/74855/34531)? (numbers instead of characters).

Comment: I agree that it's a duplicate - converting between ASCII characters and numbers is a minor difference.

Comment: Unless McMastery clarifies on Jonathan's question and there is some significant difference regarding that

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
ÇŸçJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@3@4/eiOw8u9/v/PSCzOBgA)

Honestly? I don't know why this works.

```
Ç    # Push characters as ASCII.
 Ÿ   # Supposed to be range from [a, .., b], apparently vectorizes on lists...
  çJ # Turn back into characters, join stack.
```

Comment: [I've seen this use for `Ÿ` before](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/74860/42545). It's a pretty cool feature

Comment: It's mis-documented slightly, hence my surprise :P. `Ÿ 24 = pop a,b    push [a, ..., b]`