# Delannoy numbers

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, grid, path-finding

Consider a grid from \$(0,0)\$ in the bottom-left corner to \$(m,n)\$ in the top-right corner. You begin at \$(0,0)\$, and can only move in one of these three ways:

- Directly north \$(+0, +1)\$,
- Directly east \$(+1, +0)\$, or
- Directly north-east \$(+1, +1)\$

How many different paths are there from your start at \$(0,0)\$ to \$(m, n)\$?

For example, if you're trying to reach \$(3, 3)\$, there are 63 different paths:

[image]

This value is given by \$D(m,n)\$, the [Delannoy numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delannoy_number). One formula for these numbers is

$$D(m,n) = \begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } m = 0 \text{ or } n = 0 \\
D(m-1, n) + D(m-1, n-1) + D(m, n-1), & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Others can be found on the Wikipedia page

---

You are to take two non-negative integers \$n\$ and \$m\$ and output \$D(m,n)\$. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins

You may input and output in [any convenient manner](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods), and you may assume that no part of the calculation exceeds your language's integer maximum.

### Test cases

```
[m, n] -> D(m, n)
[5, 8] -> 13073
[5, 7] -> 7183
[3, 9] -> 1159
[8, 6] -> 40081
[8, 8] -> 265729
[1, 7] -> 15
[7, 0] -> 1
[11, 6] -> 227305
[0, 4] -> 1
```

And all possible outputs for \$0 \le n, m \le 7\$:

```
[m, n] -> D(m, n)
[0, 0] -> 1
[0, 1] -> 1
[0, 2] -> 1
[0, 3] -> 1
[0, 4] -> 1
[0, 5] -> 1
[0, 6] -> 1
[0, 7] -> 1
[0, 8] -> 1
[1, 0] -> 1
[1, 1] -> 3
[1, 2] -> 5
[1, 3] -> 7
[1, 4] -> 9
[1, 5] -> 11
[1, 6] -> 13
[1, 7] -> 15
[1, 8] -> 17
[2, 0] -> 1
[2, 1] -> 5
[2, 2] -> 13
[2, 3] -> 25
[2, 4] -> 41
[2, 5] -> 61
[2, 6] -> 85
[2, 7] -> 113
[2, 8] -> 145
[3, 0] -> 1
[3, 1] -> 7
[3, 2] -> 25
[3, 3] -> 63
[3, 4] -> 129
[3, 5] -> 231
[3, 6] -> 377
[3, 7] -> 575
[3, 8] -> 833
[4, 0] -> 1
[4, 1] -> 9
[4, 2] -> 41
[4, 3] -> 129
[4, 4] -> 321
[4, 5] -> 681
[4, 6] -> 1289
[4, 7] -> 2241
[4, 8] -> 3649
[5, 0] -> 1
[5, 1] -> 11
[5, 2] -> 61
[5, 3] -> 231
[5, 4] -> 681
[5, 5] -> 1683
[5, 6] -> 3653
[5, 7] -> 7183
[5, 8] -> 13073
[6, 0] -> 1
[6, 1] -> 13
[6, 2] -> 85
[6, 3] -> 377
[6, 4] -> 1289
[6, 5] -> 3653
[6, 6] -> 8989
[6, 7] -> 19825
[6, 8] -> 40081
[7, 0] -> 1
[7, 1] -> 15
[7, 2] -> 113
[7, 3] -> 575
[7, 4] -> 2241
[7, 5] -> 7183
[7, 6] -> 19825
[7, 7] -> 48639
[7, 8] -> 108545
[8, 0] -> 1
[8, 1] -> 17
[8, 2] -> 145
[8, 3] -> 833
[8, 4] -> 3649
[8, 5] -> 13073
[8, 6] -> 40081
[8, 7] -> 108545
[8, 8] -> 265729
```

Comment: May I take `m` and `n` as 1-based?

Comment: @Bubbler I'm going to say no, as the sequence is specifically designed for 0 based inputs

Comment: These look a lot like [Motzkin numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/66851/20260).

Comment: @xnor They are a similar/related sequence, but I don't think the answers are similar enough for these to be duplicates

Comment: I love these diagrams. Thanks for the challenge!

Answer (score 12):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
Żc@Ɱ,PṚḄ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o7mSHRxvX6QQ83Dnr4Y4WIP/w8sP7Etz//zcFAA)

Because I couldn't tolerate Jelly being tied with APL.

Again uses the formula

$$D(m,n) = \sum_{k=0}^{\min(m,n)} \binom{m}{k} \binom{n}{k} 2^k$$

but takes `m` and `n` as two separate arguments. This is essentially a port of [my own Dyalog Extended answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225208/78410).

```
Żc@Ɱ,PṚḄ    Dyadic link. Left arg: m, Right arg: n
Ż           Inclusive range 0..m (if m > n, the extra nCk terms will be zero)
    ,       [m, n]
 c@Ɱ        A table containing [[mC0 .. mCk], [nC0 .. nCk]]
     P      Vectorized product; [mC0 * nC0 .. mCk * nCk]
      ṚḄ    Reverse and unbinary; effectively sum mCk * nCk * 2^k for k = 0..m
```

Alternative 8 bytes, taking a single argument `[m, n]`:

```
c€ṂŻ$PṚḄ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/5UdOahzubju5WCXi4c9bDHS3/j@7WObwv4XA7UAKI3P//NwUA)

Comment: oh, I didn't even think about what xCk terms for x>min would turn out as, lol. That unbinary trick is genius tho

Comment: Clever use of `Ḅ` for \$2^k\$, +1!

Answer (score 8):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 19 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```
⊢/(1,2+/+\)⍣⎕⊢1,⎕⍴1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/@f9qhtQvX/R12L9DUMdYy09bVjNB/1Ln7UuwsoZKjzqHfro94thv9r/z/qmKGX9qh3hYIBUHCzBQA)

A full program that takes `n` and `m` on two separate lines. TIO link has an equivalent dfn for demonstration purposes.

#### How it works

It goes through the table of Delannoy numbers row by row. Start with the zeroth row of `m + 1` ones, and calculate the next row n times:

```
Previous row: 1 a b c d e ...
Next row:     1 A B C D E ...
```

From the recurrence relation, we can observe the following:

```
A = 1 + 1 + a = 2 + a = (1) + (1 + a)
B = A + a + b = 2 + 2a + b = (1 + a) + (1 + a + b)
C = B + b + c = 2 + 2a + 2b + c = (1 + a + b) + (1 + a + b + c)
...
```

Therefore, we can compute the next row by taking the cumulative sum `+\`, then pairwise sum `2+/`, then prepending a 1. The desired value of `D(m,n)` is at the end of the row, so we apply `⊢/` at the end.

---

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 13 bytes

```apl
⊥⍤⌽(×/…⍤⌊!\,)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1HX0ke9Sx717NU4PF3/UcMyMKdLMUZH83/ao7YJj3r7HnU1H1pv/Kht4qO@qcFBzkAyxMMz@P@jjhl6aY96VygY6Dzq3WwBAA)

A straightforward implementation of the Wikipedia formula, also used by multiple other answers.

```apl
⊥⍤⌽(×/…⍤⌊!\,)  ⍝ Input: left arg = m, right arg = n
         !\    ⍝ Outer product by nCk function...
      …⍤⌊      ⍝ k = 0..min(n,m)
           ,   ⍝ [m, n]
    ×/         ⍝ Row-wise product; mCk * nCk for each k
⊥⍤⌽            ⍝ Reverse and evaluate in base 2; sum of mCk * nCk * 2^k
```

Comment: Oh, nice base 2 trick.  I'm going to try that in my answer.

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 37 bytes

```hs
m#n|m*n<1=1|i<-m-1,j<-n-1=i#n+m#j+i#j
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1BroIwEED3PcUkmAjfaewUsZjfegJvQFyQ0Gj5tBBkQ@Ld@RXibl7evJln/fqzXbcsPglv/xM0GXo7zT0nbDUPnIxLwsEn7cEl7eJrF0zTM0gd9pnmr6EO6dHs@T7Tu@vDTjcXLIPOTpXHcDejrRtwv/M67JqxH0BCzIfRhSmNP42ZMW7inDH4HF@qAqG8A78C5ULl7MNqZUVlxBzhsmkqLqwqEc4rnoQoaeWtludCybhA35wKVikEsUEU9E2lVLmIViCcNvsP)

Straightforward recursive implementation.

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 41 bytes

```hs
0#n=1
m#n|j<-m-1=2*sum(map(j#)[0..n])-j#n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3BisMgFEX3fsUDC9VBO2qamtLYL5g/kCyEyIyZaEKSLgrz7xmb0M3jHc693B83//q@X1eBk5Eo4vTX1TxyadTH/IgkupF0mFpxOqWG8g6nNbqQTDsgIIENtObz6BL5NEd@pPXh/u2Xr5A8gt4vNrLUmMm7FsLtuT2HdhpGUJDr4xTSQvKiMU@WkyxfnCiC18BqSwZVA/wOshC6QC/WG2tZZSwYXHctyyuyFYPLhmchKrnx3laXUqsckO@6LJHVDMQOWch3VSldiGwFg/Nu/wE)

Based on a curious formula I found, but not quite short enough.
$$
D(m,n)=2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}D(m-1,k)+D(m-1,n).
$$

Comment: Should your formula be \$-D(m-1,n)\$?

Comment: @Giuseppe No I think it's right, because \$k\$ ranges from \$0\$ to \$n-1\$ in the sum. In the code I actually sum for \$k=0\$ to \$n\$ and then subtract \$D(m-1,n)\$ because, you know, bytes ;)

Comment: Oh! I see, wasn't sure how `[0..n]` worked, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>24 21</sup> 19 bytes

```
2#.[:*/,!~/],i.@-@]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcyxCsIwEAbg3ac4dShKmt4lTS8JFAqCk5OrdBKLuvgGvno8TYodAvd//PmfaaOrCfoIFShAiPJqDYfz6ZjMVl/ivlHrdzOqhx7qYUy71e16f4GDCXw@ySJb6JfE5GfhUiIXRKxIyNIiehLyQl0m0zk2odi87iTTYkgiS8TyxbDFX4X@O98OSmzTBw)

<sup>-3 thanks to the base 2 trick from [Bubbler's APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225208/15469).</sup>

<sup>-2 thanks to Bubbler.</sup>

Just this formula translated into J:

$$
D(m,n) = \sum ^ {\min(m, n)} _ {k=0} \binom m k \binom n k 2^k
$$

Comment: You don't need to explicitly take the minimum of `m` and `n`.

Comment: Meaning I can assume they are ordered?

Comment: Not that, but the values of `k` higher than `min(m,n)` will be silently ignored because one of the `nCk`s become 0. So you can do something like `],i.@-@]` instead of `[:i.@-1+<.`

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 45 bytes

```r
function(m,n,o=0:m,`$`=choose)m$o%*%(n$o*2^o)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/rvkpqTmJeXX2n7P600L7kkMz9PI1cnTyff1sAqVydBJcE2OSM/vzhVM1clX1VLVSNPJV/LKC5fE65Pw1THQlNBWUHXTsHQ2MDc@D8A)

Similar but independently-derived approach to pajonk's answer (version 2) - [check it out](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225223/95126) - but here maximizing [R](https://www.r-project.org/)'s vectorization & vector operators to avoid needing any loop.

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 38 bytes

```javascript
m=>g=n=>m*n?g(n--,m--)+g(n)+g(n,m++):1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcbBCoAgDADQ39nSBdGpYHbxR8JECt0io9@36PJ4x/qsNVz7eZPoFpvnVtglFnalkyWBENlChObrjy3G4Dy0oFI1xz5rAg8jwoTYXg)

Uses the specified formula, so will reach recursion limit on larger testcases.

-1 byte thanks to @dingledooper

-3 bytes thanks to @Arnauld

Comment: Does `m*n` work?

Comment: @dingledooper I don't think so.

Comment: It works from what I can tell; tested a few cases though not all of them. might overflow but that should be fine anyway

Comment: Oh you meant instead of `m&&n`. Yes that works, or I can use `m&n`. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that `m&n` works (e.g. `5&2=0`). `m*n` does though.

Comment: @dingledooper Oh true, will fix.

Comment: [38 bytes](https://tio.run/##HcbBCoAgDADQ39nSBdGpYHbxR8JECt0io9@36PJ4x/qsNVz7eZPoFpvnVtglFnalkyWBENlChObrjy3G4Dy0oFI1xz5rAg8jwoTYXg) by taking `(m)(n)` and doing the recursion on the inner function.

Comment: @Arnauld Nice, never thought of that!

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 49 bytes

```python
D=lambda m,n:m*n<1or D(m-1,n)+D(m-1,n-1)+D(m,n-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/38U2JzE3KSVRIVcnzypXK8/GML9IwUUjV9dQJ09TG8rQNQQzwYz/BUWZeSUaLhoGOgaamv8B)

Uses the formula specified in question, and looks like `m*n` works instead of `m and n`

-1 byte saved thanks to @CommandMaster forgot that we could use short-circuit evaluation

-4 again for @DingleDooper, genius one line short circuit

Comment: `D=lambda m,n:m*n and D(m-1,n)+D(m-1,n-1)+D(m,n-1)or 1` is 53 bytes

Comment: `D=lambda m,n:m*n<1or D(m-1,n)+D(m-1,n-1)+D(m,n-1)` is 49 (or you can replace `m*n<1` with `1>>m*n` if you don't like that `True` is outputted in place of `1`).

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.combinatorics math.unicode`, 65 bytes

```
[| m n | m n min [0,b] [| k | m k nCk n k nCk k 2^ * * ] map Σ ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY@7DsIgGIV3n@LMxph6rZfExcG4uBgnUxNEVNICFehgap/G9/GVEEttCPDxncPwXwm1SrvDfrvbLCCIvfepEmcuidecGmSKkszUSYiVvjAdsJCcqgsLD03kjRkQY5T/lmtm7TPXXFoY9iiYpD5cdsoOUGKCGaqG4oZGmDc0w7Slf2/Q9mJEfzdoixHGnip3fEFAIpyCSxyj3jmB12ktU8i1382dYnhC16/Ej5Dj80biSlRhhtVPGUto2ndf)

Inputs are re-used so often it's one of the odd times local variables are the terse way to go. Since recursion is generally verbose in Factor, I've gone with the formula

$$D(m,n) = \sum_{k=0}^{\min(m,n)} \binom{m}{k} \binom{n}{k} 2^k$$

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 52 bytes

```r
D=function(x)"if"(all(x),D(x-1:0)+D(x-1)+D(x-0:1),1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcxNCoNADIbhfU8R7GZCIyQzjhmFduVFiiAIYqG04O2nZX5wlfDw8r1jnO7Ld58/62s3Bzbr0pjntv1fmszRysh4S08@PAqSYJzMbDxBQLxC@wBxrO5SUAuqhGyOYKih@CFZIOiLdcxBKtZF23u1OZVzUnwSJeAqOZFzzlp1nDsm6GoXfw)

Using the recursive formula and taking input as a tuple (thanks to [@Dominic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen)).

Taking input as two arguments:

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 55 bytes

```r
D=function(m,n)"if"(m*n,D(m-1,n)+D(m-1,n-1)+D(m,n-1),1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYw7CsMwEET7nGJxGilZwa5keeUiqXSTgMGFFQjJ@RX9cDfz5jGfnONj@6XXd38ndWDS075N6rgljOowXMB9BMMttoCsc1QeIegrmCewI3GXRqQT4VCBQ1iHwn4tICAsHcxEgTsZL3bxYqvE5w37UgWBRq0jnxfWiqNqEMI8jPwH)

Using the closed-form expression from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delannoy_number#Delannoy_numbers) results in 56 bytes with a loop, but take a look at [@Dominic's 45 byte approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225244/55372)!

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>68</s> <s>61</s> <s>58</s> 56 bytes

```r
function(m,n,`$`=choose){for(k in 0:m)F=F+m$k*n$k*2^k;F}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzBCoJAEIbvPcVAHrQmmNl13bWwk/gYIUiSiLtgdYqefXNT9DCH/5uPb/Rl4du3bV6ds/GAFuuoLpqHc8978mndGPfQWaDzkFRFdRyi/mCnE7f@Un19GSsEk@zhdAWWpOXuT/RMNJsAJEK@KKzyCRiEbAYpkeGZLBWRKS2CxGuG1TQ1Ai0zPHlNCKElBYMQ0s2gzfc/)

Comment: [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/38U2rTQvuSQzP0@jQlMpM01Jo6AoPwXI1nHRqNA1tDLQ1AYzIJSBlaGmjqHmfxeNZA1THQtNTWUFXTsFQ2MDc@P/AA) by accepting ```m,n``` as 2-element vector.

Comment: (I was thinking all morning about how to use ```choose```, and came up with [this](https://tio.run/##K/rvkpqTmJeXX2n7P600L7kkMz9PI1cnTyff1sAqVydBJcE2OSM/vzhVM1clX1VLVSNPJV/LKC5fE65Pw1THQlNBWUHXTsHQ2MDc@D8A)... only to find you'd beaten me to it!)

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I think your solutions are distinct enough to be posted separately. Clever use of `%*%`! Also for the recursion: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##RcxNCoNADIbhfU8R7GZCIyQzjhmFduVFiiAIYqG04O2nZX5wlfDw8r1jnO7Ld58/62s3Bzbr0pjntv1fmszRysh4S08@PAqSYJzMbDxBQLxC@wBxrO5SUAuqhGyOYKih@CFZIOiLdcxBKtZF23u1OZVzUnwSJeAqOZFzzlp1nDsm6GoXfw "R – Try It Online")

Comment: Ok - I posted my version of the ```choose``` one, but the recursive one is definitely yours!

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 31 bytes

```
Total//@DiamondMatrix@Table@##&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZJPa9tAEMXv@hRGCaUFmUizf0Vi40Jy6KFQiG@qDqrrNAuyZBQFDCGf3ZX27a729kajmd@bmT014@vx1Izm0FxfNtd9Pzbt3d3u0TSnvvv7sxkHc9ntmz/tcXdz8@X62FfJh8n6z01ruuN9YjbpS/qwNffJr8F0Y2XW233/dDkPx7c303eVqbN09TXN@iz9ltZJ9jGXZc9T1@7f02UcmsNY3T4fBnMef3Tn9xGZLP3dpevt97adqtfbFXT9WV@rPFvl9fytSGZdRJoizSLNIy0iLSOtIq29LiJW4VnMarCE1WApq8EqrXYsFDsYqh0N5Q431VPEI88TVlMoJw8kZEDkKAFSIgBS4zeHdB0ck085FkGZhyqrKXCYh0pmA7dSKm0EKjF0AJYp9ABXKDQBV7OpC4@43HNLqymMxMMlCSmAGSHnxtWI3IpJ41eQiVwfoJnkU1ZEbBEeEQIKKxRh0wwRX3AinFdqZkM3thQIQVeFy7qFs1xNsYzwMuCRoHA06fF2lXJZ@jyf9HwAZbh26bLu3qUmtIIBnuezexUZUMGAsAEtD0V5B/Z8yjvASpV3gBlV2D@QylvgWrLSxm4HuRbzu9ORBx08KBvQ8jy192AfjQ4vwN5RhytgsdqbcHPqsIcFChckhaLyPw)

Returns `{1}` instead of `1` when the second argument is 0. To fix this, <s>+4</s> +3 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZJPa9tAEMXv/hRGKaUFmUizf0Vqo4Jz6KFQiG@qDqrjpAuyZBQVDCGf3ZX27a729kajmd@bmT0349/TuRnNsbm9bG/7sjz0Y9Pe35d705z77vlnMw7mWh6aP@2pvLv7fNv31erdpP3HtjXd6WFltslL8m1nHla/BtONldnsDv3j9TKc3t5M31WmTpP1lyTt0@RrUq/S97ksfZq6dq@P13FojmP16ek4mMv4o7v8G5FJk99dstl9b9uperNbQ9cf9a3K0nVWz9/y1azzSFOkWaR5pEWkZaRVpLXXecTKPYtZDZawGixlNViF1Y6FYgdDtaOh3OGmeop45HnCagrl5IGEDIgcJUBKBEBq/OaQroNj8inHIijzUGU1BQ7zUMls4FZKhY1AJYYOwDKFHuAKhSbgajZ14RGXe25hNYWReLgkIQUwI@TcuBqRWzFp/AoykesDNJN8yoqILcIjQkBhhSJsmiHiC06E80rNbOjGlgIh6Cp3WbdwlqkplhFeBjwSFI4mPd6uUi5Ln@eTng@gDNcuXNbdu9CEVjDAs2x2ryIDKhgQNqDloSjvwJ5PeQdYqfIOMKMK@wdSeQtcS1bY2O0g02J@dzryoIMHZQNanqf2Huyj0eEF2DvqcAUsVnsTbk4d9rBA4YKkUFT8Bw)

From Wikipedia:

> The Delannoy number \$D(m,n)\$  also counts... the number of cells in an *m*-dimensional von Neumann neighborhood of radius *n*...

Generates a matrix representing a radius-`m` dimension-`n` von Neumann neighborhood, and counts the number of cells.

---

Some other approaches:

**Multinomial formula, <s>38</s> 36 bytes**

```
Multinomial[k,#-k,#2-k]~Sum~{k,0,#}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZRNi9swEIbv/hXGW0oLMtgj68NsEyh0Dz0UCtmb64MJ2VYksUPWgYWQ/euprVdSRNpD4J2MZp7RzMj7bvyz2XejWXfXl8X1x2k3mn7Ym27XbNlDPv0o37bvq9P@/bxlBXu4fLx@G5rkbNhwWexMv3lMzCJ7yb4szWPy82j6sTH58nl4ejscN6@vZugb07Is/ZSxgWWfszZh5zmMrcbp8O@nt/HYrcfmw2p9NIfxe384jfCw7Fef5cuvu90UnS9T6PbSXhvBUt3O/5W8UDyZbWVtVerJ5Cyt4S5FnTSapdKaVVHo0tqIJikUTQdKH16KpFEsLWBMjtKHEileTN6CpZX3FtHJSZeRpkjzSMexItIy0irSOlQSV@VZ3GqwhNVgKavBwvUcC8EOxu8uXgbcFE8RjzxPWE0hnDyQ4AGxQgiQEgaQGscc0mVwzErYuQUo91BlNQUO91CJSbuWznPknkocGYDlCjnAFQpJwNV8ylJF3Mpza6spXKkKkyS4AOYEn7uuhuVaTBpHldshlwdoLqvarm5gi7BEMCi0UIROc1jVDSfCeKXGW3DXluLfp3H/cmSElwEPB4WhSY@3rZS3ps/3k54PoAzTrp3XzbvWhFQ6fozxc1OhALxDui2K8hXY8SlfAVqqfAW4owr9B1L5EioteW1t14NCi3nvdFSDDjUoa9BtPbWvwS6NDhtg56jDFNDY/3x01D00/gr9BQ)

**Direct recursion, 46 bytes**

```
f=If[1##>0,f[#-1,#2]+f[#-1,#2-1]+f[#,#2-1],1]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZRNi9swEIbv/hXGKaWlMlijT7NNoNA97K2we3N9CCFpBVk7ZF1YWPa3p7ZeSRFpb@94NHrmS37eTr/3z9vJ7baXy2H9cOj4arVp2KFb1ZytqP8SVc29hmK8/3j5PnbFm2Pj@/rohv1d4dbVofq6cXfFj7Mbps7Vm6fx/vV03r@8uHHoXM@q8lPFRlZ9rvqCvS1h7HGaD/@6f53O293UfXjcnd1pehhOfyZ4WPVzqOrNt@Nxjq43JXT/3l86xUrbL9@4aIwoFtt423A7m4KVLdxctUVnWam9KZvGcm8jmrQyNB/gMZyrojOsbGDMDh5DiYxoZm/DShm9TXZy1jzTlGmR6TxWZVpn2mTapkzyrCJLeA2W8hos4zVYKC@wEBxg4qZwnnBzPGU8ijzlNaVwikCCB0SJECA1DCAtjgVkuCEwpfJzS1ARocZrShwRoRqTDi1d5igilQRuAFYY3AGuMrgEXCvmW2TGlZHbek2pJJkmSXABLAi@UK6FFVpMFkdN2KFwD9BCy9avbmKrtEQwKLVQpU4LWPKKU2m82uIthLK1@vdp3L4cneF1wsNBaWg64n0r9bXpS3068gHUadpt8IZ5t5Zwlc0fY/7cTEoA75Cui2JiBn58JmaAlpqYAWo0qf9AmpiCtFq03g49aKxa9s5mOdiUg/EGXdfTxhz80ti0AX6ONk0Bjf3PT8fcQvO/0F8)

**Generating function, 46 bytes**

```
SeriesCoefficient[1/(2-x y),{x,1,#},{y,1,#2}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZRNi9swEIbv/hXGW8ouKNQaWR9mm0Bp99BbIb25PoTgbAXZOCQuZAn57amtV1JE2lPeyWjmGc2M/LYafndvq8GuV9fN/LrsDrY7fu27zcaubbcbGv7pkWan/P2JnU@Ms4cLO79Pv3RpP16/9U12tqy/zLd21z1ndl5sis8L@5z9ONgx2M4WP/uX0/7QHY@23zW2ZUX@WLCeFU9Fm7HzFMaWw3j49eU0HFbrofmwXB/sfvi@2/8Z4GHFr10xW3zZbsfo2SKHbi/ttZEsN@30HxelFtlka2drbkZTsLyGm8s6awzLlTOrsjTc2YgmJTWNB3gI5zJrNMtLGKODh1AiLcrRW7K8Ct4yOTlqnmhKtEh0GisTrRKtE21iJWlVgSWcBks6DZZ2Gixcz7MQ7GHi7uI84sZ4SngUeNJpiuEUgAQPiBVCgFQwgDQ45pE@g2dW0s0tQkWAaqcpckSAKkzat3SaowhUEsgArNDIAa7USAKuEWOWKuFWgVs7TfFKVZwkwQWwIPj8dQ0s32IyOKr9Dvk8QAtV1W51I1vGJYJBsYUydlrAqm44GcerDN6Cv7aS/z6N@5ejEryKeDgoDk0FvGulujV9up8KfABVnHbtvX7etSGkMuljTJ@bjgXgHdJtUXSowI1PhwrQUh0qwB117D@QOpRQGSVqZ/selEZOe2eSGkysQTuDbutpQg1uaUzcADdHE6eAxv7no6PvoelX6C8)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E),  <s>10</s> 8 bytes

```
WÝ€cPR2β
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8//PDcR01rkgOCjM5t@v8/2lTHPBYA)

-2 thanks to the base 2 trick from Bubbler's APL answer.

Uses the direct formula from wikipedia.

```
W     push the minimum of m,n
Ý     push the range [0,min(n,m)]
€     and map each number to
 c    the input choose that number, vectorizes
P     product
R     reverse
2β    convert from base 2
```

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>79</s> 67 bytes

```powershell
filter f($a){if($a*$_){(--$a|f $_)+(--$_|f $a)+($a+1|f $_)}else{1}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY1bC4JAEIXf/RXzsIHmCol0AQmEnruQjxFhNpKxXnKVAt3fbjsaBbvsd86eOVMWL6zkHYVw4qLCvk9SUWMFickiq03pmbKL1ZqOw6IuAc028YU40swi2x19hUJi6yrVB6bBA9PjoM/Cs0jMOaw4uN5sqbVhQQcTaA0AlnFgub74LjGu8QZr3eXTT4WyETXpjBbk2jsdwk0j6yLbXx86fQ6oAiBs4hilpOh3yMHnv9IfQtuhaeQdcT7y8bdmnCVXGar/AA)

- Saved 1 byte by using a filter
- Saved 3 bytes replacing the `-and` by a `*`
- Saved a whopping 12 bytes thanks to [Zaelin Goodman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/99902/zaelin-goodman)

Comment: -4 bytes by cutting one set of unnecessary parenthesis and using `--` to save a single `-1` . [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3Ra8IwEMbf@1fcQwaNS2ClqAMZFPa8KfooUmp3ZY7UdkmLQpu/vd61opDkvt99313q6oLW/aIxOq8sDkNxMg1aKLo6s1kZikyeCnpnIpVdKNKeQUdSvo6VUGuyRmSPpEfjsIu8H5IwUEkYK6CziCXDXMG7gih@WxIHEnp4gS4AEKUCcaaL1xrzBn/gA0S6Yseia03DXPYFhai33@w@W9dU5fr4R@lDwisAdm2eo3McvQ9p/H@uXI2hr3HTpL9Znye9fXwzzXLXB364AQ "PowerShell Core – Try It Online")

Comment: -7 additional bytes by putting the parameter outside the block, shuffling some parameters, and eliminating more unneeded parenthesis [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU3RaoNAEHz3K/bhCnfxhIo0CUhByHPbEB9Dkcas1HJq4ikJmPt2s6shhV12ZnZ29tRcsLW/aEyQNy2OY1GaDlsopPhRQ8ljITI1SJHdChkEpCqfJ1Eg4pPBDxlnyqGxOITOjYn0dCIjDVTLSDF507DWEEavK@Keghu8wOABiEqDqKnxesK8wyO8U1bMmxZtbzrmFT@oSdtv001vu6b6OvyR@zvhCIC0z3O0lq2PowDP/5HxZPqYkmb8ybie8e75Zr5l1XluvAM "PowerShell Core – Try It Online")

Comment: -1 additional byte (sorry, just missed my editing window) by shuffling parameters again [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY1bC4JAEIXf/RXzsIHmCol0AQmEnruQjxFhNpKxXnKVAt3fbjsaBbvsd86eOVMWL6zkHYVw4qLCvk9SUWMFickiq03pmbKL1ZqOw6IuAc028YU40swi2x19hUJi6yrVB6bBA9PjoM/Cs0jMOaw4uN5sqbVhQQcTaA0AlnFgub74LjGu8QZr3eXTT4WyETXpjBbk2jsdwk0j6yLbXx86fQ6oAiBs4hilpOh3yMHnv9IfQtuhaeQdcT7y8bdmnCVXGar/AA "PowerShell Core – Try It Online")

Comment: You can save another 9 bytes (down to 58) by switching to PS7 and using the ternary operator, but then you lose the nice TIO support: `filter f($a){$a*$_ ?(--$a|f $_)+(--$_|f $a)+($a+1|f $_):1}`

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 22 bytes

```
≔Ｅ⊕Ｎ¹θＦＮＵＭθ⁺κ⊗↨…θλ¹Ｉ⊟θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XUw5DsIwEOzzCpdryRSICqUC01CA/IWNY0jE@ogPJF5vbEpGGmk0l14wao9U6yml9enghgGuTkdjjctmbjqUfC92MhE4F2zfuPFxePjI/kLWttJbi26GTTBFJcFLsIsvE7WnMyYD8qPJyMWH3qDfX8M4qLi6DBJTBtXDbtZ6YMe6e9MX) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Uses @Delfad0r's curious formula.

```
≔Ｅ⊕Ｎ¹θ
```

Input `n` and create an array of `1`s representing `D(0,k)` for `0<=k<=n`.

```
ＦＮ
```

Repeat `m` times.

```
ＵＭθ⁺κ⊗↨…θλ¹
```

Add twice the cumulative sum to each element. (I have to use base `1` conversion because `Sum` returns `None` for an empty list. It was still shorter than adding the inclusive and exclusive cumulative sums.)

```
Ｉ⊟θ
```

Output `D(m,n)`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>47</s> 30 bytes

```julia
m%n=m*n<1||~-m%n+~-m%~-n+m%~-n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P1c1zzZXK8/GsKamThfI0QaRdbp52mDyf1p@kUKmQmaegoGVuY5CFpTFxVlQlJlXkpOnoaSSqaOgkmWloKKRqZqlqaTJlZqX8h8A)

Boring port of the formula.

- -12 bytes thanks to @Sisyphus!
- -5 bytes thanks to @MarcMush!

Comment: Save 12 bytes by redefining `%`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P1c1zzZXK8/GUMFewVDBSqFOFyiiDSLrdPO0weT/tPwihUyFzDwFAytzHYUsKIuLs6AoM68kJ09DSSVTR0Ely0pBRSNTNUtTSZMrNS/lPwA "Julia 1.0 – Try It Online")

Comment: save 5 more bytes by using `||` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P1c1zzZXK8/GsKamThfI0QaRdbp52mDyf1p@kUKmQmaegoGVuY5CFpTFxVlQlJlXkpOnoaSSqaOgkmWloKKRqZqlqaTJlZqX8h8A "Julia 1.0 – Try It Online")

Comment: @Sisyphus Thank you! New to Julia, didn't realize operators could be redefined that easily. Also nice trick with the bitwise not, that's definitely something I'll need to keep in mind.

Comment: @MarcMush Thank you, I wasn't aware that false and true were treated as 0 and 1 in Julia!

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 18 bytes

```
{0/x(+':+\)/1,y#1}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxVkEsOwjAMRPc5RRALQCA1juvYyVlYc4QKhLg7GRuQkJpP3eeZcW/jWZb78XwY5+tpoctjT6+UtpF3PW35tozryFtKlPN8fiu2v/13gOV5kbkUle7laONgJA4FK1GuqK1ONd9Nos9baBWwGlybNarQrQyW1Y1EvcWYwXaXc4wrqGaYopr3VbfitvbJItw0dbGgmjG+CsyV8EJcFLrIM6PBMrSCso47dUO+tRTDf5hzIj9yhaFLfSFr3DMVE5+NFEMivKcKv1D6QLk20drfXT9KOA==)

Port of [my APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225208/78410) that does not use the binomial coefficient built-in. See the linked answer for the explanation of how it computes Delannoy numbers using just cumulative sum `+\` and windowed sums `+':`.

```
{0/x(+':+\)/1,y#1}  x, y: two input integers
            1,y#1   (y+1) copies of 1; the 0th row of the grid of Delannoy numbers
   x(     )/        do x times:
     +':+\          calculate the next row
 0/                 base 0 = extract the last item
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 62 bytes

```java
int f(int m,int n){return n*m<1?1:f(m--,n-1)+f(m,n)+f(m,n-1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dUzLDoIwEDzDV@yx1ZaEg9GIxi/wxNF4qLwC0oW0BWMI314XwtU5zO7O7EyjRiWb/O374dXWGWStshbuqkaYQiBsunXK0Ri7OgdNLkudqbF6PEGZyvIpDNaMhitg8VkLGE/WhgXp17pCR93gop5yrkWmo5IdxInTV/DXPvKtZPYkQ8kW1mJh5JMp3GAQcKcv8S0@l0xLKVDGfE@rwG3Qncx@9j8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 45 bytes

```
d(m,n)=if(m*n,d(m-1,n)+d(m-1,n-1)+d(m,n-1),1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYtBCsMwDATvfUncyqC148g5@DGF0pJDQuj/IdWK3mY02vP53fLnvK7XtMuRxvae9vshbhnujz9kBAYIEt@b9DQGqlq90czN0ClVVia01aXL4jKrdoRxVZZmhRExQ3M0USKPiEkpVpVFZWb5AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 44 bytes

```ruby
f=->m,n{m*n<1?1:f[m-1,n]+f[m-1,n-=1]+f[m,n]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W1y5XJ686VyvPxtDe0CotOlfXUCcvVhvK0LU1BLOBQrX/CxTSoo11jGP/AwA)

Using the formula in the question

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 38 bytes

```
D(m,n)=\sum_{k=0}^mnCr(m,k)nCr(n,k)2^k
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kxgyyd9zi2)

[Try It On Desmos! (Prettified)](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6tppbob2vv)

Implements the formula$$D(m,n)=\sum_{k=0}^{\min(m,n)}\binom mk\binom nk2^k$$with the observation that \$\min(m,n)\$ can be replaced with \$m\$(or \$n\$).

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 17 bytes

```
]{(2&+/\@[&0>:$#)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKegnqZga6Wuo2CgYAXEunoKzkE@bv9jqzWM1LT1Yxyi1QzsrFSUNf9rcqUmZ@QrpClp69cpZOpZ/gcA)

Uses the same algorithm as my [19-byte APL solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225208/78410). I randomly came across the problem again and realized J has multiple tricks to shorten the code, so it is actually shorter than APL. Also beats [Jonah's J solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225212/78410) which uses the direct formula.

Takes `m` and `n` as left and right argument respectively.

`2&+/` part comes from [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206979/78410).

```
]{(2&+/\@[&0>:$#)   NB. left arg = m; right arg = n
   xxxxxxxxxyyyy    NB. This part is a hook, so it evaluates as m x (y n)
            >:$#    NB. n+1 copies of 1
   xxxxx@[&0        NB. A trick idiom for "repeat x m times to (y n)"
   2&+/\   NB. Evaluate next row of Delannoy matrix:
       \   NB. For each prefix,
   2&+/    NB. Convert [a, b, ..., m, n] to 2a+2b+...+2m+n
]{         NB. Extract the last element, which is at index n (0-based)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
ṂŻc@ⱮµPæ«J$SH
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9qZWxsef//4bmCxbtjQOKxrsK1UMOmwqtKJFNI////WzMsIDld)

Using the direct formula from Wikipedia.

```
Ṃ              Minimum
 Ż             [0, 1, ..., min(m, n)]
    Ɱ          For each in the input
  c@           swapped args: input choose k
     P         product (vectorizes)
      æ«J$     bitshift by [1, 2, 3, ...]
          S    sum
           H   halve (since J starts at 1)
```

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
_45Bs2¤ß€Sµ1Ȧ?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9qZWxsef//XzQ1QnMywqTDn@KCrFPCtTHIpj////9bMywgOV0)

Could use some work, probably.

```
             ? If
            Ȧ  all (m != 0, n != 0)
          S    take the sum of
       ß       this link
        €      applied to each of
_              (m, n) -
 45Bs2¤        [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1]
 45B           45 as binary: [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
    s2         sliced into size 2 chunks
           1   Otherwise, 1
```

Comment: I like the `45Bs2¤`. I had a naive 18 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw8zDyw8t1QbTQKL25HRtCOPQ0sMbDA9Pt////7/xf0sA "Jelly – Try It Online")

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Oh, I see. I didn't want to deal with calling on the chain that many times, lmao. Felt it'd be easier to take as pairs and then just generate the neighborhood

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 73 bytes

```
f: func[m n][either(m * n)= 0[1][(f m - 1 n)+(f m - 1 n - 1)+ f m n - 1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BCoMwDIbvPsWPJ53ILNvUDbaH2DX0IDZFwVYp@vxO7brlEL6Ej@R3rNY3K5KrfkAvtiUDK4n7uWOXGJxg0ycKEpISDYMcYttkf957mmGfD5bbpdFx03bwpyLsdUMdoPJwwd1DjTLA1xHBqVAcIERwClwjSZPr7QyaGnUeWM8w46DgWC0tH09RIs5fMX6Cj1dt4T4)

Uses the formula from the problem description.

Answer (score 1):

## MMIX, 64 bytes (16 instrs)

Recursive, so takes forever.

```
00000000: dc020001 52020003 e3020001 f8030000  ṇ£¡¢R£¡¤ẉ£¡¢ẏ¤¡¡
00000010: fe020004 c1040000 27050101 f303fff9  “£¡¥Ḋ¥¡¡'¦¢¢ṙ¤”ż
00000020: 27060001 f304fff7 c1050100 22030304  '©¡¢ṙ¥”ẋḊ¦¢¡"¤¤¥
00000030: f304fff4 22030304 f6040002 f8040000  ṙ¥”ṡ"¤¤¥ẇ¥¡£ẏ¥¡¡
```

Disassembled:

```
delannoy    MOR   $2,$0,$1
            PBNZ  $2,0F
            SETL  $2,1
            POP   3,0           // if(!(m && n)) return(1,m,n)
0H          GET   $2,rJ
            SET   $4,$0
            SUBU  $5,$1,1
            PUSHJ $3,delannoy   // $3,$4,$5 = delannoy(m,n-1) = f(m,n-1),m,n-1
            SUBU  $6,$0,1       // $6 = m - 1
            PUSHJ $4,delannoy   // $4,$5,$6 = delannoy(n-1,m-1)
            SET   $5,$1
            ADDU  $3,$3,$4      // $3 += $4
            PUSHJ $4,delannoy   // $4,$5,$6 = delannoy(n-1,m)
            ADDU  $3,$3,$4
            PUT   rJ,$2
            POP   4,0           // return(f(m,n), m, n)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>45</s></sup> 43 bytes

```c
D(m,n){m=m*n?D(m-1,n)+D(m-1,--n)+D(m,n):1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVFhT4MwEP2@X3EhIQFWYoExmIh@UH@FWwwpZRJtt1CixIW/Ll4LI5uRlOPdvXuv7cH8PWPD8OQIIt2TyIUnHzDxA0yXI/D9EWLlNsj6oZYtiKKWjgZFs2cE2FvReJ5OPt3FaQH4aLLlqn0VLzvI4RQTwBURSM0KCCQY8UP77FogR0FqOjYE1kaAmBq8uujn3ZGzlpejIohoghskQRpp6xi1K0pT3CNcx0mIaRCbncMwiaiGk5U5PkbO3nmDXqDdrG33HG67zSO@sUXgMo@sSVkdGjBzqGXJO5TRbIJ3oOpvfqic8xndm6ngzZUMlkvT7cI4tPO9BDpNwzP8Lrui5ZmW/9IK6fF/Xdc51ueJ/RUeG2ypHMsuCdgl@Pc62mor8eqCgCSgyDwiled8N7n3i374YdVHsVeD//UL)

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to [mousetail](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/91213/mousetail)!!!*

Comment: -1 byte using `D(m-1,n--)+D(m,n):1;}`

Comment: @mousetail That doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry should be `--n` instead

Comment: @mousetail Much better, sorry was very busy yesterday and didn't have time to look at it properly - thanks! :D

Comment: Smart one @mousetail

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), <s>50</s> <s>48</s> 47 bytes

```arturo
f:$[m,n][(0=m*n)?->1[+ +f m-1n-1f m n-1f m-1n]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?cRSQyZ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 19 bytes

```
Đ↓0⇹ŘĐ1⇹«04Ș⇹ɐćÁ*·+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yIRHbZMNHrXvPDrjyARDIH1otYHJiRlAxskJR9oPN2od2q79/3@0kY5JLAA)

Direct implementation of the formula on Wikipedia

```
Đ↓                     implicit input; Đuplicate on stack; get minimum of inputs (k)
  0⇹Ř                  create Řange [0,1,...,k]
     Đ1⇹«              2^k
         04Ș⇹          stack manipulation to have the range on top, then the input
             ɐć        for ɐll pairs of values in the two arrays, nćr 
               Á*      multiply the two nCr lists element-wise
                 ·     dot-product with the powers of 2
                  +    remove that pesky 0; implicit print
```