# Calculate the middle number of a row of the pascal triangle

Tags: code-golf

Write a function that calculates a row of the pascal triangle and returns the middle number, if there are 2 it should return their sum.

Example:

`5`

would return

`20`

Example 2:

`4`

would return

`6`

**EDIT:**

To be clear:

a) if the number inputted is odd then find then return the middle number of a row on the pascal triangle.

b) if the number inputted is even then find the two middle numbers of the row on the pascal triangle and sum the 2 numbers.

The nth row is using zero-based indicies. For numbers other than zero, this is the row which has its second number as the number inputted into the function.

Comment: So `nC(n/2)` if `n` is even and `2(nC((n-1)/2))` if `n` is odd?

Comment: [Very related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3815/70347).

Comment: @LeakyNun wait what's `C` in that context?

Comment: @Mayube binomial coefficient

Comment: Which built-in function may we not use?

Comment: @KSFT any, you can't actually write any code

Comment: [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/66127/8478)

Comment: Welcome on the site. I strongly recommend you to post your challenges in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) before posting the on main, in order to get feedbacks and help from the community to improve them.

Comment: @KSFT, I have removed that rule as it is unlikely for there to be a built-in function that does my challenge.

Comment: If the rows are 0-indexed (which is what I believe you are suggesting with "The nth row is using zero-based indicies") then it will be the odd numbered rows that have two middle entries. Note, however, that it is quite common to allow either 0 or 1 indexing in code-golf.

Comment: I don't see why this was closed; the OPs sequence is not the Catalan numbers.

Comment: @ChasBrown The Catalan numbers are very closely related to this sequence. Let `C_n` be the `n`th Catalan number, and `G_n` be the `n`th term of this sequence. `G_n = (nCn/2)` if `n` is even and `G_n = 2(nC(n-1)/2)` if `n` is odd (where `aCb` means `a choose b`, aka binomial coefficients). `C_n = ((2n)Cn)/(n+1)`. Thus, `C_2n = G_n/(2n+1)` if `n` is even, and `C_2n = 2(G_n)/(2n+1)` if `n` is odd. The sequences are very closely related, and so any optimal solution to this challenge is likely to be very similar to an optimal solution for the Catalan numbers challenge.

Comment: @Mego Indeed they are closely related; but they are not so identical as 'Marked as duplicate' would imply. One might equally say that producing the Catalan numbers should be 'marked as a duplicate' of producing nCk, as they are also 'closely related'. IMHO, of course!

Comment: @ChasBrown I don't know that I would have voted to close this as a dupe of Catalan numbers, but given that my votes are binding due to my gold badge, and thus only one is needed to close or reopen a code golf question, I'm not going to unilaterally reopen it.

Comment: @Mego With great power comes great responsibility :). No worries!

Answer (score 5):

## [Ohm](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 6 bytes

```
½⌠Ddac
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/I/f//0N5HPQtcUhKT//@3AAA)

If the number is even it is you calculate (n n/2) if it is odd (n+1 (n+1)/2)

```
         Inplicit input
½        Half
 ⌠       Ceil
  D      Duplicate on stack
   d     x2
    a    Swap on stack
     c   Binomial
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>7</s> 5 bytes

Saved 2 bytes using the duplicate/swap technique from [FrodCube's Ohm answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/129569/47066)

```
;îxsc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f@vC6iuLk///NAQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>88</s> <s>81</s> <s>80</s> <s>79</s> <s>74</s> 72 bytes

Thanks to @JonathanAllen

```python
import math
f=math.factorial
n=input()
print(n%2+1)*f(n)/f(n/2)/f(n-n/2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcZNCoAgEEDh/ZyiTTBTlCS09DASDIo5ikyLTm8/m/e@emsoYnuPuZamQ/YagN23lf2hpUV/grgo9VIkSK8UxViC2n6Odt5oYhQyjOmLLIl63x8)

Comment: No need for the `int` (saving 5), since division is integer division by default in Python 2, which means you can remove the assignment to `k` too and save another 2 with `print(n%2+1)*f(n)/f(n/2)/f(n-n/2)`.

Comment: ...and two more bytes removing the line `k=n/2` and using the code I put in the last comment for the last line.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly)

```
HĊµḤc
```

A monadic link, taking a (0-indexed) row and returning the middle number or the sum of the two middle numbers - equivalently the middle number of the row beneath).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/jSNehrQ93LEn@//@/oQEA), or see the first 20 values in the [test suite](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9qZWxsef//SMSKwrXhuKRj/zIw4bi2wrXFvMOH4oKsR/8).

#### How?

```
HĊµḤc - Link: number v
H     - halve = v/2
 Ċ    - ceiling, i.e. (v + isOdd?(v)) / 2
  µ   - monadic chain separation, call that k
   Ḥ  - double k (this is n: v if v was even, or v+1 if v was odd)
    c - that choose k = nCk, the required result
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 35 bytes

```r
function(n)(1+n%%2)*choose(n,n%/%2)
```

An anonymous function.

Since odd rows need to be doubled, `n%%2+1` is 2 when `n` is odd and `1` when `n`n is even. Then, I multiply by the appropriate binomial coefficient.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jT1PDUDtPVdVIUys5Iz@/OFUjTydPVR/I/5@mYaLJlaZhqvkfAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>40</s> 38 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n<1or(-n|1)*2*f(n-2)/(-n/2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpLCoAgFEbheau4Q68kPoZSizHKEupXxEnQ3s0z@@CUt10Zrve43uHZ9kDwWGyuQuGzLJ2MAsqxHtaOe8yVQAlUA85DWGPYTzQqNaERZho/9x8)

Comment: `(4+2./(-n/2))*f(n-2)` saves a few bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
c:2$×Ḃ‘$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/Zykjl8PSHO5oeNcxQ@f//vwkA)

Answer (score 0):

## Dyalog APL, 12 bytes

```
{k!2×k←⌈⍵÷2}
```

or

```
(⊢!2∘×)∘⌈÷∘2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbhOpsRaPD07OBrEc9HY96tx7eblQLlFEw4UpTMAUA)

**How?**

`⍵÷2` - divide by 2

`⌈` - ceiling

`k←` - assign to `k`

`2×` - double

`k!` - binomial with `k`