# A Fine sequence with fine interpretations

Tags: code-golf, sequence, integer, combinatorics

The ubiquitous [Catalan numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/66127/110698) \$C_n\$ count the number of *Dyck paths*, sequences of up-steps and down-steps of length \$2n\$ that start and end on a horizontal line and never go below said line. [Many other interesting sequences](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0012-365X(98)00371-9) can be defined as the number of Dyck paths satisfying given conditions, of which the *Fine sequence* \$F_n\$ (not the Fibonacci numbers and not related to any common definition of "fine") is one.

Let a *hill* be a sequence of an up-step followed by a down-step that starts – and therefore also ends – on the horizontal line. \$F_n\$ is then the number of Dyck paths of length \$2n\$ with **no** hills. The picture below illustrates this: there are \$C_5=42\$ Dyck paths of length \$10\$, of which \$F_5=18\$ (marked in black) have no hills.

[image]

This sequence is [OEIS A000957](https://oeis.org/A000957) and begins
$$\begin{array}{c|ccccccccccc}
n&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\
\hline
F_n&1&0&1&2&6&18&57&186&622&2120&7338
\end{array}$$
$$\begin{array}{c|ccccccccccc}
n&11&12&13&14&15\\
\hline
F_n&25724&91144&325878&1174281&4260282
\end{array}$$

Other things counted by the Fine numbers include

- the number of Dyck paths of length \$2n\$ beginning with an even number of up-steps
- the number of ordered trees with \$n+1\$ vertices where the root has no leaf children
- the number of ordered trees with \$n+1\$ vertices where the root has *an even number of* children
- and so on. For more interpretations see Deutsch and Shapiro's "[A survey of the Fine numbers](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0012-365X(01)00121-2)".

### Formulas

You may use any correct formula to generate the sequence. Here are some:

- The generating function is
  $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty F_nz^n=\frac1z\cdot\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{3-\sqrt{1-4z}}$$
- For \$n\ge1\$, \$C_n=2F_n+F_{n-1}\$.
- An explicit formula:
  $$F_n=\frac1{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k(k+1)\binom{2n-k}{n-k}$$

### Task

Standard [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) rules apply to this challenge, where permissible behaviours are

- outputting the \$n\$th term in 0- or 1-based indexing given \$n\$
- outputting the first \$n\$ terms given \$n\$
- outputting the infinite sequence with no input, either by printing or returning a lazy list/generator

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf); fewest bytes wins.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 58 bytes

```python
i=a=1;b=0
while 1:print a;i+=1;a,b=2*b+7*a/2-(2*a+b)*3/i,a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9M20dbQOsnWgKs8IzMnVcHQqqAoM69EIdE6UxsokaiTZGuklaRtrpWob6SrYaSVqJ2kqWWsn6mT@P@/oQEA)

Prints the sequence endlessly. The method substitutes \$C_n = 2F_n + F_{n-1} \$ into the Catalan recurrence
$$
C_n = 4C_{n-1} - \left\lfloor \frac{6C_{n-1}}{n+1} \right\rfloor
$$

Comment: @dingledooper awesome. I think you should post your own answer, it's sufficently different (and more clever)

Answer (score 6):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <strike>22</strike> <strike>10</strike> 7 bytes

-12 bytes by emanresu A (double welp)
-3 bytes by alephalpha using a clever approach

```
ꜝ$ʀƈ¦ṁȧ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLqnJ0kyoDGiMKm4bmByKciLCIiLCI1Il0=)

**How it works**

```
ꜝ$ʀƈ¦ṁȧ
ꜝ$               Bitwise not n and swap with input
  ʀƈ             Take the binomial coefficient
    ¦ṁȧ          Cumultative sum, take the mean and push the absolute value
```

Comment: [15](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLKgH4rJMaI4bmYw57FvHlOWeKIkT/igLovIiwiIiwiNSJd)

Comment: @emanresuA ... wth man

Comment: [10](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLKgCskxoh5TlnCpuG5gcinIiwiIiwiNSJd) (several tricks stolen from Unrelated String)

Comment: [7](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLqnJ0kyoDGiMKm4bmByKciLCIiLCI1Il0=)

Answer (score 5):

## [HOPS](https://akc.is/hops/), 19 bytes

```
C=1+x*C^2;C/(1+x*C)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kI7-geG20kq5uQVFqsq2RgVLsgqWlJWm6FpudbQ21K7Sc44ysnfU1wExNiAxUwQIoDQA)

The generating function of the Catalan numbers satisfies \$C(x)=1+x\ C(x)^2\$. The generating function of this sequence is \$F(x)=C(x)/(1+x\ C(x))\$.

---

## [HOPS](https://akc.is/hops/), 21 bytes

```
2/(1+2*x+sqrt(1-4*x))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kI7-geG20kq5uQVFqsq2RgVLsgqWlJWm6FluN9DUMtY20KrSLC4tKNAx1TbQqNDUhclAlC6A0AA)

A simplified version of the generating function.

It seems that HOPS on ATO is currently not working.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 61 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,v=1:sum(f(i,0)*f(n+~i,v)for i in range(v,n))or 1-n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcxBCoAgEEDRq8zSKQOlneBhjLIGchQzoU1XN9dt/4eXnnJEnlvz9nRhWR2wrFab6w7CC5IKBy94fElW9DEDATFkx/smqmTEnvTE7be0QpMycelCVxDbBw)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 50 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,v=1,i=v)=>i<n?f(i,0)*f(n+~i,v)+f(n,v,i+1):+!n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcsxDoMwDEDRs7DFtUFkLXF7FkQxchXZCKqMXD0Ny5/@@85lPpdD919v/llrFQ5GhSMpF@CXJntLUBrhIcHwUiqAci@kGOGJnVXxIyiPk6bYggiL2@l5HbJvjTYOUP8)

Another [47 bytes JavaScript](https://tio.run/##FcsxDoMwDEDR01Sya4rqgaUkcBaUxsgVshEgJsTVQ1n@9P5v2Ic1LTpvL/NvLkUiWKXRHnwcXDcYOw3WCyg@BYxORZJbEOPHAhfxBTS@Ww38DxEmt9WnXE8@glb3iOUC) answer but output `true` and `false` for `f(0)`, `f(1)`.

First, we write down following recursive formula:

$$F_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}C_i\cdot F_{n-i-1}$$
$$F_1=0, F_0=1$$
$$C_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}C_i\cdot C_{n-i-1}$$
$$C_0=1$$

Then, we try to merge two functions into one

$$f(x,1):=F_x$$
$$f(x,0):=C_x$$
$$f(x,v)=\begin{cases}\sum_{i=v}^{x-1}f(i,0)\cdot f(x-i-1,v) & x>v\\ 0 & x=v=1 \\ 1 & x=0 \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 48 bytes

Returns the \$n\$-th term (0-indexed).

Inspired by the Catalan recurrence [pointed out by Sisyphus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48931/sisyphus).

```javascript
f=n=>n?(g=n=>n?g(n-1)*(4+6/~n):1)(n)-f(n-1)>>1:1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxBDsIgEEX3PcUsupiRoJKoi1bwKiUViIYMpm3cELw6El29n5ef97Rvu87L47VJTndXq9esDd8w/BmQpaIdnsTl8GEaFCGT9D9rjBpU9WnB6DZg0HAcG64a1LkNIQhyBzAnXlN0@5gCThb7zIXat8@tQmWisSv1Cw)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 60 bytes

Returns the \$n\$-th term (0-indexed).

This is based on the explicit formula provided in the challenge.

```javascript
f=(n,k=n)=>~k&&(g=v=>v--?(v-n-k)*g(v)/~v:--k-n)(k)/~n-f(n,k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYzNDoIwEITvPMUeCNkV15@DF3HxVWiwEG2zNUB6IfDqtZ5mvmS@@Zho5n56fxfW8LIpDYJ6dKIk7e6qCkeJ0kbmJ0ZWdnQYMdJ5j3dmx0roMigPf4nSECb0dgEFgUuT4yFwveVS1wRrAdAHnYO3Jx9G7AyWq26Ut@WaD2jrqCm29AM)

Answer (score 4):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), <s>46</s> 41 bytes

```
f(n)=-∑_{k=1}^n(-1)^kknCr(2n-k-1,n-k)/n
```

A port of the explicit formula but with one-indexing instead of zero-indexing.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1q5oj0ifah)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hdplzbpejf)

#### Proof for the formula:

We start with the explicit formula given in the question:
$$F(n)=\frac1{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k(k+1)\binom{2n-k}{n-k}$$
Then convert it to one-indexing (making a new function \$f\$) by doing the following:
$$f(n)=F(n-1)=\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k(k+1)\binom{2n-k-2}{n-k-1}$$
From there, shift the bounds of the summation up by one, making sure to correct the shift within the summation:
$$\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k(k+1)\binom{2n-k-2}{n-k-1}=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}k\binom{2n-k-1}{n-k}$$
Factoring out a \$-1\$ gives the formula used in my answer:
$$f(n)=-\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^kk\binom{2n-k-1}{n-k}$$

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>22</s> <s>21</s> 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
xŸIc2Å€(}ηOÅAÄ
```

Port of [*@mathcat*'s Vyxal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/258124/52210), so make sure to upvote him as well!

Uses the formula: $$G_{n,k} = (-1)^{(k+1)}\binom{k}{n} + G_{n-1,k}\\
F_n=\left|\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=n}^{2n}G_{n,k}\right|$$
Given \$n\$, it'll output \$F_n\$.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/4ugOz2Sjw62PmtZo1J7b7n@41fFwy///hkYA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##ATIAzf9vc2FiaWX/MTXGkk4/IiDihpIgIj9Owqn/eMW4wq5jMsOF4oKsKH3Ot0/DhUHDhP8s/w).

**Explanation:**

```python
x              # Push double the (implicit) input (without popping)
 Ÿ             # Pop both, and push a list in the range [input,2*input]
  Ic           # Calculate the bionomical coefficient of each value with the input
    2Å€(}      # Negate every second item, starting with the first:
    2          #  Push a 2
     Å€ }      #  Map over each item where the 0-based index is divisible by 2:
       (       #   Negate that item
         ηO    # Calculate its cumulative sum:
         η     #  Get all prefixed of this list
          O    #  Sum each inner prefix-list together
           ÅA  # Get the arithmetic mean of that
             Ä # Convert it to its absolute value
               # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

---

**Original <s>22</s> 21 bytes answer:**

```python
ÝεÈ·<y>Ixs‚y-`cI>zP}O
```

-1 byte thanks to *@emanresuA*

Uses the given explicit formula: $$F_n=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k(k+1)\binom{2n-k}{n-k}\frac1{n+1}$$
Given \$n\$, it'll output \$F_n\$.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8NxzWw93HNpuU2nnWVH8qGFWpW5CsqddVUCt////hkYA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##ATkAxv9vc2FiaWX/MTXGkk4/IiDihpIgIj9Owqn/w53OtcOIwrc8eT7Crnhz4oCaeS1gY8KuPnpQfU//LP8).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ý              # Push a list in the range [0, (implicit) input]
 ε             # Map each integer to:
  È            #  Check whether it's even
   ·           #  Double that check (2 if even; 0 if odd)
    <          #  Decrease it by 1 (1 if event; -1 if odd)
  y>           #  Push the current integer, and decrease it by 1
  I            #  Push the input
   x           #  Double it (without popping)
    s‚         #  Swap, and pair them together: [2n,n]
      y-       #  Subtract the current integer from each: [2n-k,n-k]
        `      #  Pop and push the values back to the stack
         c     #  Calculate their binomial coefficient
  I>z          #  Push 1/(input+1)
  P            #  Take the product of the four values on the stack
 }O            # After the map: sum them together
               # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: I don't know 05AB1E but [this](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8NxzWw93HNpuU2nnWVH8qGFWpW5CsqddVUCt////hkYA) seems to work?

Comment: @emanresuA Thanks. And porting mathcat's Vyxal answer is even 7 bytes shorter.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
ḤrcµJNÐeḋ:L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9qZWxsef//4bikcmPCtUpOw5Bl4biLOkz/xbvDh@KCrFn//zEw)

Port of emanresu A's golf to [mathcat's Vyxal solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/258124/85334).

```
Ḥrc            Each of [2n .. n] choose n.
   µ    ḋ      Take the dot product of that with
    J          [1 .. n+1]
     NÐe       with every other element negated,
         :     and (floor) divide that by
   µ      L    n+1.
```

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 bytes

```
o2µḤœcµṬ-*ÄAƑ×ṂḂ)S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATQAy/9qZWxsef//bzLCteG4pMWTY8K14bmsLSrDhEHGkcOX4bmC4biCKVP/xbvDh@KCrFn//zEw)

Haven't actually tried any closed form or recursive formulae, but ignoring the special case fix for \$n=0\$ this brute-force enumeration feels elegant enough to post, <s>especially considering how the current golflang closed form solutions are</s>. Leverages the "even number of leading up-steps" interpretation--or rather, "first down-step at an odd 1-index", hence the special case.

```
o2µ                   If n is 0, from here on out, pretend it's 2.
    œc                Get every combination of n elements from
   Ḥ                  [1 .. 2n],
      µ         )     then for each combination:
       Ṭ-*            Produce a list of -1 at those indices and 1 elsewhere,
          Ä           take its cumulative sums,
           AƑ         and check that none of those is negative.
             ×        Multiply that result by
              Ṃ       the smallest element of the combination.
               Ḃ S    How many are odd?
```

Comment: Why is the 12-byter funnier?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Explanation pending

Comment: Wow, nice port! I tried porting it to Jelly but couldn't find the binomial coefficient builtin.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 49 bytes

Prints the sequence indefinitely.

```python
x=c=n=1
while 1:print x;n+=1;c=c*4-c*6/n;x=c-x>>1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8I22TbP1pCrPCMzJ1XB0KqgKDOvRKHCOk/b1tA62TZZy0Q3WctMP88aqFC3ws7O8P9/AA)

Based on the Sage program at the end of the OEIS page.

Answer (score 3):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 36 bytes

```
n->Vec(2/(1+2*x+sqrt(1-4*x+O(x^n))))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWN1XydO3CUpM1jPQ1DLWNtCq0iwuLSjQMdU2ATH-Nirg8TSCAqF1TUJSZV6KRpmFkABNasABCAwA)

Using the generating function.

---

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 39 bytes

```
n->(matrix(n+1,,i,j,i>abs(j-2))^n)[1,1]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWN9XzdO00chNLijIrNPK0DXV0MnWydDLtEpOKNbJ0jTQ14_I0ow11DGOhylXS8os08hRsFQx0FIyAuKAoM68EKKCkoGsHJNI08jQ1NSFqFyyA0AA)

Using this interesting formula on OEIS:

```
a(n) = the upper left term in M^n, n>0; where M = the infinite square production matrix:
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, ...
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, ...
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, ...
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...
...
- Gary W. Adamson, Jul 14 2011
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
~cŻÄÆmA
```

This calculates `abs(mean(cumsum(choose(-n-1, [0..n]))))`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/78u@ejuwy2H23Id/wMZ7Y@a1vz/b2gAAA)

The "negative binomial coefficients" are defined as $$\binom{-a}{b} = (-1)^b \binom{a+b-1}{b}.$$
And they are supported by Jelly's `c`. So we can rewrite the closed form as:

\begin{align}
F_n&=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k(k+1)\binom{2n-k}{n-k} \\
& \color{gray}{\text{(introduce negative binomials:)}} \\
&=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k(k+1) \color{#0bf}{(-1)^{n-k} \binom{-n-1}{n-k}} \\
& \color{gray}{\text{(factor out powers of $-1$:)}} \\
&=(-1)^n \frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{k=0}^n (k+1) \binom{-n-1}{n-k} \\
& \color{gray}{\text{(substitute $j=n-k$:)}} \\
&=(-1)^n \frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{j=0}^n (n+1-j) \binom{-n-1}{j}
\end{align}

The `~cŻ` generates the negative binomials \$\binom{-n-1}{0}\$ through \$\binom{-n-1}{n}\$.

Then we use an obscure trick: we can calculate \$\sum_{j=0}^n (n+1-j) \cdot z_j\$ as `sum(cumsum(z))`, or `ÄS` in Jelly parlance. But then because we want to divide by \$n+1\$ immediately after, and our list has \$n+1\$ elements, we can write `Æm` (mean) instead of `S` (sum).

Here's an example of why this works:
\begin{align}
& \textrm{sum}(\textrm{cumsum}([a,b,c,d])) \\ =~& (a) + (a+b) + (a+b+c) + (a+b+c+d) \\ =~& 4a+3b+2c+d
\end{align}

Finally we still have to multiply by \$(-1)^n\$ to fix the sign. But because we know the Fine numbers are never negative, we can just take the absolute value with `A`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `koszul math.combinatorics`, 69 bytes

```factor
[ 4 dupn + [a,b] [ -1^ -rot nCk * ] with map-index cum-sum mean abs ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYyxDoJAEAV7v@LVKiYkVlpaGBsbY0UwWY4VL3B7eLcXlZ9HlHbmvbmTUR/G6@V0Pu4Q@ZlYDEc0LByoswOp9RLhSB@bQNJMruUg3KH1cUjdbIx3lRWaUtbM45lHnf5Rf7APrPrpgxXFfrHIc1ivNBbYok69YIWC1lWJAll@Qxa8Qg4tlijxsv9en1mp@Q2TXBaTg2MSUBVRjpPEZvwC)

"Mathy" answers cause far too much whitespace in Factor so this is a port of mathcat's [Vyxal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/258124/97916).

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 25 bytes

```
⊞υ¹≔¹θＦＮ≔⊘⁻↨⊞ＯυΣ×⮌υυ⁰θθＩθ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iOSOxKDk_MWfBgqWlJWm6Fjf7A0qLMzRKdRQMNa25HIuLM9PzNAx1FAqBvLT8IgUNz7yC0hK_0tyk1CINTU0FqAqPxJyy1BQN38y80mINp8TiVA2QMf4FqUWJJflFIOOCS3M1QjJzU4s1glLLUouAKko1dRRKNTWBpIEmyAJNiC0BRZl5JRrOicUlGkAx6yXFScnFUMctj1bSLctRil1oBuEDAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
⊞υ¹
```

Start with `C(0)` = 1.

```
≔¹θ
```

Start with `F(0)` = 1.

```
ＦＮ
```

Loop `n` times.

```
≔⊘⁻↨⊞ＯυΣ×⮌υυ⁰θθ
```

Calculate the next Catalan number from the dot product of the list of numbers with its reverse and use that to calculate the next Fine number.

```
Ｉθ
```

Output `F(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 32 bytes

```
Đ⁺Đř⁻ĐĐ05Ș↔+2ř*⇹ɐ-Á⇹ć⇹⁺*⇹1~⇹^·⇹/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yIRHjbuOTDg681Hj7iMTjkwwMD0x41HbFG2jozO1HrXvPDlB93AjkD7SDiSAKkFihnVAIu7QdiCp//@/IQA)

Naive implementation of the formula in the question.

The following walkthrough of the code is worked on an input of n=3

| Code | Stack | Action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Đ | 3 3 | implicit input; **Đ**uplicate |
| ⁺ | 3 4 | increment |
| Đ | 3 4 4 | **Đ**uplicate |
| ř | 3 4 [1,2,3,4] | **ř**angify |
| ⁻ | 3 4 [0,1,2,3] | decrement |
| ĐĐ | 3 4 [0,1,2,3] [0,1,2,3] [0,1,2,3] | **Đ**uplicate twice |
| 05Ș | 3 0 [0,1,2,3] [0,1,2,3] [0,1,2,3] 4 | Push **0**, then **Șwap** the top **5** items on the stack |
| ↔ | 4 [0,1,2,3] [0,1,2,3] [0,1,2,3] 0 3 | Flip the entire stack |
| + | 4 [0,1,2,3] [0,1,2,3] [0,1,2,3] 3 | Remove that pesky 0 by adding |
| 2ř | 4 [0,1,2,3] [0,1,2,3] [0,1,2,3] 3 [1,2] | Push **2** and **ř**angify |
| * | 4 [0,1,2,3] [0,1,2,3] [0,1,2,3] [3,6] | Multiply |
| ⇹ | 4 [0,1,2,3] [0,1,2,3] [3,6] [0,1,2,3] | Swap the top two items on the stack |
| ɐ- | 4 [0,1,2,3] [0,1,2,3] [[3,2,1,0],[6,5,4,3]] | For **ɐ**ll pairs of values, subtract |
| Á | 4 [0,1,2,3] [0,1,2,3] [3,2,1,0] [6,5,4,3] | Push contents of **Árray** to stack |
| ⇹ | 4 [0,1,2,3] [0,1,2,3] [6,5,4,3] [3,2,1,0] | Swap the top two items on the stack |
| ć | 4 [0,1,2,3] [0,1,2,3] [20,10,4,1] | nCr |
| ⇹ | 4 [0,1,2,3] [20,10,4,1] [0,1,2,3] | Swap top two items on stack |
| ⁺ | 4 [0,1,2,3] [20,10,4,1] [1,2,3,4] | Increment |
| * | 4 [0,1,2,3] [20,20,12,4] | multiply element-wise |
| ⇹ | 4 [20,20,12,4] [0,1,2,3] | Swap top two items |
| 1~ | 4 [20,20,12,4] [0,1,2,3] -1 | Push **1**, then negate |
| ⇹^ | 4 [20,20,12,4] [1,-1,1,-1] | Swap top two, then exponentiate |
| · | 4 8 | Dot product |
| ⇹/ | 2 | Swap top two items, then divide; implicit print |

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 51 bytes

It's [A000957](https://oeis.org/A000957)

Use the generating function

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty F_nz^n=\frac1z\cdot\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{3-\sqrt{1-4z}}$$

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z/NNji1KDO12Dk/NS0tMzkzNa8k2khfw1A7uLCoJNpQ10SrKlbbSKtKU6e6SsdAR7k2Vu1/moK@g0JQYl56arShQayCvn5AUWZeyX8A)

```
f=SeriesCoefficient[2/(1+Sqrt[1-4*z]+2*z),{z,0,#}]&
```