# Some Lonely Primes

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, primes

*I know, I know, yet **another** primes challenge...*

[Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/94714/42963)

A lonely (or isolated) prime is a prime number `p` such that `p-2`, `p+2`, `p-4`, `p+4` ... `p-2k`, `p+2k` for some `k` are all composite. We call such a prime a **`k`th-times-isolated prime.**

For example, a 5th-times-isolated prime is `211`, since all of `201, 203, 205, 207, 209, 213, 215, 217, 219, 221` are composite. (`p-2*5=201`, `p-2*4=203`, etc.)

#### Challenge

Given two input integers, `n > 3` and `k > 0`, output the smallest `k`th-times-isolated prime that is strictly larger than `n`.

For example, for `k = 5` and any `n` in range `4 ... 210`, the output should be `211`, since that's the smallest 5th-times-isolated prime strictly larger than the input `n`.

#### Examples

```
n=55 k=1
67

n=500 k=1
503

n=2100 k=3
2153

n=2153 k=3
2161

n=14000 k=7
14107

n=14000 k=8
14107
```

### Rules

- If applicable, you can assume that the input/output will fit in your language's native Integer type.
- The input and output can be given by [any convenient method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: Is a 3rd-times-isolated prime also a 2nd-times-isolated prime?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer The last two test cases indeed seems to confirm that.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Test cases are not a part of the challenge specification.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Yes, a `k`th-times-isolated is also, by definition, a `k-1`th, `k-2`th, etc.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork Just wanted to check, thanks.

Comment: @l4m2 `2` here is a special case because it's infinitely isolated by this definition, which is why I'm starting with `n>3`.

Comment: ok it doesn't matter. The smallest result 5 with k=2 go to 9

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>17</s> 13 bytes

```
_æR+⁼ḟ
‘ç1#Ḥ}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/@8LIg7UeNex7umM/1qGHG4eWGyg93LKn9f3i5/qOmNd7//0ebmuooGMbqKESbGhhAWUaGIKYxhGlqDGUamhiAhM2R2BaxAA)

#### How it works

```
‘ç1#Ḥ}  Main link. Left argument: n. Right argument: k

‘       Increment; yield n+1.
    Ḥ}  Unhalve right; yield 2k.
 ç1#    Call the helper link with arguments m = n+1, n+2, ... and k until 1 one
        them returns a truthy value. Return the matching [m].


_æR+⁼ḟ  Helper link. Left argument: m. Right argument: k

_       Subtract; yield m-2k.
   +    Add; yield m+2k.
 æR     Prime range; yield the array of primes in [m-2k, ..., m+2k].
     ḟ  Filterfalse; yield the elements of [m] that do not occur in [k], i.e., [m]
        if m ≠ 2k and [] otherwise.
        The result to the left will be non-empty when m = 2k, as there always is
        a prime in [0, ..., 2m], since m > n > 3.
    ⁼   Test the results to both sides for equality.
        This yields 1 iff m is the only prime in [m-2k, ..., m+2k].
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 13 bytes

```
ḟ§=;ofṗM+ṡD⁰→
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9odXNr///huJ/Cpz07b2bhuZdNK@G5oUTigbDihpL///8x/zU1)

### Explanation

Pretty straightforward.

```
ḟ§=;ofṗM+ṡD⁰→  Inputs are k and n.
            →  Increment n
ḟ              and find the first number m >= n+1 such that:
         ṡD⁰    Take symmetric range [-2k,..,2k].
       M+       Add m to each.
    ofṗ         Keep those that are prime.
 §=             Check equality with
   ;            the singleton [m].
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>144</s> 143 bytes

```java
(n,k)->{for(k*=2;;)if(p(++n)>1){int i=-k;for(;i<=k&p(n+i)<2|i==0;i+=2);if(i>k)return n;}}int p(int n){for(int i=2;i<n;n=n%i++<1?0:n);return n;}
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##pdBBb8IgFAfwu5/iXbbAWmupVhMRPe04Lx6XHVjFBWtfmxbdFtfP3kHVLC5Gs@wCecDvwZ@13MluXihcL9Mm2ciqgiepcd8B0GhUuZKJgrkr2wVIiBvRb4uUcrtRd@wwBwQBDUE/pd3pfpWXJH0QEedUr0hBPA/plNG9U1p0U@4OcD0R6X1B0NN0En1pIUKuPRFRbo2eprRUZlsiIK9r7mRxuJy27Q@tItsEOQq80543YbNwjJT/uAag2L5udAKVkcZOu1wvIbMJycKUGt@eXyQ9pHOxIbMhUL23BWnTASw@K6OyIN@aoLDEbJBkAQYJiWOfUcrdmV4PHj8KlRi1HMNwdMOF4QmeuTjsX4cRs7LfyjMYsfimjPuX5ZBdlwM/Pmb8LdnNx57oXyG7CGfXGRuE9ndGDp4xNmDh6H@07tTNNw)

```java
(n,k)->{                      // Method with two integer parameters and integer return-type
  for(k*=2;                   //  Multiply `k` by 2
      ;)                      //  Loop indefinitely
    if(p(++n)>1){             //   Increase `n` by 1 before every iteration with `++n`
                              //   And if it's a prime:
      int i=-k;for(;i<=k      //    Loop `i` from `-k` to `k` (inclusive)
        &p(n+i)<2|i==0;       //    As long as `n+i` is not a prime (skipping `n` itself)
        i+=2);                //    And iterate in steps of 2 instead of 1
      if(i>k)                 //    If we've reached the end of the loop:
        return n;}}           //     We've found our result, so return it

// Separated method to check if `n` is a prime
// `n` is a prime if it remained unchanged, and not when it became 0 or 1
int p(int n){for(int i=2;i<n;n=n%i++<1?0:n);return n;}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>94</s> <s>92</s> 89 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,k)=>(Q=y=>y<-k||(P=(a,b=2)=>a>b?a%b&&P(a,b+1):1)(n+2*y)^!!y&&Q(--y))(k,++n)?n:f(n,k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dczRCoIwFIDh@97Ci8Y5bYtNk0KavoK@QDDNRU22yAgGvvuyLsNuP37@m37psXtc70/u/LmP0ShwzKIqoVFBleHI7TRBrUCzVqWz67Kt9LolpP4QlVhIBEfTTcBTkgRCGuA8IIJllDqsXGG@x9h5N/qh3w7@AgbynEnE1Q8KsaCpnDlb4DxbYLkTc77/4wfE@AY)

<s>Mysteriously, further golfs end up stack overflow. Only this works at the size of 14000.</s>

Finally one golf that won't end up stack overflow at 14000.

**Explanation**

```javascript
f=(n,k)=>            // Two inputs
 (Q=y=>              // Function checking whether all numbers in 
                     // [n-2*k, n+2*k] except n are all composite
  y<-k               // The counter runs from k to -k
                     // If none breaks the rule, return true
  ||(P=(a,b=2)=>     // Function checking primality
   a>b?              // Check if a>b
   a%b&&P(a,b+1)     // If a>b and a%b==0 return false, else proceed
   :1                // If a<=b return 1 (prime)
  )(n+2*y)^!!y       // If n+2*y is prime, then y must be 0
                     // If n+2*y is not prime, then y must be non-zero
                     // If none of the conditions are met, return false
  &&Q(--y)           // Else proceed to the next counter
 )
 (k,++n)?            // Add 1 to n first, then start the check
 n                   // If conditions are met, return n
 :f(n,k)             // Else proceed to the next n.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>105</s> 104 bytes

<sup>-1 byte thanks to ovs</sup>

```python
n,k=input()
n+=1
while sum(all(x%i for i in range(2,x))^(x==n)for x in range(n-k*2,2*k-~n)):n+=1
print n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcyxCsIwEAbgvU9xi3BX06FXXIS8itCh2iPxb4gpxsVXj@ji/MGXXmXdoK3BBW9Ie2HpcPRj91wtLvTY7zzHyPVgdN0yGRkoz7gtrK6KXLh6D/lS/ROG0KvTPgxviJx/X8qGQmhNx9PkaPoA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
åΣ▀ë F▬&■º↔╔^∞
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=86e4df8920461626fea71dc95eec&i=1+55%0A1+500%0A3+2100%0A3+2153%0A7+14000%0A8+14000&a=1&m=2)

This is the corresponding ascii representation.

```
w^x:r{Hn+|p_!=m0#

w                   while; run the rest of the program until a falsy value remains
 ^                  increment candidate value.
  x:r               [-x, ..., -1, 0, 1, ... x] where x is the first input
     {        m     map using block, using k from -x to x
      Hn+           double and add to candidate value - this is "p+2k"
         |p         is it prime? produces 0 or 1
           _!       k is zero?
             =      two values are equal; always true for a passing candidate
               0#   any falses left after mapping? if so, continue running
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) + `-rprime`, <s>73</s> <s>71</s> <s>61</s> 57 bytes

```ruby
->n,k{n+=1;(-k..k).all?{|i|(i*2+n).prime?^(i!=0)}?n:redo}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VdDRaoMwFAbg@z7Fv4Cga5REmzo6rA8iDlwTmeiiGIWN2lefi7Pt6N3hO//5L04/vn/PZTL7R03rs94m/NX16yCovaBomvQ8VZNbPYdb7QVdX32q9M2tnhLmXVJ96JVsL3O2ATIAQlBwagfs45yuKBi7omDRFUO@YGQx5OIfRXTDPV@R79iSjG3DjrP4AV9uuMkDVZw@IFtMmqKmUF@dOg1KTjbeKzM2AxKU2bLMLXXjYEAcISkcieQIO8J1jEfgIFsr1jN6P0/upUhBusIYggNIWVQNyTdKy/mn7Yaq1Wb2@783/QI)

It feels good to be learning! I'm <s>using the `Integer#[]` and `redo` techniques that I learned here on PPCG.</s> getting lost in the weeds of fun techniques...

-1 byte: Use `n%2` instead of `n[0]` to get the least significant bit. Thanks, [Asone Tuhid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/77598/asone-tuhid)!

-1 byte: Use a ternary operator instead of a boolean expression. Thanks, [Asone Tuhid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/77598/asone-tuhid)!

-10 bytes: Use the XOR operator to avoid typing out `.prime?` twice... This is just as much [Asone Tuhid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/77598/asone-tuhid)'s answer as mine now :)

-4 bytes: There's no harm in checking even values of `n`. [Asone Tuhid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/77598/asone-tuhid) is non-stop.

Ungolfed:

```ruby
->n,k{
  n += 1;                   # Increment n
  (-k..k).all?{|i|          # In the set [n-2*k, n+2*k], is every number
    (i*2+n).prime? ^ (i!=0) #    EITHER prime XOR different from n itself?
  } ? n                     # If yes, return the current value of n
  : redo                    # Otherwise, restart the block
}
```

Comment: [Flags no longer need to be included in the byte count. Each separate invocation of a flag is instead considered a different language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/59487). So this answer should instead be *Ruby + `-rprime`, 73 bytes*

Comment: Oh lovely! Thanks for keeping me up to date on the meta, @Mr.Xcoder.

Comment: [71 bytes](https://tio.run/##VdBBboMwEAXQfU4xtUQExSAb4lClcjgIYkFjo1pQgzBIreJcvdQUkqq70Zs/fzHD9PY113yOzho3Vx1y7SUhfdVxP6gPme/3ftTEcRPEVdvmV6us4pxY@@Sr5yTUwRa75fo0SNHd5mIHUAAAYxgodgMcsxKvyAjZkJF0w4QumDpMKPtDlt7xSFekB7IkM9dwoCT7hy933JWxrC7vIDqwGkODQX728jJKYV18kGZqR@BQF8uydNRPowHkMYHBE8DP4EbwPRMg8KBYK9Yz/Djnj1LIAfWVMQhOgOpKtajcSS3m764fVafNHA2///kB). `n%2` is shorter than `n[0]` in this case and `?...:` can be shorter than `&&...||`

Comment: [-10 bytes](https://tio.run/##VdDRaoMwFAbge5/iX0DQGcVoU0eH9UHEgauRBV0Uo7BR@@pzcbYdvTt85z//xRmm9@@lThf/qGhzVl6q7Mhjr47fBEHjBmXbZudZzo58jjzlBv0gP0X25sinNHQvmToMououS24BOQDOKRg1A/ZJQTfkYXhFHsZXjNiKscGI8X/k8Q33bEO2C9dkYhp2LEwe8OWGVhGI8vSBqsOsKBoK8dWL0yiq2cQHoad2RIo6X5eFoX4aNYjNKwq7QnqEGeHY2iWwkW8V2xm9n6f3UmQgfak1wQGkLmVLCkuoavnp@lF2Si/@8PemXw) :)

Comment: @AsoneTuhid Very nice!

Comment: this one's small but [it turns out "`n%2+`" was useless](https://tio.run/##VdDRaoMwFAbg@z7Fv4Cga5REmzo6rA8iDlwTmeiiGIWN2lefi7Pt6N3hO//5L04/vn/PZTL7R03rs94m/NX16yCovaBomvQ8VZNbPYdb7QVdX32q9M2tnhLmXVJ96JVsL3O2ATIAQlBwagfs45yuKBi7omDRFUO@YGQx5OIfRXTDPV@R79iSjG3DjrP4AV9uuMkDVZw@IFtMmqKmUF@dOg1KTjbeKzM2AxKU2bLMLXXjYEAcISkcieQIO8J1jEfgIFsr1jN6P0/upUhBusIYggNIWVQNyTdKy/mn7Yaq1Wb2@783/QI)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 113 bytes

```c
P(n,d,b){for(b=d=n>1;++d<n;)b=b&&n%d;n=b;}f(n,k,i,f){for(f=n;f;)for(f=i=!P(++n);i++<k;f|=P(n+i+i)|P(n-i-i));f=n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hcxBCsIwEIXhtZ4iCkqGpJBYY4UxegUP4MY0RAZxFHHX9uw1UsFdXc2/@ObVxaWu@/4oWUcdoEn3pww@et5bVCruGCH4sFzyIiL7gF3K8qpJp8Emz5gQhiQ/O0qlGJCU2l0xtT4PK1IEbY6CCgLAz0vX387EEprp5PEkfiU5X7goDl7kc@K5TlII4Zy2oHNsKsAx6YwZpDPlqFzZLMssV9b9k678yo0dk3Zt8mYF2q6tqf7L7U92/Rs)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 55 bytes

```
f(n,k)=until(isprime(n++)&&#primes([n-2*k,n+2*k])<2,);n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcrNCsMgEATgV1lSCG5VUFNpoT8vIh6kNEViFknSQ5/emjaHXoZvhslhivKZS@kZiQGvL1piYnHOUxwfjDjHtt19y8wcSbMfBPGaHi9G4JlKyDm9WQB5g3qjpbJZSwP3kBLrBQREAc5ZK0D7KqvUJqNXdj/abqM@qHU@/vnkPZYP)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 63 bytes

```perl6
{$^k;first {[grep *.is-prime,$_-2*$k..$_+2*$k]eqv[$_]},$^a^..*}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJKmYPu/WiUu2zots6i4RKE6Or0otUBBSy@zWLegKDM3VUclXtdISyVbT08lXhvEiE0tLItWiY@t1VGJS4zT09Oq/W/NVZwIMkrD1FRHwVATwTUwQOEbGYIEjJEFTI1RBAxNDEBKzDFELDSt/wMA)