# Primes with prime bit-counts

Tags: code-golf, primes, binary

#### Task

> Find all the non-negative integers up to and including a given non-zero positive integer *n*, that are prime and the count of `1's` and `0's` in their binary representation (having no leading zeroes) are prime too.

Here are the first five such primes,

```
17, 19, 37, 41, 79

10001, 10011, 100101, 101001, 1001111
```

#### Clarifications and rules

- [Default I/O methods are accepted](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods?noredirect=1&lq=1).
- The answer can be a program or a function.
- If there are no such primes then output garbage or nothing.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default?noredirect=1&lq=1) are forbidden.
- `2 3 5 7` did not make it to the list because in their binary representation number of occurrences of `0's` and `1's` are not prime. Consider `7`whose binary representation is `111`, here `0` occurs zero times and zero is not prime.
- Built-ins are allowed.
- The shortest code in bytes wins!

#### Test cases

```
10
[]

100
[17, 19, 37, 41, 79]

150
[17, 19, 37, 41, 79, 103, 107, 109, 131, 137]
```

```js
/* Configuration */

var QUESTION_ID = 107050; // Obtain this from the url
// It will be like http://XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions/QUESTION_ID/... on any question page
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";
var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk";
var OVERRIDE_USER = 47650; // This should be the user ID of the challenge author.

/* App */

var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page;

function answersUrl(index) {
  return "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" +  QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER;
}

function commentUrl(index, answers) {
  return "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER;
}

function getAnswers() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: answersUrl(answer_page++),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);
      answers_hash = [];
      answer_ids = [];
      data.items.forEach(function(a) {
        a.comments = [];
        var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/);
        answer_ids.push(id);
        answers_hash[id] = a;
      });
      if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false;
      comment_page = 1;
      getComments();
    }
  });
}

function getComments() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      data.items.forEach(function(c) {
        if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER)
          answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c);
      });
      if (data.has_more) getComments();
      else if (more_answers) getAnswers();
      else process();
    }
  });  
}

getAnswers();

var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,<]*(?:<(?:[^\n>]*>[^\n<]*<\/[^\n>]*>)[^\n,<]*)*),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/;

var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i;

function getAuthorName(a) {
  return a.owner.display_name;
}

function process() {
  var valid = [];
  
  answers.forEach(function(a) {
    var body = a.body;
    a.comments.forEach(function(c) {
      if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body))
        body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>';
    });
    
    var match = body.match(SCORE_REG);
    if (match)
      valid.push({
        user: getAuthorName(a),
        size: +match[2],
        language: match[1],
        link: a.share_link,
      });
    else console.log(body);
  });
  
  valid.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aB = a.size,
        bB = b.size;
    return aB - bB
  });

  var languages = {};
  var place = 1;
  var lastSize = null;
  var lastPlace = 1;
  valid.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.size != lastSize)
      lastPlace = place;
    lastSize = a.size;
    ++place;
    
    var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html();
    answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".")
                   .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user)
                   .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language)
                   .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size)
                   .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link);
    answer = jQuery(answer);
    jQuery("#answers").append(answer);

    var lang = a.language;
    lang = jQuery('<a>'+lang+'</a>').text();
    
    languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, lang_raw: lang, user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link};
  });

  var langs = [];
  for (var lang in languages)
    if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang))
      langs.push(languages[lang]);

  langs.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.lang_raw.toLowerCase() > b.lang_raw.toLowerCase()) return 1;
    if (a.lang_raw.toLowerCase() < b.lang_raw.toLowerCase()) return -1;
    return 0;
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i)
  {
    var language = jQuery("#language-template").html();
    var lang = langs[i];
    language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang)
                       .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user)
                       .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size)
                       .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link);
    language = jQuery(language);
    jQuery("#languages").append(language);
  }

}
```

```css
body { text-align: left !important}

#answer-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#language-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

table thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b">
<div id="language-list">
  <h2>Shortest Solution by Language</h2>
  <table class="language-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="languages">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="answer-list">
  <h2>Leaderboard</h2>
  <table class="answer-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="answers">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="answer-template">
    <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="language-template">
    <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You ask for all primes **under** a given n, but you also say inclusive. Which do you mean?

Comment: @Riley What I mean is ...`all the numbers from 1....n`. I do not know how to rephrase it in a simple way.

Comment: I have phrased it for you.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks a lot.

Comment: **[OEIS A144214](http://oeis.org/A144214)**

Comment: @mbomb007 Clearly, _for any total ordering of integer sequences,_ the smallest uninteresting integer sequence would be itself interesting, and thus worthy of inclusion in OEIS. Ergo, OEIS contains all integer sequences, of any interest real or imagined :-)

Comment: Does the resulting list have to be sorted?

Comment: @mbomb007 nope.

Comment: I'm wondering whether Mathematica contains more builtins than OEIS has sequences...

Comment: We should do a version of this in the unary number system! Wait...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÅPʒbTS¢pP
```

Pretty straight-forward.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cGvAqUlJIcGHFhUE/P9vaGoAAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/w60BpyYlhQQfWlQQ8L9W53@0oYGOoQEQm4Jpg1gA).

**Explanation:**

```python
ÅP         # Push a list of all prime numbers below or equal to the (implicit) input
  ʒ        # Filter this list of primes by:
   b       #  Convert it to a binary string
    TS     #  Push 10, and pop and convert it to a list of digits as strings: ["1","0"]
      ¢    #  Count those characters in the binary string
       p   #  Check for both those counts whether they're a prime number
        P  #  Check that this is truthy for both of them
           # (after which the filtered list is output implicitly as result)
```

There seems to be a bug in the count builtin `¢` when using an integer list on a string, so some alternatives to `TS` like `Ð‰`, `0L`, or `1Ý` doesn't seem to work and result in a pair of the binary string instead, unless we add a `§` (cast to string): [Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cGvAua1JIcGHFtXqHNpmzwXhH57wqGEDqpCBDyrf8PBcbHqWY@hajqkPLPT/v6GpAQA).

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>106</s> <s>102</s> 100 bytes

```python
k=m=1;p={0}
exec"p^={m%k*k,0};c=bin(k).count\nif{k,c('1'),c('0')-1}<p:print k\nm*=k*k;k+=1;"*input()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59tm2traF1gW21Qy5VakZqsVBBnW52rmq2VrWNQa51sm5SZp5GtqZecX5pXEpOXmVadrZOsoW6orgmiDNQ1dQ1rbQqsCooy80oUsmPycrVsgVqts7WBhippZeYVlJZoaP7/b2hqAAA)

#### Background

To identify primes, we use a corollary of [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem):

[image: corollary of Wilson's theorem]

#### How it works

We start by initializing **k** and **m** as **1** and **p** as the set **{0}**. Note that **m = 1 = 0!² = (k - 1)!²**. Immediately afterwards, the following code is executed **n** times, where **n** is the integer read from standard input.

```python
p^={m%k*k,0};c=bin(k).count
if{k,c('1'),c('0')-1}<p:print k
m*=k*k;k+=1
```

By the corollary, **m % k** will be **1** if **k** is prime and **0** otherwise. Thus, `{m%k*k,0}` will return the set **{k, 0}** if **k** is prime and the set **{0}** otherwise.

If (and only if) **k** is prime, since **p** cannot contain **k** at this point, the in-place symmetric difference `p^={m%k*k,0}` will add **k** to the set **p**. Also, **p** will contain **0** after the update if and only if it does not contain **0** before, so **0 ∊ p** if and only if **k** is even.

On the same line, we define a function **c** via `c=bin(k).count`, which will count the occurrences of its argument in **k**'s binary representation.

The second line produces the actual output. `{k,c('1'),c('0')-1}` returns the set that consists of **k** itself, the number of set bits in **k**, and the number of unset bits in **k**. Since the output of `bin(k)` begins with **0b**, we have to decrement `c('0')` to account for the leading **0**.

If all of them are prime, they will all belong to **p**, which by now contains all prime numbers up to **k** (and potentially **0**). If **k** is a Mersenne number (i.e., if it has only set bits), `c('0')-1` will yield **0**. Since Mersenne numbers are odd, **p** will *not* contain **0**, so the condition will fail.

After (potentially) printing **k**, we multiply **m** by **k²**. Since **m = (k-1)!²** before the update, **m = k!²** after it. After incrementing **k**, the relation **m = (k-1)!²** holds again and we're ready for the next iteration.

Answer (score 9):

## Mathematica, <s>80</s> <s>68</s> 54 bytes

```
Select[p=PrimeQ;Range@#,p@#&&And@@p/@#~DigitCount~2&]&
```

**Explanation**

```
Select[p=PrimeQ;Range@#,p@#&&And@@p/@#~DigitCount~2&]&

       p=PrimeQ                                        (* Store prime check func. in p *)
Select[                                             ]  (* Select *)
                Range@#                                (* from a list {1..n} *)
                        p@#                            (* numbers that are prime *)
                           &&                          (* And *)
                                     #~DigitCount~2    (* whose digit counts in binary *)
                             And@@p/@                  (* are prime as well *)
```

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>123</s> <s>118</s> <s>115</s> <s>111</s> <s>104</s> 96 bytes

*Saved 4 bytes thanks to @Arnauld*

```
G=n=>n?G(n>>1,++a[n%2]):a.some(n=>(P=x=>n%--x?P(x):x)(n)-1)
F=n=>F(n-1,G(n,a=[0,0,n])||alert(n))
```

A combination of three typical recursive functions. Alerts the sequence in reverse order and terminates on a "too much recursion" error.

#### Test snippet

(modified to output to the page)

```js
alert = s => O.textContent += s + "\n"

G=n=>n?G(n>>1,++a[n%2]):a.some(n=>(P=x=>n%--x?P(x):x)(n)-1)
F=n=>F(n-1,G(n,a=[0,0,n])||alert(n))

F(1000)
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

The main function can return an array for 104 bytes:

```
G=n=>n?G(n>>1,++a[n%2]):a.some(n=>(P=x=>n%--x?P(x):x)(n)-1)
F=n=>n?F(n-1).concat(G(n,a=[0,0,n])?[]:n):[]
```

It can also be non-recursive at the cost of another byte:

```
G=n=>n?G(n>>1,++a[n%2]):a.some(n=>(P=x=>n%--x?P(x):x)(n)-1)
n=>[for(_ of Array(n))if(!G(--n,a=[0,0,n]))n]
```

---

Here's the one I started with: *(Saved 6 bytes thanks to @Arnauld)*

```
P=(n,x=n)=>n>1&--x<2||n%x&&P(n,x)
G=n=>n?G(n>>1,o+=n%2,t++):P(o)&P(t-o)
F=n=>n?F(n-1).concat(P(n)&G(n,o=t=0)?n:[]):[]
```

I tried golfing this further and managed to do it in 104 bytes—then realized I had already found that solution (it's at the bottom of the answer). Don't you hate it when that happens? :P

A non-recursive attempt at the main function (again, same byte count):

```
n=>[for(i of Array(n))if(P(--n)&G(n,o=t=0))n]
```

---

This one takes the easy route of counting how many 0's and 1's are in the binary representation:

```
F=n=>n?F(n-1).concat([n,(G=x=>n.toString(2).split(x).length-1)(0),G(1)].some(n=>(P=x=>n%--x?P(x):x)(n)-1)?[]:n):[]
```

Same thing with an array comprehension:

```
n=>[for(_ of Array(n))if(![--n,(G=x=>n.toString(2).split(x).length-1)(0),G(1)].some(n=>(P=x=>n%--x?P(x):x)(n)-1))n]
```

This one takes a slightly harder route to do the same thing:

```
F=n=>n?F(n-1).concat([n,(G=(x,w=n)=>w&&G(x,w>>1)+(w%2==x))(0),G(1)].some(n=>(P=x=>n%--x?P(x):x)(n)-1)?[]:n):[]
```

And this one takes yet another related route that's as short as the original:

```
F=n=>n?F(n-1).concat([n,o=(G=x=>x&&x%2+G(n>>++t))(n,t=0),t-o].some(n=>(P=x=>n%--x?P(x):x)(n)-1)?[]:n):[]
```

Again, you can golf 8 bytes by making it alert the sequence in reverse order:

```
F=n=>F(n-1,[n,o=(G=x=>x&&x%2+G(n>>++t))(n,t=0),t-o].some(n=>(P=x=>n%--x?P(x):x)(n)-1)||alert(n))
```

Comment: You don't really need to recursively pass `a`. Just initialize it in the initial call to `G`. (That should save 4 bytes.)

Comment: @Arnauld Oh yeah, thanks! This is fun :-)

Comment: Wow this has dropped a lot. Nice work

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>17</s> 16 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
BĠL€µ;LÆPẠ
ÆRÇÐf
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#ASEA3v//QsSgTOKCrMK1O0zDhlDhuqAKw4ZSw4fDkGb///8xMDA)**

#### How?

```
BĠL€µ;LÆPẠ - Link 1, hasPrimeBits: n  e.g. 7         or 13
B          - convert to binary        e.g. [1,1,1]  or [1,1,0,1]
 Ġ         - group indices            e.g. [1,2,3]  or [3,[1,2,4]]
  L€       - length of €ach           e.g. 3          or [1,3]
    µ      - monadic chain separation
     ;L    - concatenate length       e.g. [3,1]      or [1,3,2]
           -     this caters for the edge case of Mersenne primes (like 7), which have
           -     no zero bits, the length will be 1, which is not prime.
       ÆP  - isPrime?                 e.g. [1,0]      or [0,1,1]
         Ạ - All?                     e.g. 0          or 0

ÆRÇÐf - Main link: N
ÆR    - prime range (primes up to and including N)
   Ðf - filter keep those satisfying
  Ç   - last link (1) as a monad
```

Comment: Ah thanks, I see you changed that, that'll save a byte.

Comment: You've got the alphabet going, there. `ẠBÇÐ€fĠ...`

Comment: @mbomb007 Yeah, the `LÆµ;P` bit always confuses me.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 14 bytes

```
ƒNpNbSD_‚OpP&–
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@39skl@BX1KwS/yjhln@BQFqjxom//9vaGoAAA)

**Explanation**

```
ƒ               # for N in [0 ... input]
 Np             # push N is prime
   Nb           # push N converted to binary
     S          # split into individual digits
      D_        # push an inverted copy
        ‚       # pair the 2 binary lists
         O      # sum them
          p     # elementwise check for primality
           P    # product of list
            &   # and with the primality of N
             –  # if true, print N
```

Comment: I still can't find a use for `.¡`, this challenge seemed good for it, but is longer: `FNb{.¡€gpONp+3QiN}})`

Comment: @carusocomputing: I had a similar solution I considered as well, but it also ended up slightly longer than this.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
RBċþd`ÆPPTfÆR
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@x/kdKT78L6UhMNtAQEhaYfbgv7//29oagAA)

#### How it works

```
RBċþd`ÆPPTfÆR  Main link. Argument: n

R              Range; yield [1, ..., n].
 B             Binary; convert each integer to base 2.
    d`         Divmod self; yield [n : n, n % n], i.e., [1, 0].
  ċþ           Count table; count the occurrences of 1 and 0 in each binary
               representation, yielding a pair of lists of length n.
      ÆP       Test each count for primality.
        P      Product; multiply the corresponding Booleans.
         T     Truth; get all indices of 1, yielding the list of integers in
               [1, ..., n] that have a prime amount of 0's and 1's.
           ÆR  Prime range; yield all primes in [1, ..., n].
          f    Filter; intersect the lists.
```

Comment: That ``d`​`` trick is something else...

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>17</s> 15 bytes

```
LDpÏvybSD_)OpP—
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@@/jUnC4v6wyKdglXtO/IOBRw5T//w0NDAA)

Comment: `LDpÏvybSD_)OpP—` for 15 bytes should work.

Comment: @Emigna That is really clever! Thanks :).

Answer (score 4):

### Perl, 101 bytes

99 bytes of code + `-nl` flags.

```pl
$r=q/^1?$|^(11+)\1+$/;for$@(2..$_){$_=sprintf"%b",$@;print$@if(1x$@)!~$r&y/01/1/dr!~$r&s/0//gr!~$r}
```

To run it:

```
perl -lne '$r=q/^1?$|^(11+)\1+$/;for$@(2..$_){$_=sprintf"%b",$@;print$@if(1x$@)!~$r&y/01/1/dr!~$r&s/0//gr!~$r}' <<< 150
```

**Some short explanations**
`$r` holds the classical prime checking regex (`q/^1?$|^(11+)\1+$/`).
For all numbers between 2 and the input,
`(1x$@)!~$r` checks if the number is prime,
`y/01/1/dr!~$r` checks if the number of `0` in the binary representation is prime,
`s/0//gr!~$r` checks if the number `1` in the binary representation is prime.
(if the 3 conditions are met, `print$@` prints it).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Quite amazing what you can do with what is basically regex and some logic :)

Comment: @Emigna Thanks! The explanations aren't very detailed (I'm having a hard time writing longer explanations), but it seems it was enough for you :) (I still believe the code is slightly too long, but I don't see how to get it shorter, so here it is)

Comment: As someone who doesn't know Perl I appreciate every explanation I can get. It won't help me make a Perl program but I understand some of the reasoning behind the method employed, which is always interesting.

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
:"@tB!t~hshZp?@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@2@l5FDipFhSl1GcEVVg7/D/v6GpAQA)

```
:         % Input n (implicit). Push range [1 2 ... n]
"         % For each k in [1 2 ... n]
  @       %   Push k
  tB!     %   Duplicate. Binary expansion as an m×1 vector
  t~      %   Duplicate. Negate
  hs      %   Concatenate horizontally into an m×2 matrix. Sum of each column.
          %   This gives a 1×2 vector. However, for k==1 this gives the sum of
          %   the original 1×2 matrix (m==1). But fortunately it doesn't matter
          %   because 1 is not a prime anyway
  h       %   Concatenate horizontally into a 1×3 row vector
  Zp      %   Isprime function applied on each of those three numbers
  ?       %   If all gave true
    @     %     Push k
          %   End (implicit)
          % End (implicit)
          % Display (implicit)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python, <s>129</s> <s>125</s> 123 bytes

If only zero were prime...

```python
p=lambda n:all(n%m for m in range(2,n))*n>1
lambda n:[i for i in range(n+1)if p(i)*all(p(bin(i)[2:].count(x))for x in'01')]
```

[**Try it online**](https://repl.it/FKoP/3)

Function `p` is the prime-checking function, which has `>0` at the end so that it works for zero as well, which would otherwise return `-1`. The anonymous lambda is the lambda that checks all the conditions required.

---

Here's a slightly different method using a set comprehension. The result will be a set. (**124 bytes**):

```python
p=lambda n:all(n%m for m in range(2,n))*n>1
lambda n:{i*p(i)*all(p(bin(i)[2:].count(x))for x in'01')for i in range(n+1)}-{0}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 65 bytes

```perl6
{grep {all($^a,|map {+$a.base(2).comb(~$_)},0,1).is-prime},0..$_}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#Ky1OVSgz00u25uLKrVRQS85PSVWw/V@dXpRaoFCdmJOjoRKXqFOTmwjkaask6iUlFqdqGGnqJefnJmnUqcRr1uoY6Bhq6mUW6xYUZeamArl6eirxtf8LSksUwIYZmhr8BwA)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{           # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣

  grep      # find all of the values where

  {         # lambda with placeholder parameter ｢$a｣

    all(    # all junction ( treat multiple values as a single value )

      $^a,  # declare parameter to block

      |\    # slip the following list into the outer list

      # get the count of 0's and 1's in the binary representation
      map

      {             # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣

        +           # turn to numeric ( count the values in the list )
        $a          # the outer parameter
        .base(2)    # in base 2
        .comb(~$_)  # find the characters that are the same as
      },0,1         # 0 or 1

    # ask if $a, count of 0's, count of 1's are all prime
    ).is-prime

  },

  0 .. $_ # Range from 0 to the input inclusive

}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Octave, 73 bytes

```
@(n)(p=primes(n))(all(isprime([s=sum(dec2bin(p)'-48);fix(log2(p))+1-s])))
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/#svX40)

```
@(n)
    (p=primes(n))                           generate prime numbers
        (all(                               from them select those that
            isprime(                        are prime both
                [s=sum(dec2bin(p)'-48);     sum of 1s
                fix(log2(p))+1-s])))        and sum of 0s
```

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>26</s> 27 bytes

```
ri){mp},{2b_1-,mp\0-,mp&},p
```

Straightforward algorithm, will golf further.

EDIT: Forgot n was inclusive.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@1@UqVkdn1sQY5QUb6irA2QYgEg1tVqdgv//DQ0MAA)

For fun, this is very similar and also 27 bytes:

```
ri){_mp\2b_1-,mp\0-,mp&&},p
```

**Explanation**

```
ri                          e# Take an int as input
  ){mp},                    e# Take the range up and including to the input, 
                            e#   including only prime numbers
       {                    e# For each prime...
        2b_                 e# Convert it to binary and copy it
           1-,mp            e# Take the top binary number, remove 1's, check if the length 
                            e#   is prime
                \           e# Swap top elements
                 0-,mp      e# Do the same but remove 0's
                      &     e# And
                       },   e# Filter out primes for which the above block was false
                         p  e# Print nicely
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python, <s>172</s> <s>170</s> <s>168</s> <s>159</s> <s>154</s> <s>133</s> 130 bytes

```
p=lambda n:[i for i in range(1,n)if n%i==0]==[1]
lambda n:[i for i in range(n+1)if p(i)*all(p(bin(i)[2:].count(x))for x in'10')]
```

---

Usage: Call the anonymous lambda function
Method `p` checks whether a number is prime

---

Saved 2+2+9=13 bytes thanks to Gurupad Mamadapur
Saved 5 bytes thanks to mbomb007

Comment: You can save 2 more by using this `v` - `def v(n):a=bin(n)[2:];return p(n)and(p(a.count('1'))and p(a.count('0')))`

Comment: A much shorter one - `v=lambda a:p(a)and all(p(bin(a)[2:].count(x))for x in['1','0'])`

Comment: Strings are iterable. So you can use `for x in'01'`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
BċÆPðÐf
ÆRç0ç1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#ARwA4///QsSLw4ZQw7DDkGYKw4ZSw6cww6cx////MTUw)

Unfortunately, I could only tie with @Dennis, but the algorithm seems to be somewhat different so I'm posting this anyway.

### Explanation

Helper function (deletes list elements that don't have a prime number of occurrences of a given bit):

```
BċÆPðÐf
     Ðf   Filter {the first argument}, looking for truthy returns from
    ð     the preceding code, which takes two arguments:
B         Convert {the element being checked} to binary
 ċ        Count the number of occurrences of {the second argument}
  ÆP      Return true if prime, false if not prime
```

Main program:

```
ÆRç0ç1
ÆR        Generate all primes from 2 to the input
  ç0      Call the subroutine to require a prime 0 count
    ç1    Call the subroutine to require a prime 1 count
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + GNU utilities, <s>129</s> <s>126</s> <s>123</s> <s>114</s> <s>111</s> 109 bytes

```bash
seq '-fp()([ `factor|wc -w` = 2 ]);g()(dc -e2o${n}n|tr -cd $1|wc -c|p);n=%.f;p<<<$n&&g 0&&g 1&&echo $n' $1|sh
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#HYqxDoMgGAZf5RsoykAjJp3AJ2lMbH5Bpx@qJg7SZ0ftcsPdldV/UemQalW/MYQPbXHJO0HvAzq06JWdrjZexrdRHPzjvC3QNEKY/0g5Kcvd4xlscs4JlnJCc8NI6WmOEFzd8zqXUsyrOQE)

Noticed the comment that the output doesn't have to be in increasing order -- shaved off 3 bytes by counting down instead of counting up.

Replaced grep with wc to save 3 additional bytes.

Eliminated a variable (9 more bytes off).

Changed the way factor is used -- 3 more bytes.

Made it golfier with seq (2 bytes).

Answer (score 2):

## Haxe, <s>169</s> 171 bytes

```
function f(n,?p)return[for(j in(p=[for(i in 0...++n)i<2?0:i]))if(j>0){var x=j*2,y=0,z=0,k=j;while(k<n)p[k+=j]=0;while((x>>=1)>0)x&1>0?y++:z++;p[y]<1||p[z]<1?continue:j;}];
```

Nothing crazy. Essentially a modified sieve of Eratosthenes that evaluates the primality of the 0 / 1 count in the same iteration as crossing out higher non-primes. With some whitespace:

```
function f(n, ?p)
  return [ for (j in (p = [ for(i in 0...++n) i < 2 ? 0 : i ]))
    if (j > 0){
      var x = j * 2, y = 0, z = 0, k = j;
      while (k < n)
        p[k += j] = 0;
      while((x >>= 1) > 0)
        x & 1 > 0 ? y++ : z++;
      p[y] < 1 || p[z] < 1 ? continue : j;
    }
  ];
```

But today I learned I could put `continue` in a ternary operator and Haxe doesn't even mind.

Edit: +2 because `n` is an inclusive upper bound!

Comment: Hey, the `n` is inclusive.

Comment: @GurupadMamadapur You're right, fixed!

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 50 bytes

```
{grep {($_&+.base(2).comb(~0&~1)).is-prime},0..$_}
```

Variation of [b2gills' answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/107079/14880), using the `&` [junction](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Junction) operator to great effect.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#Ky1OVSgz00u25uLKrVRQS1Ow/V@dXpRaoFCtoRKvpq2XlFicqmGkqZecn5ukUWegVmeoqamXWaxbUJSZm1qrY6CnpxJf@784sVIhTcHQ1OA/AA)

#### How it works

```
{                                                }  # Lambda
                                            0..$_   # Range from 0 to the lambda argument.
 grep {                                   },        # Filter values satisfying:
       ($_                      ).is-prime          #  a) The Number itself is prime.
       (   +.base(2).comb(~0   )).is-prime          #  b) The count of 0's is prime.
       (   +.base(2).comb(   ~1)).is-prime          #  c) The count of 1's is prime.
          &                 &                       # Junction magic! :)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ò≥úû╙2ï⌡T5è╧²■
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=95f2a396d3328bf554358acffdfe&i=10%0A100%0A150&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 14 bytes

```
'bĊvtJ₅3=$væA∧
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%27b%C4%8AvtJ%E2%82%853%3D%24v%C3%A6A%E2%88%A7&inputs=100&header=&footer=)

```
'              # (implicitly convert to range), then filter by...
 b             # Binary representation
  Ċ            # Count the amount of each value in a (1 & 0 only)
   vt          # Get the counts
     J         # Join the current number to each of those
      ₅        # Duplicate and get length
       3=      # Is it equal to 3?
         $     # Swap
          væA  # Are all prime?
             ∧ # Are both true?
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 21 bytes

```
S#j_PI\0[jb2R/_P)I\1[
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=S%23j_PI%5C0%5Bjb2R%2F_P%29I%5C1%5B&input=150&warnings=0)

```
S#j                   - for j in filter(range(1, input+1))
   _PI                -  if is_prime(j):
        [jb2R/_P)     -   function_[(a) = V
         jb2          -      base_2(j)
            R/        -     ^.count(a)
      \0         I    -   if function_[("0"):
                  \1[ -    function_[("1")
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 18 bytes

```
f.APM_M+T/LSjT2U2S
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=f.APM_M%2BT%2FLSjT2U2S&input=100&debug=0).

Comment: @GurupadMamadapur srry changing `U` to `S`

Comment: @GurupadMamadapur done

Comment: @GurupadMamadapur `eS`

Comment: @GurupadMamadapur cuz we're out of chars :P Pyth is ascii only.

Answer (score 1):

### Groovy, 120 bytes

```groovy
p={x->(2..<x).every{x%it!=0}&x>1|x==2}
{x->(1..x).findAll({y->p(y)&'10'.every{p(Integer.toBinaryString(y).count(it))}})}
```

This is an unnamed closure.

[Try it here!](http://ideone.com/LWnXW3)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 110 bytes

```js
B=n=>n?B(n>>1,v[n%2]++):v.every(n=>(P=i=>n%--i?P(i):1==i)(n))
F=(n,a=[])=>n?F(n-1,B(n,v=[0,0,n])?[n,...a]:a):a
```

```js
B=n=>n?B(n>>1,v,v[n%2]++):v.every(n=>(P=i=>n%--i?P(i):1==i)(n))
F=(n,a=[])=>n?F(n-1,B(n,v=[0,0,n])?[n,...a]:a):a

const update = () => {
  console.clear();
  console.log(F(input.value))
}

input.oninput = update;
update();
```

```html
<input id="input" type="number" min="1" value="100" />
```

Comment: That primality test function is... just amazing :-) Did you create it yourself?

Comment: @ETHproductions You've seen it before http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91309/11182 modified from here. I also borrowed your 1 and 0 counting code (whooped anything I could come up with) but alas I couldn't beat your byte count.

Comment: @ETHproductions Good catch thanks! Was an artefact of a previous version

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 97 bytes

```python
def f(n,k=2,m=1,p={0}):f(n-1,k+1,m*k*k,p^{m%k*k,{*map(bin(m%k%n*k)[2:].count,'01')}<p==print(k)})
```

This is the same algorithm as in [my Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/107073/12012), but the implementation is quite different. The function prints to STDOUT and terminates with an error.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#FchNCsJADEDhq7gpTcZUJgU3xZxEKvg3UMLEUOpqmLOPdfe@117vdEhgpDJSFiaXEitO@xqY9MiUgwYlv5Xc/aOEfHd4LAa7OwuK13GaT8/P1zbqI/dYLy7i62IbKFZsCfgcsf0A)

Answer (score 1):

## **MATLAB, 50 bytes**

```
@(n)all(isprime([n,sum(de2bi(n)),sum(~de2bi(n))]))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haxe, <s>158</s> 147 bytes

```
function p(n,x=1)return n%++x<1||n<2?x==n:p(n,x);function f(n){var q=n,t=0,o=0;while(q>0){t++;o+=q%2;q>>=1;}p(n)&&p(o)&&p(t-o)?trace(n):0;f(n-1);};
```

Outputs to STDOUT and terminates on a "too much recursion" error; call with e.g. `f(1000);`. You can use a `while` loop with no error for 156 bytes:

```
function p(n,x=1)return n%++x<1||n<2?x==n:p(n,x);function f(n){while(n>0){var q=n,t=0,o=0;while(q>0){t++;o+=q%2;q>>=1;}p(n)&&p(o)&&p(t-o)?trace(n):0;n--;}};
```

Using a range turned out three bytes longer:

```
function p(n,x=1)return n%++x<1||n<2?x==n:p(n,x);function f(n){for(i in 0...n+1){var q=i,t=0,o=0;while(q>0){t++;o+=q%2;q>>=1;}p(i)&&p(o)&&p(t-o)?trace(i):0;}};
```

[Test it online!](http://try.haxe.org/#70094)

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, 147 bytes

```
fn f(x:u32){let p=|n|n>1&&(2..n).all(|x|n%x!=0);for n in 9..x+1{if p(n)&&p(n.count_ones())&&p(n.count_zeros()-n.leading_zeros()){print!("{} ",n)}}}
```

[playground link](https://is.gd/zkedvo)

The `count_ones`, `count_zeros`, and `leading_zeros` methods came in handy.

#### Formatted version

```
fn f(x: u32) {
    // primality test closure using trial division
    let p = |n| n > 1 && (2..n).all(|x| n % x != 0);

    for n in 9..x + 1 {
        if p(n) && p(n.count_ones()) && p(n.count_zeros() - n.leading_zeros()) {
            print!("{} ", n)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 16 bytes

```
↑<⁰foΛṗo§e#0Σḋİp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9odXNr///ihpE84oGwZm/Om@G5l2/Cp2UjMM6j4biLxLBw////MTA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>15</s> 13 bytes

```
fȯΛṗmėΣ#0ḋḋŀ→
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P@3E@nOzH@6cnntk@rnFygYPd3QD0dGGR22T/v//b2hgAAA)

#### Explanation:

```
fȯΛṗmėΣ#0ḋḋŀ→
           ŀ→    Inclusive range from 0 to input
fȯ               Filter by
    mė             Map three functions over
          ḋ        The binary digits
      Σ              Sum of digits
       #0            Count of zeroes
         ḋ           And convert back to decimal
  Λṗ               Are all the results prime?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 15 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
õA fÈ¤ü mÊpX ej
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=9UEgZsik/CBtynBYIGVq&input=MTUw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
œPæ2B01,cPp
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDNSU5M1AlQzMlQTYyQjAxJTJDY1BwJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9MTUwJmZsYWdzPQ==)

##### Explanation

```python
œPæ2B01,cPp  # Implicit input
œP           # Only keep primes from [1..input]
  æ          # Filter this list of primes by:
   2B        #  Convert it to a binary list
     01,c    #  Count 0s and 1s
         Pp  #  Are they both prime?
             # Implicit output
```