# A prime test that's LITERALLY prime

Tags: code-golf, math, restricted-source, primes

Write a program that will test the primality of a specified number, and give the output as a Boolean value (True is prime). Your prime test can (but doesn't have to) be valid for the number 1.

Here's the catch: your program itself has to sum to a prime number. Convert every character (including spaces) to its Unicode/ASCII value ([table](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/american-standard-code-information-interchange/ascii-codes-table.png)). Then, add all those numbers together to get the sum of your program.

For example, take this not-so-great program I wrote in Python 3.3:

```
q=None
y=int(input())
for x in range(2,int(y**0.5)+1):
    if y%x==0:
        q=False
if not q:
    q=True
print(q)
```

If you convert all the characters to their corresponding Unicode/ASCII value, you get:

```
113 61 78 111 110 101 10 121 61 105 110 116 40 105 110 112 117 116 40 41 41 10 102 111 114 32 120 32 105 110 32 114 97 110 103 101 40 50 44 105 110 116 40 121 42 42 48 46 53 41 43 49 41 58 10 32 32 32 32 105 102 32 121 37 120 61 61 48 58 10 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 113 61 70 97 108 115 101 10 105 102 32 110 111 116 32 113 58 10 32 32 32 32 113 61 84 114 117 101 10 112 114 105 110 116 40 113 41
```

You can then find the sum of those numbers manually or with your own program. This specific program sums to 8293, which is a prime number.

Of course, this is Code Golf, so the smaller you can make your program, the better. As pointed out by other users, this program is not very golfy.

A few rules:

Valid inputs include STDIN and prompts (no functions, it's just a way to  add free extra code). Spaces are permitted, but only if they are crucial to the functionality of your program. Output must be an output, not just stored in a variable or returned (use print, STDOUT, etc.)

Flags can be used and should be counted literally, not expanded. Comments are not allowed. As for non-ASCII characters, they should be assigned to the value in their respective encoding.

Make sure to list your program's size and the sum of the program. I will test to make sure programs are valid.

Good luck!

Here is a snippet to count the sum of your program and check if it is prime:

```js
function isPrime(number) { var start = 2; while (start <= Math.sqrt(number)) { if (number % start++ < 1) return false; } return number > 1; } var inp = document.getElementById('number'); var text = document.getElementById('input'); var out = document.getElementById('output'); function onInpChange() { var msg; var val = +inp.value; if (isNaN(val)) { msg = inp.value.toSource().slice(12, -2) + ' is not a valid number.'; } else if (isPrime(val)) { msg = val + ' is a prime number!'; } else { msg = val + ' is not a prime number.'; } out.innerText = msg; } function onTextChange() { var val = text.value; var total = new Array(val.length).fill().map(function(_, i) { return val.charCodeAt(i); }).reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0); inp.value = '' + total; onInpChange(); } text.onkeydown = text.onkeyup = onTextChange; inp.onkeydown = inp.onkeyup = onInpChange;
```

```css
body { background: #fffddb; } textarea, input, div { border: 5px solid white; -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px  rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 0 0 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); -moz-box-shadow:  inset 0 0 8px  rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 0 0 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); box-shadow:  inset 0 0 8px  rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 0 0 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);  padding: 15px; background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5); margin: 0 0 10px 0; font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace; font-size: 0.9em; width: 75%; }</style><meta charset="utf-8"><style>/**/
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono" rel="stylesheet"><textarea id="input" tabindex="0">Insert your (UTF-8 encoded) code here
Or directly input a number below</textarea><br><input id="number" value="6296" tabindex="1"><br><div id="output">6296 is not a prime number.</div>
```

Comment: In non-golfing languages, it looks like you could just take the shortest prime-deciding code, and tweak variable names until the sum is prime.

Comment: Why the restrictions on I/O?

Comment: @JonathanAllan To prevent excessive and useless code. For example, if function arguments were allowed, you could choose a name for your function that would perfectly match the number you wanted.

Comment: What's a "Unibyte value" ?!???

Comment: Is our code allowed to exit with an error?

Comment: "Flags can be used and should be counted literally, not expanded." What does this mean? If my program runs as `perl -ne 'your code here'`, do I count the `n` which is the edit distance, or the `-n`?

Comment: Are built-ins allowed?

Comment: @mbomb007 Provided the built-ins come with the software by default (no custom-made built ins)

Comment: Do the I/O restrictions still allow full programs that take an argument?

Comment: You talk about characters and code pages. A Unicode character has always the same code point, no matter which encoding is used to represent it. *As for non-ASCII characters, they should be assigned to the value in their respective encoding.* makes me think you actually want the sum of the **byte** values to be prime

Comment: [Test Your code online](https://tio.run/nexus/php#ZY8xT4RAFIR7fsXL5pnAAYdX2Ny6ucJcYaONVsYQDh7wDLwlu8tVxr@Oq4mV5cx8mcncn5ZxAQByzrra0WJdYBnSr3P99Pzy@HDONFQV/ClgD2IDsEAYCTrqm3UKcG2mlQq4rP@S2L5nYUi23roUvel5onqgULdWAknwqYrMsap86FhUprE16N@Q8vxdZyi5sa5Lsc108tvA5pCj7Hb7u89bjXJTlsg609fG1d06L3EiktSOVk0kQxiNKpDKQ6E0@HU2KPFCtLg8nNTPFXVUqlCwOJ5J6WTbXj@@AQ)

Comment: @Titus It looks like your script is thrown off by the sequence `>0` in the input: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY8xb4MwFIR3fsWT9SpBgBCGLnGdDFGGLu3SraoQgQdYgmfLNpmq/nXqVurU8e4@3ensZLens50sAJBzxjWOrHFB85h@XZuX17fnyzWTUFXwp0B7YBNAM4SJoKehXecA93ZeqYDb@i@J7XvNGpJtMC5FrwY9UzNSaDrDgTj4VETmWFU@9JpFJrFT6N@R8vxDZsi5Mq5Psctk8tugVZ0j73b7x8@DRH4oS9Qyk/fWNf262DgRSeomI2biMUxKFEhlXQgJfl0UcrwQLV3WZ/FzRRyFKARYpxcSMtm206G9dd8 "PHP – Try It Online")

Comment: @Laikoni It´s not `>0`, it´s `0`. Here is a fixed version: [Verify primarity of your code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c88eac5629957791aa914aac4add9c252aaa8f0d).

Comment: Is it a lowest score or a shortest code?

Comment: @l4m2 The tag is `code-golf`, so it should be shortest code. (Or equivalently, the score is the byte length.) Challenges where the score is something special are usually tagged as `code-challenge`.

Answer (score 37):

### [hello, world!](https://github.com/histocrat/hello_world), 13 bytes, `1193`

```
hello, world!
```

Comment: ***perfect***. I heard of this language before, but to think it also happened to have a perfect byte sum for this challenge :D

Answer (score 7):

## Ruby, sum 3373, 37 bytes

```
require'prime'
g=gets.to_i
p g.prime?
```

Answer (score 7):

## Microscript II, 2 bytes (sum 137)

```
N;
```

## Microscript II, 4 bytes (sum 353)

```
N;ph
```

I'm actually quite surprised that both of these wound up having prime byte sums.

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, 50 bytes, `4201`

Works for 1. Output is positive if prime, or zero if not.

```python
p=input();print all(p%m for m in range(2,p))*~-p;p
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8A2M6@gtERD07qgKDOvRCExJ0ejQDVXIS2/SCFXITNPoSgxLz1Vw0inQFNTq063wLrg/38TIwNDAA)

---

## Python 2, 44 bytes, `3701`

Doesn't work for 1. Outputs a Boolean.

```python
p=input();print all(p%k for k in range(2,p))
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8A2M6@gtERD07qgKDOvRCExJ0ejQDVbIS2/SCFbITNPoSgxLz1Vw0inQFPz/39jcwNDAA)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes, `173`

```
p=
```

Explanation:

```
p  # Checks if number is prime - returns 1 if true and 0 if false. Uses implicit input.
 = # Wouldn't usually be required for this sort of program, but I added it to make the sum prime.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@19g@/@/KQA)

Comment: Something something "comments are not allowed" but I guess effective no-ops work fine :D

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, 2 bytes, `127`

```
/P
```

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2FP&input=127&debug=0)

Outputs `1` for primes, `0` for non-primes.

`/` has code point `47`. `P` has code point `80`.

How it works:

```
/P
/PQQ    Implicit variables.
        Q = input
 PQ     Prime factorize Q.
/  Q    Count how many times Q appears. 1 if prime, 0 if not.
```

Answer (score 5):

## Excel, <s>34</s> 30 bytes, sum <s>2039</s> 1759

```
=SUM(--(MOD(A2,ROW(A:A))=0))=2
```

Uses `ROW` instead of `SEQUENCE` which makes it shorter. As a added bonus, it now uses functions available at the time the question was asked.

### Original Answer

```
=SUM(--(MOD(A2,SEQUENCE(A2))=0))=2
```

Uses `SEQUENCE` which was not available when the question was posted.

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 1 byte, sum 23

```
æ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C3%A6&inputs=23&header=&footer=)

`æ` is the built-in primality checker. Vyxal uses its own codepage, in which the character `æ` is `0x17`, or `23`, which is a prime number.

Comment: My god. Those golfing languages really do think of everything!

Comment: @Pyautogui As far as I know, this one was just a coincidence, but it sure was convenient!

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 bytes, `191`

```
Uj
```

`U` :`85`

`j` : `106`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@x@a9f@/MQA)

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, 52 bytes, 4421

```
main=do
 k<-readLn
 print$product[1..k-1]`rem`k==k-1
```

Wilson theorem.

Comment: Turned it into a full standalone program.

Comment: The `::IO Int` really shouldn't be necessary unless that's the shortest way you can get a prime sum.

Comment: Good call. However, we then get some code that `hashes' to an even value. Adding spaces or new-lines does nothing (even values), nor does changing the name of the variable (it appears four times, so replacing its code (say c) amounts to subtracting 4 * c and adding 4 * c', leaving the sum even. However, it can be tweaked by breaking the lines and still be shorter, which I did.

Comment: 47 bytes with a different primality test: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM882JZ8zz0a3KDUxxSfPuqAoM69EJTEnR0PDzkBTLzc/hTNPM9pITy9P1zD2/39jczNzAA "Haskell – Try It Online") (note that there are tabs instead of spaces to get the count right).

Comment: Also welcome to PPCG!

Comment: @Laikoni well done. I think yours will be hard to beat.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 40 bytes, `3203`

*Saved 6 bytes thanks to [@l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76323/l4m2)*

```javascript
g=x=>m%--x?g(x):x<2;alert(g(m=prompt()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY7NCsIwEITvPsVSEDbYLP7c1FTExxCRsA1RaZqQVsnbx1QvHr0O38w3D/3SA8d7GGXvW5N1Z@IICtj3g@8Mdd7OQvQuTOEVVAOrTbYqqcbNpUwHi0ls0369@xTRolNfHIUQ@WcFz0RU/dusLhRN@2SDGGpgMYkDLICJbzqeytNj4WpYFskb)

Comment: `alert((F=x=>n%--x?F(x):!~-x)(n=prompt()))`

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 38 bytes, sum 2791

Fun fact: With `$h` instead of `$c`, the sum would be `2801` (also a prime), and its binary representation `101011110001` read as decimal is also a prime number.

```php
for($b=$c=$argv[1];$c%--$b;);echo$b<2;
```

takes command line argument, prints `1` or empty string. Run with `-r`.

Code taken from [my own prime function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008130/php-check-if-number-is-prime/39743570#39743570) (look at the original post if you can).

Comment: @Artyer It´s fixed.

Answer (score 2):

## R, 27 <s>32</s> bytes, sum 2243 <s>2609</s>

Saved a 5 bytes thanks to @rturnbull

```
cat(gmp::isprime(scan(),r=43)>0)
```

This makes use of the gmp library's isprime function.

```
> sum(as.integer(charToRaw('cat(!!gmp::isprime(scan()))')))
[1] 2243
> cat(!!gmp::isprime(scan()))
1: 2243
2: 
Read 1 item
TRUE
>
```

Comment: `cat(!!gmp::isprime(scan()))` is 5 bytes shorter, and sums to `2243`, also prime.

Comment: @rturnbull thanks for that :)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/) + `dfns`, 7 bytes

### Sum: 569

```apl
1 pco⌈⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qc6SCekpaXrE616OO9rT/hgoFyfmPejqAMv@BAv850xS4DI2NzQE) or [Verify](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qc6SCekpaXrE616OO9rT/hgoFyfmPejqAMv@BAv850xS4DLhApCGYNAKTxmDSBCJuwsUFVP2obYK6OowRXJqrkJ@mkJyfklqQn5lXAjS9GCiurQ@U9/TXfdS7AshwDHvUu1kdyUKgIpgBnsUKAUWZuan26lxgBQrFAA)

The program uses the ceiling function(`⌈`) since it's a no-op on integers, and pads the codepoint sum to a prime number, according to APL's code page.

`pco` is a function from the dfns library which checks for primality.

Comment: You either need to count the import, or use Extended with `⌂pco`. Same byte count, as you don't need the space on the left of `pco`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.primes`, sum 3373, 34 bytes

```
readln string>number prime? pprint
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQma@Qm1iSoVeQWFScWgRlF2XmphYrFBSllpRUAjl5JQrW/4tSE1Ny8hSKS4D8dLu80twkoHKwSnuFArCi//8NDQE)

Should be pretty self-explanatory I hope!

Comment: [28 bytes](https://tio.run/##fcu9CsIwFAVg8EkOnXRooKsOjuLiIn2AS3vEYpLGmxvBp4@lCG5u54fvJoPNWvvr@XLaY5rxoEZ68CUeQezukmimfrNOgRlJafZeSjRkPgvjsKyHqpTRx9Vu0bbYYIeVHOFq8@9tkEvAWBLcT3TdBw) using eval with stack effect (which allows adjusting the codepoint sum arbitrarily).

Comment: @Bubbler that is extremely clever, and rides the line between the 'no comments' rule in the best way.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 44 bytes, byte-sum 3109

This is [xnor's 44 byte implementation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58114/53748) with the lowest valued variable names that yield a prime byte sum.

Prints `1` if prime and `0` if not.

```
C=B=1
exec"B*=C*C;C+=1;"*~-input()
print B%C
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly) 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page), byte-sum 691

```
ƓÆḍ,ṠE
```

prints `1` if prime and `0` if not.

**[TryItOnline!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@39s8uG2hzt6dR7uXOD6/78xAA)**

The bytes in hexadecimal are `93 0D D5 2C CD 45` (see the [code page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)), or in decimal are `147 13 213 44 205 69` which sum to 691, which is prime.

#### How?

```
ƓÆḍ,ṠE - Main Link: no arguments
Ɠ      - read and evaluate a line from STDIN (integer expected)
 Æḍ    - proper divisor count
   ,   - paired with
    Ṡ  - sign
     E - all equal? - returns a boolean (1 or 0)
       - implicit print
```

The `Æḍ` functionality is such that primes and their negations return one while other integers do not (composites and their negations return numbers greater than one, one and minus one return zero and zero returns, oddly enough, minus one).

The `Ṡ` functionality is such that negative integers return minus one, zero returns zero and positive integers return one.

Thus the two functions only return the same value for the primes.

Note that the 3 byte program `ƓÆP` which directly tests if the input from STDIN is prime is unfortunately not a prime-sum program (240).

Testing for equality using `=`(equals), `e`(exists in), or `⁼`(non-vectorising equals) for 5 bytes also do not yield prime-sum programs.

---

## Alternative (maybe not acceptable) 4 bytes, sum 571

If the I/O restrictions still allow full programs that take an argument.

```
Æḍ⁼Ṡ
```

...using the same principle as above, where `⁼` is non-vectorising equality (the non-vectorising aspect has no effect since there is nothing to vectorise over anyway). The hex values are `0D D5 8C CD` which are `13 213 140 205` in decimal which sum to 571, a prime.

Again note that the 2 byte program `ÆP` does not have a prime sum (93).

Comment: `ƓÆPG` (311) and `ÆPF` (163) should be fine, I think?

Comment: As Unicode, for `ƓÆḍ,ṠE`, the value is `16183`, which is coincidentally prime!

Comment: @Lynn Yes, it seems the "unnecessary code restriction" (except for the space character) has been lifted, making `ƓÆPG` OK. I have also asked if a program taking input rather than the use of STDIN is acceptable.

Comment: ...If both such things are OK then `ÆP¥` is 3 bytes and 97.

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 4 bytes, byte-sum 439

```
qimp
```

Uses the built-in primality test.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@1@YmVvw/7@JsSUA)

#### Alternate solution, 4 bytes, sum 461

```
r~mp
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), <s>24</s> 22 bytes, `1949`

```perl6
say .is-prime
for +get
```

All three whitespace characters are required.
(Perl 6 doesn't care what *kind* of whitespace character they are, though, so I chose a newline instead of the more commonly used space for the second one...)

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, 21 bytes, `1997`

```
Print@*PrimeQ@Input[]
```

`Input[]` reads a line of input (from STDIN if no front end is used, through a dialog box if the Mathematica front end is used), `Print@*PrimeQ` is the composition ([`@*`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html)) of the `Print` and `PrimeQ` functions, and `@` is prefix function notation.

Answer (score 1):

### Pyth, 4 bytes, `367`

```
}QPQ
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%7DQPQ&input=367&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 8 bytes, `511`

```
0Na%,a=1
```

I wrote a prime checker, and the sum was prime. Convenient. Verify inputs 1-30: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#@@@mkKgQo2NsoFDNFaCQqFesp8HFZeCXqKqTaGvIxaVZ@///fyNjAA)

#### Explanation

```
          a is first command-line argument
    ,a    Numbers from 0 to a-1
  a%      Take a mod each of those numbers (a%0 gives nil)
0N        Count number of times 0 occurs in that list
      =1  If 0 occurs only 1 time (for a%1), then a is prime
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>62</s> 60 bytes, 4583

Pretty straight-forward. Outputs * if prime, otherwise it outputs a space. Does not work for 1.

-2 thanks to [l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76323/l4m2)

```c
p;main(i){for(scanf("%d",&p);++i<p;)p=p%i?p:0;puts("*"+!p);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/7/AOjcxM08jU7M6Lb9Iozg5MS9NQ0k1RUlHrUDTWls706bAWrPAtkA1077AysC6oLSkWENJS0lbEShb@/@/iamFMQA)

Comment: ```n;main(i){for(scanf("%d",&n);++i<n;)n=n%i?n:0;puts("*"+!n);}``` may need to change some variable name for prime sum

Comment: @l4m2 Nice one!

Answer (score 1):

## J, 18 Bytes, `1103`

```
echo 1&p:".(1!:1)1
```

Not far from optimal, the least I could golf a full program primality test to was 17 Bytes: `echo(p:[:".1!:1)1`, which unfortunately sums to 1133 = 11*103.

Unfortunately I can't figure out how to get keyboard input working on TIO, so no link yet.

#### Explanation:

```
echo 1&p:".(1!:1)1  | Full program
           (1!:1)1  | Read a line of input from keyboard
         ".         | Evaluate (converts string to int)
     1&p:           | 1 for prime, 0 for composite
echo                | Print result. The space is required, as 'echo1' would be interpreted as a variable
```

Validating the program:

```
   1 p:+/u:inv'echo 1&p:".(1!:1)1'  NB. Convert to ints, sum, and test primality
1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 23 bytes, `2111`

```
print(2>=numdiv(input))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/v6AoM69Ew8jONq80NyWzTCMzr6C0RFPz/38jQ0NDAA)

Comment: This challenge does not seem to allow functions.

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 36 bytes, byte-sum 2239

```
{for(a=1;$0%++a&&a<$0;);$0=(a==$0)}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/Oi2/SCPR1tBaxUBVWztRTS3RRsXAWhPItQUK26oYaNYa/v9vyGXEZcJlymVoyGVoxGVozGVmwGVmyAUA)

Outputs `0` if not prime and `1` for prime.
Definitely not the most efficient code, since it checks every integer greater than `1` to see if it divides the input.

Answer (score 1):

## [Whispers v2](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), 33 bytes

```
>>> ⊤ℙ∘ℕ
> Input
>> 1∘2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fzs5O4VHXkkctMx91zHjUMpXLTsEzr6C0hAsobggUAioxNAYA)

1. Score: `44381`
2. Only 6 bytes/2 characters added to make it valid!
3. **1** is not prime

### How it works

This is shown in the order it is executed in:

```
		; Line 3:
>>  ∘		; Compose...
   1            ; Line 1 with
     2          ; The result of line 2

		; Line 2:
> Input		; Retrieve a line of input

		; Line 1:
>>> ⊤		; The input is...
     ℙ		; Prime
      ∘		; And it is...
       ℕ	; Natural
```

Answer (score 1):

## Excel (57 bytes, code sum 3547)

```
=XOR(0<PRODUCT(MOD(A1,ROW(OFFSET(D2,0,,SQRT(A1))))),3>A1)
```

Excel doesn't really have an "input" as such, but this formula expects the number to be tested to be in A1 and outputs to whatever cell you drop it in. It's an array formula, so press Ctrl-Shift-Enter to enter it, rather than Enter.

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 27 bytes, byte-sum 2843

```
Prompt F
3
For(A,2,sqrt(F
If not(remainder(F,A
0
End
Disp Ans
```

Prints `3` for prime and `0` for composite. Does not work for 1 (prints `3`).

TI-Basic is a [tokenized lanugage](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/one-byte-tokens). `remainder(` is a two-byte token; all others are one-byte tokens.

Explanation:

```
Prompt F             # 0xdd, 0x46, 0x3f # Store input in F
3                    # 0x33, 0x3f       # Store 3 in Ans
For(A,2,sqrt(F       # 0xd3, 0x41, 0x2b, 0x32, 0x2b, 0xbc, 0x46, 0x3f
                        # For each integer A from 2 to sqrt(F)
If not(remainder(F,A # 0xce, 0xb8, (0xef, 0x32), 0x46, 0x2b, 0x41, 0x3f
0                    # 0x30, 0x3f
                        # If F is divisible by A, store 0 in Ans
End                  # 0xd4, 0x3f # end For loop
Disp Ans             # 0xde, 0x72 (no newline) # Print Ans
```

Sum testing with Python:

```
>>> sum(eval(i) for i in ['0xdd', '0x46', '0x3f', '0x33', '0x3f', '0xd3', '0x41', '0x2b', '0x32', '0x2b', '0xbc', '0x46', '0x3f', '0xce', '0xb8', '0xef', '0x32', '0x46', '0x2b', '0x41', '0x3f', '0x30', '0x3f', '0xd4', '0x3f', '0xde', '0x72'])
2843
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>114</s> 105 bytes, Prime 9209

```java
interface M{static void main(String[]a){long n=new Long(a[0]),B=n;for(;n%--B>0;);System.out.print(B<2);}}
```

Assumes \$input\geq2\$ (will give a division-by-zero error for \$input=1\$), since the rule mention "*Your prime test can (but doesn't have to) be valid for the number \$1\$.*".

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##DcuxCoMwEADQX8kiJGAkuMnVDpnt5CgOh0aJrZcSr5Yifnvq9pa34I56GZ8peWIXJxyceBwbI/tB7MGPYkVPsuXoae56VMcr0CyoJvcVzUWJnelVbmuCKUQJlGlt7wYUtL@N3VqEDxfva7O0t1LBeaaUqtJUfw)

**Explanation:**

```java
interface M{                   // Class
  static void main(String[]a){ //  Mandatory main-method
    long n=new Long(a[0]),     //   The first argument as number
    B=n;for(;n%--B>0;);        //   Check if `n` is a prime
    System.out.print(B<2);}}   //   Print whether `n` was a prime
                               //   (if `B` is 1 after the loop, it means it wasn't
                               //   divisible by any other integer in the range [2,n),
                               //   and therefore is a prime)
```

I've used `B` instead of `i` as variable name to make the unicode sum a prime. [Verify the unicode sum here.](https://tio.run/##jY2xDoIwFAB/pYtJm9iGuFYcOuvESBheSsGivJr2gTGEb6/o6uJ2ueFugBnk0N5y9kgudmAduyyJgLxlc/AtG8Ejryh67OsGxFK9ErlRhYnUY5PEoS4aZa8QExcqTSMXQq9r/r94D9gzLNE92XnDb1DsTYm6C5Fr3ElpToUW@mdtjofP6w0)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes, [Σ](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page) = 239

```
ÆPa1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW0Ci4f///40A)

Proof: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDK/MwxMeNa151DAz@HBbwP///9WBVKKhOgA) (take the 1-based indices of the program's chars of Jelly's code page, decrement to make them 0-based, sum and then check if the result is prime).

Answer (score 1):

## [Help, WarDoq!](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Help%2C_WarDoq!), 2 bytes, ∑ 127

```
P/
```

**Outputs 1 if it is a prime (positive only) and 0 if it is not a prime**.

[Try it online!](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l%3AQ%7B%22HhEeLlOoWwRrDd%2C!AaPpQq%22Q%7C%5B%22Hh%22%22ello%22a%5B%27%2CL%5DSa%22Ww%22%22orld%22a%5B%27!L%5D%5D%3Am*%3A%60%5B%7Briri%2B%7D%7Briri%5E%7D%7Brimp%7D%7Brizmp%7DQ%60Q%7B%5C%2B%7D*%60L%5D%2Ber%3A%7EN*%7D%3AH%7E&input=P%2F%0A127) **Note: Due to technical limitations, this interpreter takes the first line as the code and the second line as STDIN.**

1 is not prime in this.

The code's codepoints are `80 47`, which sums to `127`.

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 14 bytes

```
~.,{*.!+}*.*\%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v05Pp1pLT1G7VktPK0b1/38LC3MA)

Same [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211129/98257) for the question "[Is this number a prime?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/57617/98257)", the program sums to 887.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 2 bytes, byte sum 149

```
ṗ⁸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//4c7pjxp3/P9vAgA)

Uses Pyt's custom encoding, in which the bytes are as follows:

```
8d 08
```

Explanation:

```
ṗ         checks for primality (returns True/False)
⁸         raises top of stack to the 8th power (coerces True/False to 1/0); implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), `191`

Well, that worked out nicely! :)

```
Uj
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=VWo&input=MTkx)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), 3 bytes (UTF-8), [sum = 293](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhZ7Cooy80o0iktzNXITCzTyi1J0MvMKSks0NIEAogSqcsFiv8PTIUwA)

```
N×
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhaL_Q5Ph7CgAgsWGRpCWAA)

[Verify that 293 is prime](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3jfJsM_NKNDLzCkpLNDQ1uQqKQNzEnByNPNVMhbT8IoVMhcw8haLEvPRUDSOdPE1NTYhOqAELFhtZGkOYAA)

Basically, the Thunno interpreter ignores any characters which are not in the printable ASCII set (32-127). As `×` has the codepoint 215, it is ignored and thus the program becomes `N`, which is the prime check program.

### [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 4 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 3.29 bytes, [sum = 269](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhZ7Cooy80o0iktzNXITCzTyi1J0MvMKSks0NIEAogSqcsESPxcDbwgbAA)

```
ND0K
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhZL_FwMvCFMqMiCRYaGEBYA)

[Verify that 269 is prime](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3jfJsM_NKNDLzCkpLNDQ1uQqKQNzEnByNPNVMhbT8IoVMhcw8haLEvPRUDSOdPE1NTYhOqAELFhuZWUKYAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
ND0K  # Implicit input
N     # Prime check (this is all we need, but unfortunately the ordinal of N is 78, which isn't prime)
 D    # Duplicate (completely unnecessary, but needed to make the sum prime)
  0   # Push a 0
   K  # And pop the 0 (yep, that cancels out)
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 42 bytes, `2687`

```
INPUT N:FOR D=2TO N/2P=P+!(N MOD D)NEXT?!P
```

Outputs 1 (true) if the number is prime, otherwise 0 (false).

The variable names were not just chosen to make the program prime.
`N` is the **n**umber to test, `D` is the **d**ivisor, and `P` keeps track of whether N is **p**rime.

Answer (score 0):

## [Wonder](https://github.com/wonderlang/wonder), 7 bytes, `537`

```
pr rl e
```

There probably is a better way...

Answer (score 0):

## Rust, 190 bytes, 15013 score

```
fn main(){let A=&mut"".into();std::io::stdin().read_line(A);let(B,mut C)=(A.trim().parse::<u64>().unwrap(),true);for H in 2..((B as f64).sqrt()+1.0) as u64{if B%H==0{C=false}}print!("{}",C)}
```

Ungolfed

```
fn main() {
    let input = &mut "".into();
    std::io::stdin().read_line(input);
    let (number, mut prime) = (input.trim().parse::<u64>().unwrap(), true);

    for x in 2..((number as f64).sqrt() + 1.0) as u64 {
        if number % x == 0 {
            prime = false;
        }
    }

    print!("{}", prime);
}
```

Does not work for 1

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 349

```
|pq
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7Cpq&i=349&a=1)

Comment: `|pQ` works for a score of 317. If swapping truthy/falsy is allowed, `|p!` works as well for 269.

Comment: Thank you. I don't think the challenge require that the score be minimized so I didn't tweak that part.

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 33 bytes (sum 2237)

```javascript
p=(n,i=1)=>++i*i>n||n%i&&p(n,i,1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hctRCoMwDADQqwxhJVk70QOkH7tJiXVEXBp0G35494on8PfBm9I/rbyIfZ9ahlyrEWgQ6pGi9/KQqPuud3HOTg89Vi66ljm3c3mDwes3jnmB5vI12H6SwUbxxp62wNShc4xYDw)

Comment: This challenge does not allow function solutions.

Answer (score 0):

### Python, 78 Bytes, `6067`

```python
x=lambda a:a and a*x(a-1)or 1
y=lambda b:x(b-1)%b==b-1
print(y(int(input(3))))
```

The `3` is kinda redundant, just there to make the code sum prime. The first `lambda` calculates the factorial of a number and the second `lambda` checks whether a number is prime using [Wilson's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem).

Comment: The `True if` ... `else False` is redundant, since it will return a Boolean anyway

Comment: You need to delete the `if`

Comment: it would be shorter to change the variable names rather than add an extra `7`

Comment: @JoKing it just obfuscates the code in my opinion

Comment: Well, the goal of [tag:code-golf] is to have the smallest amount of bytes, not the clearest code

Comment: @TheThonnu The challenge prohibits functions. Yeah, that's bad, but that's how it's been written, and I'm not aware of any [Meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/) post that's countermanded that. If the challenge had been written in the past few years I'm sure it wouldn't have felt the need to include that rule.

Comment: @Deadcode  I didn't see that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

### [vemf](https://github.com/selaere/vemf), 9 bytes, sum 911

```
{α%├2↕α&☻
```

Prints `1` if \$\alpha\$ is prime and `0` if it is not. Somehow *does* work on 1, because an empty list is considered truthy.

In the vemf codepage this is represented as

```
7b e0 25 c3 32 12 e0 26 02
```

which sums to `0x38f` = decimal 911.

### Explanation

```
{α%├2↕α&☻
{         ' define function
 α%    &  ' are all of the remainders nonzero
   ├2↕α   ' between 2 and α-1?
        ☻ ' reprints, just to make the program's sum a prime number
```