# Primes other than Optimus

Tags: code-golf, sequence, arithmetic, primes

### Challenge

Given an input integer `n > 0`, output the number of primes (*other* than `n`, if `n` itself is prime) that can be produced by altering one digit in the decimal expansion of n (without changing the number of digits).

### Examples

For example, `n = 2`. By altering one digit in the decimal expansion of `2`, we can come up with three additional prime numbers, `3, 5, 7`, so `a(n) = 3`.

For another example, `n = 13`. By altering one digit, you can get primes `11, 17, 19, 23, 43, 53, 73, 83`, so `a(13) = 8`.

For a final example, `n = 20`. By altering one digit, you can get primes `23, 29`, so `a(20) = 2`.

### Sequence

Here are the first 20 terms to get you started. This is OEIS [A048853](http://oeis.org/A048853).

`4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 7, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 7, 4, 7, 2`

### Rules

- The input and output can be assumed to fit in your language's native integer type.
- The input and output can be given [in any convenient format](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- Ignore leading zeros (for example, `03` is not a prime number under this formulation).
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- If possible, please include a link to an online testing environment so other people can try out your code!
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: I'm trying to think of the smallest `n` for which the output is `0`. I think it's `n = 200`. I also think they come in bunches: `200,202,204,206,208`, `320,322,...,328`, `510,...,518`, `620,...628`, `840,...,848`, etc.

Comment: Does "The input and output can be assumed to fit in your language's native integer type" states that we are not allowed to take input as string?

Comment: @DeadPossum No, that's allowed. Just that you don't need to worry about 2^100 as input if you only are using 32-bit integers, for example.

Comment: Do let me know if I'm going overboard... I have 3 different submissions now

Comment: @EngineerToast The bunches happen because a number `>7` ending in one of `0,2,4,5,6,8` cannot be prime. However it might be possible to have a single *prime* number that still gives output 0, and has no such bunch because that prime itself gives 1 for the others. However, I tried searching (rather inefficiently) up to 99999 and didn't find any.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen I just searched for when the list of primes skipped over an entire range `10n` to `10(n+1)` and then picked every even within that range. Picking the even values forces you to change just the ones digit since leaving it guarantees the result won't be prime. Anything you could change it to won't be prime, either, since there's no other prime in those ten numbers.

Comment: +1 for the title (and the excellent challenge as well of course).

Comment: @EngineerToast You can also include the number ending in 5. What I'm saying is that there *could* be a number with output 0 not of that type, if we're extremely lucky. (It seems hard to avoid hitting other primes, but only for statistical reasons.)

Comment: @EngineerToast After finding the first example prime (294001), I finally thought of looking it up on OEIS: [A192545](http://oeis.org/A192545) and [A158124](http://oeis.org/A158124). Also relevant: [A143641](http://oeis.org/A143641).

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen It's too bad we can't give bounties for comments. That's great work!

Answer (score 10):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>17</s> <s>16</s> <s>14</s> 11 bytes

```
ā°`<Ÿʒ.L}pO
```

Explanation:

```
ā             Push inclusive range from 1 to the length of the input
 °            Raise 10 to the power of each element
  `           Push each element to the stack
   <          Decrement the topmost element
    Ÿ         Inclusive range
              For 13, this creates an array like [10 11 12 13 14 .. 98 99]
     ʒ.L}     Only keep elements with a levenshtein distance to the input of
              exactly one
         p    Check each element for primality
          O   Sum
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//SOOhDQk2R3ecmqTnU1vg//@/oTEA) or [up to 100](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/e9TVmmvpKBrp6BkX/n/SOOhDQk2R3ecmlSp51Nb4P9f57@hgQEA).

Comment: `.L`? Seriously? `.L`?!?!

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer `L`.

Comment: I mean, there's a builtin for levenshtein distance!

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I know it's been a while, but you can remove the `<` to save a byte. Even if the filter doesn't remove the `100`/`1000`/`10000`/etc., it's never a prime anyway so won't affect the output.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>146 136 127 121</s> 118 bytes

Thanks to @Mr.Xcoder for suggestions

```python
lambda I:sum(all(i%v for v in range(2,i))*sum(z!=x for z,x in zip(I,`i`))==1for i in range(1+10**~-len(I),10**len(I)))
```

Explanation:

Generate numbers with length equal to input length, skipping first (1,10,100,1000,... )

```python
for i in range(1+10**~-len(I),10**len(I))
```

Check that generated number differs from input by only one digit

```python
sum(z!=x for z,x in zip(I,`i`))==1
```

Check for prime

```python
all(i%v for v in range(2,i))
```

Count

```python
sum(...)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVHRSsMwFH3PV1yR0qTLoEk7LYX4Ij4UBj746IarWF2gTUubzdkHf72alGzVgW/C5XBzzr03cE7zobe14sNSrIYyr55fcsjSblfhvCyx9PbwWrewB6mgzdVbgTmVhARmoL8QB6v29GD0XjY4oxu5IUQIZgR5WmMzFgbB57wsFM4INY@xJWT4PUo5IymCppVKg6T@/ManS2wOI3R/lz2AgMeYQmQr/oljXVtMzphv5A6vLPIJs5hgMlEXbiayW5HrowmT/MPlxPF/X2aWZ5ZhrmLHmyac2rFGun7SRaeNjaOtcJaAycZYTWaMrBEao/BX6raumrwt4F3qLdgsdg3oGi69LvW94xaF4x/Cjg08/AI)

Comment: Might it be shorter to not make this a lambda, and do `r=range`, since you use it many times...?

Comment: Does this work for things like `143`? Because I see `range(1,10)`, that excludes `0`, and `103` is prime

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder fixed

Comment: You do not need `0` in `r(0,10)`. `r(10)` suffices.

Comment: Also, I suggest putting it as such: `lambda I,r=range:`

Comment: I see the range idea was helpful for all the answers here :D

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder a bit to be proud of :D

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>21</s> <s>18</s> 15 bytes

3 bytes thanks to Dennis.

```
æḟ⁵æR×⁵$DnDS€ċ1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wsoc75j9q3Hp4WdDh6UBaxSXPJfhR05oj3Yb///83NAYA) or [Verify all testcases](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wsoc75j9q3Hp4WdDh6UBaxSXPJfhR05oj3Yb/jQwOtwOZ/wE).

Comment: `æḟ⁵æR×⁵$DnDS€ċ1` saves a few bytes.

Comment: The alternative range is quite clever.

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript (ES6) 148 bytes

Takes the input as a string and returns as a number

```js
n=>(n.replace(/./g,"$`a$' ").split` `.map(s=>s&&[..."0123456789"].map(d=>r+=+(t=s.replace(/a/,d))[0]&&t^n&&(p=v=>t>1&(--v<2||t%v&&p(v)))(t)),r=0),r)
```

**Example code snippet:**

```js
f=
n=>(n.replace(/./g,"$`a$' ").split` `.map(s=>s&&[..."0123456789"].map(d=>r+=+(t=s.replace(/a/,d))[0]&&t^n&&(p=v=>t>1&(--v<2||t%v&&p(v)))(t)),r=0),r)

for(var k=1;k<=20;k++)
  o.innerText+=f(""+k)+" "
```

```html
<pre id=o></pre>
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>153</s> <s>142</s> 139 bytes

```
n=>([...n].map((c,i,[...a])=>[...''+1e9].map((u,j)=>s+=j+i&&j!=c?p((a.splice(i,1,j),a.join``)):0),s=0,p=q=>eval('for(k=q;q%--k;);k==1')),s)
```

Accepts input as a string. Undefined behavior for invalid input, though it should terminate without error on any string I can think of. Not necessarily before the heat-death of the universe though, particularly for long strings.

#### Demo

```js
f=
n=>([...n].map((c,i,[...a])=>[...''+1e9].map((u,j)=>s+=j+i&&j!=c?p((a.splice(i,1,j),a.join``)):0),s=0,p=q=>eval('for(k=q;q%--k;);k==1')),s)
console.log([...''+1e19].map((_,i)=>f(i+1+'')).join())
i.onchange=()=>console.log(f(i.value))
```

```html
<input id=i>
```

#### Improvements

Saved 11 bytes by refactoring the `reduce()` calls into `map()` calls, and by implicitly copying the array `a` in the function parameter, instead of in within the context of the `splice()` call.

Saved 3 bytes thanks to [@Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/137195/primes-other-than-optimus/137270#comment336215_137270)'s suggestion to convert `[...Array(10)]` to `[...''+1e9]`.

#### Unminified code

```
input => (
  [...input].map(
    (char, decimal, [...charArray]) =>
      [...'' + 1e9].map(
        (unused, digit) => sum +=
          digit + decimal && digit != char ?
            prime(
              (
                charArray.splice(decimal, 1, digit)
                , charArray.join``
              )
            ) :
            0
      )
    , sum = 0
    , prime = test => eval('for(factor = test; test % --factor;); factor == 1')
  )
  , sum
)
```

#### Explanation

The function uses a two-level `map()` to sum the amount of permutations that pass the primality test, which was borrowed and modified from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57617/is-this-number-a-prime/91309#91309).

#### <sub>(Original answer)</sub>

```
reduce((accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array) => aggregate, initialValue)
```

So for example, to calculate the sum of an array, you would pass an `initialValue` of `0`, and return an `aggregate` equal to `accumulator + currentValue`. Modifying this approach slightly, we instead calculate the number of permutations that pass the primality test:

```
reduce(
  (passedSoFar, currentDecimal, currentIndex, digitArray) =>
    isValidPermutation() ?
      passedSoFar + prime(getPermutation()) :
      passedSoFar
  , 0
)
```

That is essentially the inner `reduce()`, which iterates all the permutations of the `digitArray` by changing each `decimal` to a specific `permutatedDigit`. We then need an outer `reduce()` to iterate all possible `permutatedDigit`'s with which to replace each `decimal`, which is just `0-9`.

#### Abnormalities in implementation

`[...''+1e9].map((u,j)=>...` was the shortest way [@Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/137195/primes-other-than-optimus/137270#comment336215_137270) could think of to iterate an argument `0` through `9`. It would be preferable to do so with `u`, but `u` is not useful for each element in the array, in this case.

`i+j` in the ternary condition checks to ensure that `0` is not a possible permutation of the leading digit, as per the challenge specification. `j!=c` ensures that the original `n` is not a candidate to go through the primality test.

``` (a.splice(i,1,j),a.join``) ``` is kind of a mess. `splice()` replaces the digit at `decimal == i` with the `permutatedDigit == j`, but since `splice()` returns the removed elements (in this case, would be equal to `[a[i]]`) instead of the modified array, we must use the comma operator to pass the modified array `a` to the primality test, but not before `join()`ing it into a number string.

Lastly, the `eval()` is to save a byte since, compared to the more canonical approach, it is shorter:

```
q=>eval('for(k=q;q%--k;);k==1')
```

```
q=>{for(k=q;q%--k;);return k==1}
```

The reference to the prime test `p` is initialized in an unused argument to the `map()` call.

Comment: I think the tips page says `[...''+1e9]` is shorter.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 105 bytes

```
F=Count[Range[f=IntegerDigits;g=10^Length@f@#/10,10g],n_/;PrimeQ@n&&MatchQ[f@n-f@#,{x=0...,_,x}]&&n!=#]&;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc3BCsIgGADgV1kMPNnUriIIjUFQ0LqKDRn662F/sBkMomc3ofsH3@JyTPNWyqDOrzdm83AI3gR1wezBr32ClDcJSvDn1SPkqINumeBUcLAUJybva1r8qJGQm8tzHE3QeKyIfnbFu66jE92/lhA8qNYSWaqvz9Aw3fyzE7e2/AA)

`Function` which expects a positive integer `#`. Sets `f` equal to the function `IntegerDigits` which returns the list of digits of its input. We take the `Range` from `g` to `10g` (inclusive), where `g=10^Length@f@#/10` is the largest power of `10` less than or equal to the input `#`, then `Count` the `n` such that `PrimeQ@n&&MatchQ[f@n-f@#,{x=0...,_,x}]&&n!=#`. `PrimeQ@n` checks whether `n` is prime, `MatchQ[f@n-f@#,{x=0...,_,x}]` checks whether the difference between the list of digits of `n` and `#` is of the form `{0..., _, 0...}`, and `n!=#` ensures that `n` and `#` are `Unequal`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 134 bytes

```python
lambda x,r=range,l=len:sum(~-f*(~-l(x)==sum(`f`[t]==x[t]for t in r(l(x))))and all(f%v for v in r(2,f))for f in r(10**~-l(x),10**l(x)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU5BCsIwELz7ir1Ik7IFm2MhfkSFRNpoYJuWGEu9@PWYNXMYdnZmll0/6bkElUlfM9n5PlrYMepow2NC0jSF4fWexbdzbSESu9SaF8aZS7ppvRd2S4QEPkAUHCiwYQRLJNxxA3a36ip0UrJ2Vfentq1Hkcdazhzw/wA/IXpUvRwOULBGHxIYbxCa7twgkChC5h8)

More elegant, longer version:

```python
lambda x,r=range,l=len:l(filter(lambda f:(~-f*(~-l(x)==sum(`f`[t]==x[t]for t in r(l(x)))))*all(f%v for v in r(2,f)),r(10**~-l(x),10**l(x))))
```

The input is taken as a String.

---

## Explanation (older version)

- `lambda x,r=range,l=len:` - Defines a lambda with a String parameter `x` and two constant parameters `r=range` and `l=len`.
- `sum(1...)` - Get the length, which saves 1 byte over `len([...])`.
- `for f in r(10**~-l(x),10**l(x))` - Generates absolutely all the numbers with the same order of magnitude as the input (expect for `0`). For instance, an input of `3`, would result in `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`.
- `` sum(1for t in r(l(x))if`f`[t]==x[t])==~-l(x)and f>1 `` - Checks if the current number is exactly 1 digit away from the input, and that it is higher than 1.
- `all(f%v for v in r(2,f))` - Checks if the current number is prime.

Comment: You cound change `sum(1for..ifBOOL)` to `sum(BOOLfor)` to save some bytes

Comment: Are we allowed to take input as string? Looking at "The input and output can be assumed to fit in your language's native integer type" I'm not sure

Comment: @DeadPossum Some of the answers do. Why wouldn't it be allowed?!

Comment: I'm ran out of votes for today, but will +1 asap :D

Comment: @DeadPossum Sure. Don't forget or I'll ping you! (`</joke>`)

Comment: Duty fulfilled!

Comment: @DeadPossum Thanks, well done :P

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 32 bytes

```
Lof§&ȯ=1Σzo±≠d⁰o=Ld⁰L↑o≤Ld⁰Lmdİp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8eGOxf998tMOLVc7sd7W8NziqvxDGx91Lkh51Lgh39YHRPk8apuY/6hzCYSTm3JkQ8H///@NDAA)

#### Ungolfed/Explanation

```
                              İp  -- get all primes
                            md    -- and convert them to list of digits
                     ↑o≤   L      -- take as long as the lenghth of these digit lists are ≤ ..
                        Ld⁰       -- .. the number of digits of input 
 of                               -- from those primes filter:
               o=Ld⁰L             --   same number of digits as input
   §&                             --   and
        Σz                        --   the number of..
          o±≠d⁰                   --   .. digits that differ from input digits ..
     ȯ=1                          --   .. must be one
L                                 -- finally count them
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 137 bytes

```js
i=(a=prompt()).length;s=0;while(i--)for(j=0;j<=9;j++){(b=[...a]).splice(i,1,j);k=b=b.join('');while(b%--k);s+=i+j&&a[i]!=j&&k==1}alert(s)
```

Adapts [my other answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137270/42091) into a full-program submission using the Web API methods `prompt()` and `alert()`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Bean](https://github.com/patrickroberts/bean), 126 bytes

```
00000000: a64d a065 8050 80a0 5d20 8001 a64d a06f  ¦M e.P. ] ..¦M o
00000010: 8025 39b5 cb81 2065 27a6 4da0 6680 2581  .%9µË. e'¦M f.%.
00000020: 0035 cb81 2066 27a6 53d0 80cd a05e 8043  .5Ë. f'¦SÐ.Í ^.C
00000030: cf20 5d00 2080 82a0 65a5 3a20 66a6 4da0  Ï ]. .. e¥: f¦M 
00000040: 6780 4da0 5e80 53d0 80a0 5e20 807b 2300  g.M ^.SÐ. ^ .{#.
00000050: b5cc a05e 8f4b c120 6728 264d a06f 814e  µÌ ^.KÁ g(&M o.N
00000060: cecc a065 8b20 6681 4cd0 84a0 5d20 6581  ÎÌ e. f.LÐ. ] e.
00000070: 2066 814c a067 8025 3a26 206f b130        f.L g.%:& o±0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZE7UsMwEIZ7TrEzTALVjqyXlbSUEIYZ6jAjyXK65ABU1DyP4AZ6ilxAPpjZVeSgwl6N7G@//RWS30@TqGsN3uoOvLAGnDCCHl6A6SRXojmf9gD5Z5OHhA@Yhy0glu3h4oRpCOSENKBWwUAMrgHJSNl6C7ojpLVOgDR0ALhY5eP4ipCuCqTHBVaOJI4Q6h9hTwijOhaK7GISVVoRxzCkJ8jj@IXjex6e8KaCFIFiL3kUQX0FNXeSNYwnSS9ZaFaD8RO2yCMNKX@voS9WFaQJZFv6vXxqElVVpmxLTm0AqagN7HDDEqxDb8Dny3kwQ5hgYqz@vQ4QG7ZopQN5Dtk1OlHSx/GNObfjC@yul5wz3leQ5cFSAfGVhTIJZaUjS@n58mxJevxgUKKQ8K44bSHNRi2BSsDUs9DaeoNeWj7oITSKZjotAuRhh4v1Eg75V0yT@QM)

An adaption of [my full-program JavaScript submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137280/42091).

#### JavaScript Equivalent

```
i=a.length
s=0
while(i--){
  j=10
  while(j--){
    (b=[...a]).splice(i,1,j)
    k=b=b.join('')
    while(b%--k);
    s+=i+j&&a[i]!=j&&k==1
  }
}
s
```

#### Explanation

`a` is implicitly initialized as the first line of input as a string and the last statement `s` is implicitly output, which contains the sum of prime permutations.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>151</s> <s>147</s> <s>141</s> <s>140</s> <s>136</s> <s>134</s> <s>129</s> 128 bytes

*-6 bytes thanks to @Einacio; -1 byte thanks to @Titus*

```php
<?php for($i=$m=10**strlen($n=$argv[1]);$i-->$m/10;)if(levenshtein($n,$i)==$f=$t=1){while($t<$i)$f+=$i%$t++<1;$c+=$f==2;}echo$c;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpNDsIgEAbQq7j4TKDYyLilowcxLgwBmaQ/hJK6MJ4d7fbl5ZRbG2455UNcioIwJibbdWstY5gVZsazvLY7PbSD9P0V05ms0xLVGLYwr6kG2d8JopkRGZVJf95JxqBQhz8jGoYcUY0ZyMGbvfHFfYNPC7xrrZGlHw)

Formatted, with comments:

```php
<?php
// Work through each integer with the same number of digits as the input $argv[1].
for ($i = $m = 10 ** strlen($n = $argv[1]); $i-- > $m / 10;)
    // Is it exactly one digit different from the input?
    if (levenshtein($n, $i) == $f = $t = 1) {
        // Count its factors.
        while ($t < $i) $f += $i % $t++ < 1;
        // If there are exactly 2 factors then it's a prime, so increment the counter.
        $c += $f == 2;
    }
// Print the final count.
echo $c;
```

To keep it as short as I could, I've:

- combined assignments `$f = $t = 1`;
- snook in a `++` increment as part of another expression `$f += $i % $t++ == 0` (the increment is executed *after* the modulus operation and so does not affect its result);
- and rather than using an `if` statement for a conditional increment have utilised the fact that boolean true when cast as an integer becomes 1, using `$c += $f == 2;` rather than `if ($f == 2) $c++;`.

Comment: you don't need to define $c, it counts as 0 on the first +=

Comment: @Einacio What are the golf rules? Is that allowed, as it gives an undefined variable warning notice?

Comment: @Einacio Apparently any output to STDERR can be ignored, so thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: +1 for use of `levenshtein`. Nice idea! `$i%$t++<1` is shorter than `$i%$t++==0`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>28</s> 23 bytes

*-5 bytes thanks to @ETHproductions.*

```
¬x@AÇ|Y©+UhYZsÃâ kUn)èj
```

Takes a string as input.

[Try it online!](https://codepen.io/justinm53/full/NvKjZr?code=rHhAQcd8WakrVWhZWnPD4iBrVW4p6Go=&inputs=IjEi,IjIi,IjMi,IjQi,IjUi,IjYi,Ijci,Ijgi,Ijki,IjEwIg==,IjExIg==,IjEyIg==,IjEzIg==,IjE0Ig==,IjE1Ig==,IjEwMCI=,IjE1MCI=,IjIwMCI=)

Comment: Perhaps another couple with `¬x@AÇ|Y©+UhYZsÃâ kUn)èj`?

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 83 bytes

```
{+grep &is-prime,m:ex/^(.*)(.)(.*)$/.map:{|map
.[0]~*~.[2],grep *-.[1],?.[0]..9}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYtLCoMwGAav8iNBNI2fj0WhFtuDhFRcJEUwNMRNJY1XT2s3M4thnPbLOdmNckNDCqen147yea2cn60Wttfv@lGAlwXKQ6yGnVwfPj8SZKN2vkN2SvxHXkG2StyPAFxiTOu0UcZGGm4UDLExZmRenlqga67pCw)

Comment: How about using `X~` instead of `map`? [81 bytes](https://tio.run/##HcvfCoIwGIfhW/mQIZvpzz8HQYZ1G8JY4sEWQqMxT5I1b31hRy888DrtX@dkN8oNDSmcnl47ype1cn6xurS9/tQPjkJwiCOshp1dH74cslHjzv9DUUG2qrwfBlzEuEN2SsSY1nmjjE003CgYYlPMyLw9tUDXXNMP)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 100+1 bytes

```php
for(;~($a=$argn)[$i];$i++)for($d=-!!$i;$d++<9;$c+=$k==1)for($a[$i]=$d,$k=$a;--$k&&$a%$k;);echo$c-$i;
```

Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/13a9bfa8ff90bc831f210f4ad3c3aac66e4d5f17).

**breakdown**

```php
for(;~($n=$argn)[$i];$i++)  # loop through argument digits, restore $n in every iteration
    for($d=-!!$i;               # loop $d from 0 (1 for first digit)
        $d++<9;                 # ... to 9
        $c+=$k==1                   # 3. if divisor is 1, increment counter
    )
        for($n[$i]=$d,              # 1. replace digit
            $k=$n;--$k&&$n%$k;      # 2. find largest divisor of $n smaller than $n
        );
echo$c-$i;                  # print counter - length
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, <s>201</s> 194 bytes

```java
n->{String s=n+"";int r=0,i=0,j,k,t,u,l=s.length();for(;i<l;i++)for(j=0;++j<10;r+=n==u|t<2?0:1)for(u=t=new Integer(s.substring(0,i)+j+(i<l?s.substring(i+1):"")),k=2;k<t;t=t%k++<1?0:t);return r;}
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##bVGxbsMgEN37FSekSiCIZXsMppk7NEvGqoPj0BTbwREcqao03@6e7QyVWokD3T3uHe/R1pd6NZytbw/d2PR1jPBSO399AHAebXivGwvbKZ0L0PBp90JT5UZBK2KNroEteDAw@tXTdYfB@SNE4yVjemoIJleOolWdQpVUb2LWW3/EDy70@xC4dlWvnZRiSlqTaynbqsh1kMYbk76xKjf5upjhZNB4@wnP9MCjDTxmMe3jPJPTGCFbyYlu87vuZCHWjAmhOlPqrkKNBh87KauCeFHoYDEFD0HfRr3oOqd9T7ru8i6DO8CJrOGLutc3qMXiy/SmSaQzhQZXmTKng6QsKMDuK6I9ZUPC7EytyH1GNgqQwBSw2crFzL9Xe8/v@D8IK/N8DYx4JkJKxP1bbuMP)

```java
n->{                        // Method with integer as parameter and return-type
  String s=n+"";            //  String representation of the input-int
  int r=0,                  //  Result-integer
      i=0,j,k,              //  Index-integers
      t,u,                  //  Temp integers
      l=s.length();         //  Length of the String
  for(;i<l;i++)             //  Loop (1) from 0 to `l` (exclusive)
    for(j=0;++j<10;         //   Inner loop (2) from 1 to 10 (exclusive)
        r+=                 //     And after every iteration, raise the result by:
           n==u             //      If the current number equals the input
           |t<2?            //      or it is not a prime:
            0               //       Add nothing to the result-counter
           :                //      Else:
            1)              //       Raise the result-counter by one
      for(                  //    Inner loop (3)
          u=t=              //     First set both `u` and `t` to:
              new Integer(  //      Convert the following String to an integer: 
               s.substring(0,i)
                            //       Get the substring from 0 to `i` (exclusive)
               +j           //       + `j`
               +(i<l?       //       + If `i` is smaller than the String-length:
                  s.substring(i+1)
                            //          The substring from 0 to `i` (inclusive)
                 :          //         Else:
                  "")),     //          Nothing
          k=2;              //     And start `k` at 2
              k<t;          //     Continue looping as long as `k` is smaller than `t`
        t=t%k++<1?          //     If `t` is divisible by `k`:
           0                //      Change `t` to 0
          :                 //     Else:
           t                //      Leave `t` as is
      );                    //    End of inner loop (3)
                            //    (`t` remained the same after loop 3? -> It's a prime)
                            //   End of inner loop (2) (implicit / single-line body)
                            //  And of loop (1) (implicit / single-line body)
  return r;                 //  Return the result-counter
}                           // End of method
```

`new Integer(s.substring(0,i)+j+(i<l?s.substring(i+1):"")` will result in these integers:

For `0-9`: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9`.
For `10`: `10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19`.
For `11`: `11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19`.
etc.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES7), 118 bytes

Takes input as a string.

```javascript
n=>[...2**29+'4'].map(d=>n.replace(/./g,c=>s+=d+i>0&(P=k=>N%--k?P(k):N-n&&k==1)(N=p+d+n.slice(++i),p+=c),i=p=0),s=0)|s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYvBjoIwFEX3fkUXCn0@qGCchTqv8wfE/WQSmwKmA742dOIG@Xamm3PP4p5f8zLRTi78lezbbu1pZdLfSqnjfn88Y37Kf9TTBNmSZjV1YTS2kwd1eBSWdERq0ekqkzcaSDe7shy@bnKAS1Nylg1ENciGArbIKo4upYgOioBkoXAUqIIiJrzj2vtJsiBRXwWLz7TVRzJEEPNGCOs5@rFTo3/Iu5HbmRdI5@3cpwhFnsNyh@tmWf8B)

#### Commented

```javascript
n =>                        // n = input number (as a string)
  [...2**29 + '4']          // generate "5368709124" (all decimal digits)
  .map(d =>                 // for each digit d in the above string:
    n.replace(/./g, c =>    //   for each digit c in n:
      s +=                  //     increment s if the following code yields 1:
        d + i > 0 & (       //       if this is not the first digit of n or d is not "0":
          P = k =>          //         P = recursive function taking k and using N:
            N % --k ?       //           decrement k; if k is not a divisor of N:
              P(k)          //             do recursive calls until it is
            :               //           else:
              N - n &&      //             return true if N is not equal to n
              k == 1        //             and k is equal to 1 (i.e. N is prime)
          )(                //         initial call to P ...
            N =             //           ... with N defined as:
              p +           //             the current prefix p
              d +           //             followed by d
              n.slice(++i), //             followed by the trailing digits
                            //             (and increment the pointer i)
            p += c          //           append c to p
          ),                //         end of initial call
          i = p = 0         //         start with i = p = 0
    ),                      //   end of replace()
    s = 0                   //   start with s = 0
  ) | s                     // end of map(); return s
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) with `-rprime`, 101 bytes

`-rprime` imports the Prime module into Ruby. Get all primes up to \$10^{floor(log_{10} n)+1}\$ and count how many have the same number of digits from \$n\$ and are also 1 digit off.

```ruby
->n{d=n.digits;Prime.each(10**l=d.size).count{|x|d.zip(e=x.digits).count{|a,b|a==b}==l-1&&e.size==l}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY1LCsIwFAD3PYULKbWY0NalPM/gXqWkTaoPahLygdomVzd@EJfDMIzx3SMNcE7kIBcOknK8orP7o8G7oIL1t6KuynIETi3OYkN75aVbwhQ4nVEXAqZf8lds2wUG0EWAkdR5Lr7lG2JM2ju7Gk7rljrV4iU1Wb3LmuqptEMlbSIyEaM/7xc)