# Encode Factor Trees

Tags: code-golf, primes, balanced-string, factoring

I once saw on the xkcd fora a format for expressing numbers in an odd way. In this "factor tree" format:

- The empty string is 1.
- Concatenation represents multiplication.
- A number *n* enclosed in parentheses (or any paired characters) represents the *n*th prime number, with 2 being the first prime number.

  - Note that this is done recursively: the *n*th prime is the factor tree for *n* in parentheses.
- The factors of a number should be ordered from smallest to largest.

For example, here are the factor trees for 2 through 10:

```
()
(())
()()
((()))
()(())
(()())
()()()
(())(())
()((()))
```

Your task is to take in a positive integer, and output the factor tree for it.

## Test Cases

In addition to the 9 above…

```
100 => ()()((()))((()))
101 => (()(()(())))
1001 => (()())(((())))(()(()))
5381 => (((((((())))))))
32767 => (()())((((()))))(()()(())(()))
32768 => ()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()
```

## Rules

- Characters other than `()[]{}<>` are allowed in the output, but ignored.
- You should be able to handle any input from 2 to 2<sup>15</sup> inclusive.
- The winner is the shortest answer in bytes.

Comment: Similar to Brain-Flak: `()` nilad is 2 instead of 1, `(...)` monad is next prime instead of push, concatenation is multiply instead of add.

Comment: @user202729 you could probably get some irony points by writing a Brain-Flak answer—good luck though.

Comment: Definitely worth considering.

Comment: I would argue that this is a duplicate of [Encode an integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/139034/71256). [Here](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//3zbw52N9t5KGppKJ9YneIHoR40bHu6cbmtU8P//f2MjczNzAA) is my solution to that, with the front part removed and `[1,0]` replaced by `"()"`. Also the Jelly solution there is remarkably similar to the one here

Comment: Why didn't that come up in the sandbox?

Comment: @StephenLeppik Personally, I saw it in the sandbox, but only noticed it was a duplicate after seeing solutions. Sorry :/

Comment: @H.PWiz it's okay, at least I got 60 rep and a bunch of flags out of it. Not to mention rolling out my new tag without it having to go through Suggested Edits.

Comment: @H.PWiz is there an existing challenge for *decoding* these?

Comment: I've been trying to find a method for determining if an integer is valid and decode-able. That might make a good challenge in and of itself. Not only do the `0`s have to be balanced against the `1`s so that the parentheses are balanced, but the primes they result in have to be sorted correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>15</s> 7 bytes

```
ṁös;₁ṗp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f9qhpjVJ0rNKjpsb/D3c2Ht5WbA1kPtw5veD////GRuZm5gA)

-8 bytes thanks to @Zgarb!

#### Explanation

Note that the header `f€"[]"₁` just filters out all `[` & `]` characters, it's just so that the output is more readable, if you want to see the original output, [here](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOxsPbiq0fNTU83Dm94P///8ZG5mbmAA) you go.

```
ṁ(s;₁ṗ)p  -- define function ₁; example input: 6
       p  -- prime factorization: [2,3]
ṁ(    )   -- map and flatten the following (example with 3): "[""]["[\"\"]"]"
     ṗ    --   get prime index: 2
    ₁     --   recurse: "[\"\"]"
   ;      --   create singleton: ["[\"\"]"]
  s       --   show: "[\"[\\\"\\\"]\"]"
```

Comment: The ternary if is unnecessary: since `p1` is the empty list, the result is the empty string. Also, `"()"` can be `sø` if you switch to square brackets.

Comment: Hmm, actually since characters other than `()[]{}<>` are ignored in the output by the rules, `\`J"()"` could be `s;` instead. It produces a ton of quotes and backspaces but the rules explicitly allow it.

Answer (score 5):

### [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>84</s> <s>81</s> <s>80</s> 64 bytes

*Byte count assumes Windows ANSI encoding.*

*Thanks to Misha Lavrov for saving 16 bytes.*

```
±1=""
±x_:=Table[{"(",±PrimePi@#,")"},#2]&@@@FactorInteger@x<>""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcrPCoJAGATwe08xfIIUfFCr@afI2FPQzUO3iNhkKSENZA@C@FD7Cvtim9lhfjOHaZR56UaZulLeOysKooWz/X1fXNTjra8DLYmdLbu60WUtA6YVjRxEt1BKeVKV@XTn1uin7mR/OBL56dkaSDgbIMRaYhCMiBEztoyEkTIyRs7YMcTmlxkxr8kkzifjKEuzf@Wj/wI)

#### Explanation

Quite a literal implementation of the spec. We're defining a unary operator `±` via two separate definitions.

```
±1=""
```

This is just the base case, the empty string for `1`.

```
±x_:=Table[±#,#2]&@@@FactorInteger@x<>""
```

For all other `x`, we factor the integer (this gives a list of prime-exponent pairs, `{p, k}`), generate a table of `k` copies of the representation of `p`. 
For each `p`, we figure out the prime's index via `PrimePi` (i.e. the number of primes less than or equal to it), recursively pass it to `±` and wrap the result in parentheses. Then flatten and join the result into a single string.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
ÆfÆC$ÐLŒṘ€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW9rhNmeVwxN8jk56uHPGo6Y1/w@3A8nI//@NdBSMdRRMdBRMdRTMdBTMdRQsdBQsdRQMDUAYTBiCWUDS1NgCSBobmZuZQygLAA)

-7 bytes thanks to user202729

## Explanation

```
ÆfÆC$ÐLŒṘ€  Main Link
     ÐL     While the results have not yet repeated
ÆfÆC$       Prime factorize the number (vectorizes) and turn each prime to its prime index
       ŒṘ€  Since none of the lists actually contain anything, turn it to a Python string or else it won't print. Call on each because otherwise there will be an extra set of brackets around the output.
```

Comment: Since this is the way Jelly outputs, you can say your submission is a monadic link (like a function in other languages), and make it [7 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW9rhNmeVwxN8/h9uPzrp4c4Zj5rWqKgAicj//410FIx1FEx0FEx1FMx0FMx1FCx0FCx1FAwNQBhMGIJZQNLU2AJIGhuZm5lDKAsA).

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder "The output is a string".

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>113</s> 110 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,d=2,p=1:n>2and(n%d and f(n,d+1,p+all(-~d%i for i in range(2,d)))or'(%s)'%f(p)+f(n/d,d,p))or'()'*~-n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYvBTsMwGIPvewpfqib0HywpW8uk8iKIQyANRGr/REk47LJXL2GTsOTPlizHS/kOrDe/xpAK8iXvqh/zXNL8@ZOyD7z41RehDlVyc9Ni1g9rwGQnTXFSZ37Vhq3gxqImnKhTpyh2ZlnE/mobDxcSPDwjGf6ahSYrpQypFU2WbeNElF29PVmyFO@DbB@ue97@j2@a0BOeCUfCiTAQRsILQR3@fIO6tcpjP1b2ejgN9xjfzzsgJs8FnpzwcvsF)

---

**ungolfed**

```python
def f(num, div=2, prime=1):
    if num > 2:
        if num % div:
            # if div does not divide num
            # try next divisor, add 1 to prime if the next divisor is prime
            return f(num, div + 1, prime + all((div + 1) % i for i in range(2, div)))
        else:
            # if div divides num add div as a factor, continue with num / div
            return '(%s)' % f(prime) + f(num / div, div, prime)
    else:
        # if num <= 1: return ''
        # if num == 2: return '()'
        return '()' * (num - 1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVHbTsMwDH3fVxxpmpZAgLVjFybKjyAeqjVlltpkSlJgX19yGd3GwFKcxD52znH2B7fTKu@p3WvjYA925Ne9lc7IbWcsadVQS45lM2@8r2SNmqmuFajoo8gF9oZaWWR8M4I3quGTeEGe7mexSag4RYONQ85HUWlpobQLF6pkwP8COnOAkl8JYbURKKsKGZxODEInt5MXGJBNyYteRrrOqDMVuEV21OGPZdMwdoxyT5pQh04gBVOqd8nyWMQ5H7rKxsr/hEU9Ng4gEA6x0qJEXW5dULHVypHqJD7J7SLsIYD@YjxlE8unnlLNIlnuKUYVqUQkl1Kja17jn494LpBthqbTa0BR@O87vcpPkLMYbhDfvvNj6ocRvfrpzAUeBRYCS4GVwFrgSSCbhRVdFk/eL@Zr7@f5arlK2/ot0PUKlAOJmhHvvwE)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 93 bytes

Uses the same approach as [ovs' Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/150149/58563).

```js
f=(n,d=2,k=1)=>n>2?n%d?f(n,++d,k+(P=n=>n%--d?P(n):d<2)(d)):`(${f(k)})`+f(n/d,d,k):n-2?'':'()'
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=(n,d=2,k=1)=>n>2?n%d?f(n,++d,k+(P=n=>n%--d?P(n):d<2)(d)):`(${f(k)})`+f(n/d,d,k):n-2?'':'()'

;[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,100,101,1001,5381,32767,32768].forEach(
  n => console.log(n, '->', f(n))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) + [numbers](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/numbers/numbers.pdf), 113 bytes

```r
f=function(n)"if"(n<2,"",paste0("(",sapply(match(primeFactors(n),Primes(n)),f),")",collapse=""))
library(numbers)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY7NCoMwDIDvPoXklEAP/rDpYb3uvFeoxbJCraXVg0/vrHabDJZASfp9CfHrqriarZz0aNESaAVobxUDYE6EqS8QEFgQzpkFBzHJJzqvh/4u5DT6sI2wR@xjRUwRAwImR2OECz0HIMqM7rzwC9p56HofaFVYFgXlnOeAtCUiUXohi7BMMDLa/xM4k31kZ28pOpe6/ThHUIpI66q5Nr8rDgOPU@i7Ksrt6cy/CesL)

Recursive function. Returns a string.

```
function(n)
if(n < 2)                                                # 1 is empty string
 ""                                                      #
else                                                     #
 paste0("(",                                             # wrap in parens
            sapply(                                      # for each
                   match(primeFactors(n),Primes(n))),    # prime index of factors of n
                                                     f), # apply f
           ")",                                          #
               collapse="")                              # collapse into a single string
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Swift](https://swift.org), 155 bytes

```swift
func f(_ n:Int)->String{var d=0;return n<2 ?"":(d=(2...n).first{n%$0<1}!,n==d).1 ?"(\(f((2...n).filter{m in(2...m).first{m%$0<1}==m}.count)))":f(d)+f(n/d)}
```

### Explanation (Ungolfed)

```swift
func f(_ n:Int) -> String {                        // Declare recursive function f(n)
    var d = 0;                                     // Temporary variable d
    return n < 2 ?                                 // If n < 2:
        ""                                         //    Return empty string
    : (d = (2...n).first{n % $0 < 1}!, n == d).1 ? // If the lowest number divisible by n
                                                   // is equal to n (n is prime):
        "(\(f((2...n).filter{m in (2...m).first{   //    Return prime index of n (length of
        m % $0 < 1} == m}.count)))"                //    list of all primes ≤ n)
    :                                              // Else:
        f(d) + f(n / d)                            //    Return f(d) + f(n / d) where d is
}                                                  //    the smallest number divisible by n
```