# Keep Decoding This Number!

Tags: code-golf, primes, balanced-string

[This challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/139034/47581) posed an algorithm for encoding an integer `n` as another integer `r`. What follows is a succinct explanation of that algorithm, using `n=60` as an example.

**The original algorithm**

- First, we encode the number as a string of brackets.

  - If `n = 1`, return an empty string.
  - Otherwise, we take `n`'s prime decomposition sorted ascending and replace each element with its prime index (1-indexed) in brackets. `60 = 2*2*3*5 => [1][1][2][3]`
  - Do this recursively until all we have are brackets. `[1][1][2][3] => [][][[1]][[2]] => [][][[]][[[1]]] => [][][[]][[[]]]`
- Once we have our string of brackets, we convert that into an integer with the following process.

  - Convert each opening bracket to a `1` and each closing bracket to a `0`. `[][][[]][[[]]] => 10101100111000`
  - Remove all trailing `0`s and the final `1`. `10101100111000 => 1010110011`
  - Convert the final string of `0`s and `1`s from binary to an integer. `1010110011 => 691`

**Decoding this encoding**

An interesting property of this algorithm is that it is *not* surjective. Not every integer can be the result of this encoding.

- Firstly, the binary representation of the result `r`, must be `balance-able` in that the number of `0`s must never exceed the number of `1`s. A short falsey test case is `4`, which is `100` in binary.
- Secondly, the brackets in the binary representation must be `sorted ascending` when the final `1` and trailing `0`s are appended once more. A short falsey test case is `12 <= 1100 <= 110010 <= (())()`.

However, just determining if a number is decode-able in this way would make for a short challenge. Instead, the challenge is to **repeatedly decode** a given input until either an un-decode-able number or a cycle is reached, and returning the resulting **sequence** of numbers.

**The challenge**

- Given a number `1 <= r <= 2**20 = 1048576`, return the **sequence of numbers** that `r` **successively decodes** into, starting with `r` itself and ending with an un-decode-able number or a cycle.
- If an **un-decode-able number** is given as input, such as `4` or `12`, will return a list containing only the input.
- A sequence ending in a **cycle** should be indicated in some way, either by **appending or prepending a marker** (pick any non-positive integer, string, list, etc. as a marker, but keep it consistent), or by **repeating the cycle** in some way (repeating the first element, repeating the whole cycle, repeating infinitely, etc.).
- On the off chance that any of the sequences are infinite (by increasing forever, for example), consider it undefined behavior.
- This is code golf. Smallest number of bytes wins.

**A worked example of decoding**

```
   1 -> 1 -> 1100 -> [[]] -> [2] -> 3
-> 3 -> 11 -> 111000 -> [[[]]] -> [[2]] -> [3] -> 5
-> 5 -> 101 -> 101100 -> [][[]] -> 2*[2] -> 2*3 -> 6
-> 6 -> 110 -> 110100 -> [[][]] -> [2*2] -> [4] -> 7
-> 7 -> 111 -> 11110000 -> [[[[]]]] -> [[[2]]] -> [[3]] -> [5] -> 11
-> 11 -> 1011 -> 10111000 -> [][[[]]] -> 2*[[2]] -> 2*[3] -> 2*5 -> 10
-> 10 -> 1010 -> 101010 -> [][][] -> 2*2*2 -> 8
-> 8 -> 1000  ERROR: Unbalanced string
```

**Test cases**

```
4 -> [4]
12 -> [12]
1 -> [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 11, 10, 8]
2 -> [2, 4]
13 -> [13, 13]    # cycle is repeated once
23 -> [23, 22, 14, 17]
51 -> [51, 15, 31, 127, 5381]
691 -> [691, 60]
126 -> [126, 1787, 90907]
1019 -> [1019, 506683, 359087867, 560390368728]
```

Suggestions and feedback for this challenge are most welcome. Good luck and good golfing!

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14361).

Comment: How does `1` give `3`?

Comment: @LeakyNun `1` --(append an `1` and trailing zeros)--> `1100` --> `[[]]` --> `[[1]]` --> `[2]` --> `3`

Comment: `6`->`110`->`110100` which isn't valid, right? So should input `1` give `[1,3,5,6]`?

Comment: And for 7: `7`->`111`->`11110000`->`[[[[]]]]`->4th prime = 7? Maybe I don't understand the algorithm

Comment: @dylnan `6` -> `110` -> `110100` -> `[[][]]` -> `[2*2]` -> `[4]` -> `7` -> `111` -> `11110000` -> `[[[[]]]]` -> `[[[2]]]` -> `[[3]]` -> `[5]` -> `11`. I hope this helps you understand the algorithm better.

Comment: Yes it does, thank you

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>379</s> <s>358</s> <s>339</s> <s>337</s> <s>327</s> <s>310</s> 304 bytes

**Conjecture: Is `13` the only number that will lead to a cycle?** (There are no exceptions smaller than 10<sup>6</sup>.)

*Fixed a bug and -7 bytes thanks to [Sherlock9](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47581/sherlock9).
-3 byte thanks to [Jonathan Frech](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73111/jonathan-frech).
-16 bytes thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs).
-6 bytes thanks to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder).*

If there is a cycle, it will repeat the whole cycle.

```python
def p(a,x=0,n=1):
 while a:x+=1;a-=n%x;n*=x*x
 return x
def g(a):
 c=i=0
 for v in a:
  c+=int(v)*2-1
  if c<0:return 0,0
  if c<1:break
  i+=1
 if a:x=p(g(a[1:i])[0]);b,c=g(a[i+1:]);return(x>c>0)*(0,0)or(x*b,x)
 return 1,0
def f(a):
 x=a,
 while(x.count(a)<3)*a:a,t=g(bin(a-~a)[2:]);x+=a,
 return x[:-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVDLbsMgELzzFVyqAF5XYLeVikN@xPJhTewEtcIWJSm99NddUJIe9jCrncfO@hPPi2@37TjNdGUIyUjwRnFN6PfZfU4UdaqM6rA2/il1XpgkEqFhipfgaSKFd2JY7q1xRhI6L4FeqfOZSSi1lXE@sisXTa0ydjO1e6nvfAnysVN6DBN@FJj9SFlma7OyrN4r7Qbey4F3I1hTNq5SOsObDksHe5BcsKzHl8CSGCHx/5Qqu5Sc8y1nMgj371h6tssl50O@b7lAjRCz/Og8w/oXed8Uk1xAYTx@7nWthi1OX/GIEU3/AqoBBXlaaFp4VfD2rgZSenClh8elXkOpwsFO72BmjvPtDw)

**Explanation:**

```python
def p(a,x=0,n=1):     # return the a-th prime
 while a:             # magical way to enumerate primes
  x+=1
  a-=n%x
  n*=x*x
 return x

def g(a):             # decode a 0/1 string
 c=i=0
 for v in a:
  c+=int(v)*2-1       # +1 if 1, -1 if 0
  if c<0: return(0,0) # c<0: unbalanced parentheses
  if c<1: break       # first outermost parentheses
  i+=1
 if a:
   x=p(g(a[1:i])[0])  # recursive solve those inside the parentheses ...
   b,c=g(a[i+1:])     # and the remaining
   if x>c and c:      # if not ascending
    return (0,0)
   return (x*b,x)     # return (result, value of first closed parentheses)
 return (1,0)         # empty string

def f(a):
 x=a,
 while a and x.count(a)<3: # detect non-decodable or cycle
  a,t=g(bin(a-~a)[2:])     # a-~a is a*2+1
  x+=a,
 return x[:-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 62 bytes

```
L?b**FKme.fP_Zyd)bSIK1fTseB.u.xyvs@L,"],"\[++JjN2 1m0h-/J1/J00
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L%3Fb%2a%2aFKme.fP_Zyd%29bSIK1fTseB.u.xyvs%40L%2C%22%5D%2C%22%5C%5B%2B%2BJjN2+1m0h-%2FJ1%2FJ00&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=4%0A12%0A1%0A2%0A13%0A23%0A51%0A691%0A126&debug=0)

Indicates a cycle by repeating the final number.

```
L?b**FKme.fP_Zyd)bSIK1    Define y to decode from list format. 0 if invalid.

fTseB.u.xyvs@L,"],"\[++JjN2 1m0h-/J1/J00
     .u                                     Repeat the following until it cycles
                                            Collecting the values in a list.
                     ++JjN2 1m0h-/J1/J0     Convert the number to expanded binary
            @L,"],"\[                       Map 0 to "],", 1 to "["
           s                                Flatten to a string.
          v                                 Evaluate as a Python object.
       .x                              0    If evaluation fails, return 0.
         y                                  Otherwise decode.
  seB                                       Duplicate the final number
fT                                          Remove all 0s.
```