# Number to Binary

Tags: code-golf, binary

It seems we've managed to go all this time without a plain vanilla Number-To-Binary challenge! Whilst this will inevitably be only one element in many languages, it should put a few esolangs through their paces.

<sub>I truly looked for this challenge to no avail. If it already exists, comment as such and I'll delete this post-haste.</sub>

## Input

A single non-negative integer.

## Output

The same number as represented in Base 2.

## Test Cases

- `4 -> 100`
- `10 -> 1010`
- `1234 -> 10011010010`

## Victory Condition

[code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so fewest bytes wins!

## Notes

- The output must consist of digits `0` and `1`, either as characters or individual numbers in a list.
- Zero may optionally return nothing.
- [Standard IO Applies](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)
- [Standard Loopholes Apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)
- Have Fun!

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/200863/convert-a-decimal-integer-to-binary-only-using-arithmetic-operators), [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/20995/convert-from-base-10-to-base-2-without-built-in-base-conversions).

Comment: @chunes Both are source restricted, which makes them different challenges

Comment: Still it’s often helpful for golfers to know of [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102219/binary-to-decimal-converter) challenges.

Comment: can we print the number instead of returning it?

Comment: @badatgolf Perfectly valid, falls under Standard IO

Comment: May we output with additional leading zero(s)?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Leading zeroes are fine, Trailing zeroes go without saying are not.

Comment: Can we output the binary as little-endian?

Comment: I wonder if it can be done in TeX?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 1\log_{256}(96)\approx \$ 0.82 bytes

```
b
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhYLkyA0lLtgkaEBhAUA)

Comment: I got confused by the `log256(96)`, but now realize that that's an approximation of how many bytes each `command` takes in the Thunnu language, and this has `1` command. I get it now, it makes sense.

Answer (score 15):

## [Piet](https://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html) + [ascii-piet](https://github.com/dloscutoff/ascii-piet), 29 bytes (6×9=54 codels)

```
tkvuumf_iliqqdltT QqKln?_sf ?
```

[Try Piet online!](https://piet.bubbler.one/#eJxtjcEOgzAIht-F898EbHW2r1I9LK5LTFxn0u1k9u5D504KBPj5CCw0PG-JQowMD0GtLgKxkBbie0RhNNDk1KXSnsHr2K_aH0OZw8n8hxpctsvtEdntqz9hPaikmQIZYwg0jQ_thdVUpTJQuF-nkkBjnt-vlVXWdVm3u8x7_WvZq6_p8wWwszr1)

[image]

B2C2 is `I` (no-op). The printing loop is now:

```
O d 1 % D I
```

which nicely forms a color loop.

---

## [Piet](https://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html) + [ascii-piet](https://github.com/dloscutoff/ascii-piet), 33 bytes (5×9=45 codels)

```
tkvuumf_iliqqdltT _?tser?_iqtf? ?
```

[Try Piet online!](https://piet.bubbler.one/#eJxlTEEOwjAM-0vOrpR0G7T9SrcDGkWaNMqkwmni76Qw2IEkSuzY8krj7ZwoxMjwEHTaIpAG4iB-QBTGAbpabbGKGVzf_uP4nyo6dWnEEfbtcrtSg_iXv0sDqKSFAhljCDRPV8XCWspSGSlcTnNJoCkvj3vVbNP2Wd195u1-uWzXd_R8AR7-NQs)

[image]

The bit-extracting logic is the same as [Parcly Taxel's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/258456/78410). The printing logic is new.

Loop 1: push bits of the input (`A1 -> A8 -> B8 -> B1 -> A1`)

```
D           No-op
I           Take input (n); no-op afterwards
d 2 %       [...bits n n%2]
2 1 r 2 /   [...bits n%2 n/2]
d ! D       Turn right if the new n is 0
```

Now there is a leading zero, which is handled nicely by `A2->B2` (`>`). Since the number below is 0 or 1, and `0>0 == 0` and `1>0 == 1`, the net effect is to simply remove the extra zero.

Loop 2: print bits until the stack is empty (`D2 -> E2 -> E1 -> D2 -> D5 -> E4 -> E1`)

```
d 1 > !    If the top exists, push 1; otherwise push 0
D          Turn right if it is 1; halt otherwise (white trap)
O          Output as number
```

Answer (score 11):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 13 bytes

```python
"{:b}".format
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhZrlaqtkmqV9NLyi3ITSyBiNxULijLzSjS0NNI0KjQVgFIKFQqZeQpFiXnpqRqGBpqamhCFCxZAaAA)

Answer (score 11):

## [Piet](https://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html) + [ascii-piet](https://github.com/dloscutoff/ascii-piet), <s>50</s> <s>44</s> 42 bytes (<s>2×25=50</s> <s>2×22=44</s> 2×21=42 codels)

```
tabru?qd?t?itknmdjem_  a?liqdltailckt?iq ?
```

[Try Piet online!](https://piet.bubbler.one/#eJw9jNEKgzAMRf8lz7fQdLWr_RXtw3AdCM4J3Z5k_75E6UJIbk5ustP0uhdKw2DBAezh0IEjPNhpt1rYSu9xBbNiAaeMGQP30AzqC-o8LgPOf1ZZJ7ftjz_cMWdQLRslMsYQaJmfotlKyFTqROlxW2oBzev2ecvOj6tYx5VtE-7S2B_R9wfDfzDK)

#### Pointer Path

[image]

Answer (score 10):

## [Piet](https://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html) + [ascii-piet](https://github.com/dloscutoff/ascii-piet), 73 bytes (7×12=84 codels)

```
um    R metabrujjL    ?  ll?dD    j  d ?T    l rr tN   ttbj nfI        nn
```

[Try Piet online!](https://piet.bubbler.one/#eJxtjsEOgjAQRP9lz9OkW0oL_RXCwWBNSFBJqifDv7sFFEXbSbqTeTvpg7rrMVJomhLM4HqT-XJct2jyK5CHBjuwFaZEJddt-VvVOricipE-s2NeCJt1Q__2uOUvM6Hhd4DOK3YpkqwA_6n4lJ8rMtOCUhwpkFKKQEN_lpm1HHExdRROhyFFUH8Z77ecmcLS9ATEoUJ-)

[image]

Comment: There is output as number instead of output as character, so you can save the bytes used to make the constant `48` to make the char codes.

Comment: Also, generally speaking, making your code thinner will be better in minimizing the amount of black codels, thereby reducing the byte count as well. I'm not entirely sure how that could be achieved with your code (especially since Piet code is hard to parse lol), but a lot of bytes could potentially be saved by changing the structure around a bit to minimize black codels.

Answer (score 9):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 132 bytes

```
{(({})<><(()())>)({}(<>))<>{(({})){({}[()])<>}{}}{}<>([{}()]{})<>({}<(()())>)({}(<>))<>([()]{()<(({})){({}[()])<>}{}>}{}<><{}{}>)}<>
```

Outputs the individual numbers in a list with newlines as separators, and does not output anything for 0.

Explanation:

```
{                                                                   #  loop while top of left stack is not 0
(({})<><(()())>)({}(<>))<>{(({})){({}[()])<>}{}}{}<>([{}()]{})<>    #  leave the result of modulo 2 on right stack
({}<(()())>)({}(<>))<>([()]{()<(({})){({}[()])<>}{}>}{}<><{}{}>)    #  integer division by 2 on left stack
}                                                                   #  end loop
<>                                                                  #  switch to right stack
                                                                    #  implicit output of active (right) stack
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYwxDoAwDAO/Yw@ssET5SNWhDEgIxMAa9e3FLWulKHLsnPe3nM9y3OVqLYCoNDeAIJ06YU5Zf8TQTmCWU6NqzJH0xDxApRMWnQjQZh0@Siy6pFRr2/oB)

I'm not the best at this language so I may have left a lot of room for further golfing, please let me know if you found a better way to do it.

Comment: Nice! This is what I was hoping to see

Comment: Since you asked, [here's the task in 40 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/259651/56656)

Answer (score 8):

## Pure [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) (no external utilities), 37

```bash
b()(((a=$1/2))&&b $a
echo -n $[$1%2])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYtBCoAgEADv@4o9WOghSvMWvSQ6rLlgEAoZ9HyzoLnNwDjKoRQnlZSSZqF7o1TbOhQEvIWEXUSxCN2YVZU77AfjyeTx4nxtlHlCnwAr9fjb5@8MPkUuFvQA2owWHg)

This is a recursive function `b()` that takes its argument and divides by 2.  If the result is non-zero, then `b()` is recursively called with the result.  After the recursive call, the remainder when  the argument is divided by 2 is the current binary digit.  This is a pretty standard base conversion by repeated division by 2, with remainders becoming digits in base 2.  Making it a recursive function has a couple of advantages here:

- Recursive function boilerplate is marginally shorter than while loop boilerplate for the same algorithm
- The repeated division yields digits (remainders) in reverse order to how they should be presented.  By outputting the digit at each level after the recursive call, we effectively use the call stack to store the yielded digits and replay them back in the correct order

Ungolfed and perhaps a bit more readable:

```bash
function b() {
    a=$(( $1 / 2 ))
    if (( $a != 0 )); then
        b $a
    fi
    echo -n $(( $1 % 2 ))
}
```

Comment: Gods above. Make it a one-liner: "b()(((a=$1/2))&&b $a; printf %d $[$1%2])" and paste at the bash prompt. Then the command "b 346363" yields the output "010100100011111011" ... I'd appreciate it if you'd edit the answer to explain how it works.

Comment: @Wastrel Explanation added.

Comment: Thank you, and thanks for the more readable version. Bash lacks the built-in ability to do this operation, unlike many of the other languages given as an answer, and I enjoy seeing the problem deconstructed and solved. (In 37 characters!) Oops,  "b 346363" yields the output "010100100011111011" is bad copy-paste, it should have been "1010100100011111011"

Comment: save ***1 byte*** using `printf` instead of `echo -n` 

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript, 16 bytes

```js
x=>x.toString(2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvu/wtauQq8kP7ikKDMvXcNI838BkFGikaZhoqnJBWMbGmhq/gcA)

Answer (score 6):

### [bc](https://man.archlinux.org/man/extra/bc/bc.1.en) - 14 bytes

```
obase=2;read()
```

Run bc by typing `bc` into a terminal and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Type this code in, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, type in the number to convert, and finally press <kbd>Enter</kbd> one more time. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to exit `bc`.

`read()` reads user input (in base 10 by default), and then `obase=2` sets it to output in binary. Given that we don't tell it to do any math operations (other than base-conversion), it just outputs the input, but in binary due to the `obase=2`.

Example:

```
$ bc
bc 1.07.1
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2004, 2006, 2008, 2012-2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type `warranty'.
obase=2;read()    <-- Press Enter
1234              <-- Press Enter again
10011010010       <-- Press Ctrl + C to exit
^C
(interrupt) Exiting bc.
```

I've tested this on Arch Linux, but any system with `bc` installed should work.

Comment: Just as a note: You can also store that code into a file and pass the file name to `bc` (or `bc -q` to omit all the copyright + warranty output). On my Ubuntu, Ctrl-C just gives me "(interrupt) use quit to exit.", Ctrl-D actually exits.

Comment: This also seems to work without the `read()`?

Answer (score 6):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 2 bytes

```
2\
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLszKK4eLS5zLhMjTgMjQyNuECcq1CrBI8VYzjNWpiLI1stazUNeMNrBISi9LLFAy5uNLUQ7gAO34MFQ==)

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 1 byte

```
b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/6f9/QwMA)

Answer (score 6):

## [C (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org), 21 bytes

```c
f(n){printf("%b",n);}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700OT49OXnBgqWlJWm6FlvTNPI0qwuKMvNK0jSUVJOUdPI0rWshcjddgaIKuYmZeRqaXNVcnGkaJprWCgWlJcUaSkqa1iABQwMMESNjVFVQw2AWAgA)

Will be pretty shocked if there is any way to do it shorter in C (unless I missed a weird print function).

Comment: Save 5 bytes if you compile with `-Dp="printf"` and replace `printf` with `p`. [This is probably cheating :) ]

Comment: @Joseph yes, but then I'll be golfing the language: `C -Dp="printf"`, not `C`

Answer (score 6):

## [Befunge-93 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 28 bytes

```
2&v
2/>:0`!#^_:2%\
 ._@#-2:<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1NNYtqAQz//83UivjMtK3szJIUFSOi7cyUo3hUtCLd1DWNbKy@f/f0MjYhAsA)

### Explanation:

`2&v` and `>` below: Push 2 (used as an "end of string" character of sorts), push user input (henceforth X), then go down and enter the main loop.

#### Main Loop

`` :0\`! ``: Check if X is greater than 0. Invert the answer. (Specifically: duplicate X, push 0, swap, greater than, invert)

`#^_`: If top of stack is 1 (i.e. X <= 0), go up to print loop, else continue right. (Bridge, (up), horizontal if)

`:2%`: Get X%2. (Duplicate X, push 2, modulo)

`\`: Store below X on stack. (Swap)

`2/`: Divide X by 2. Loop restarts with this as X. (push 2, integer divide)

#### Print Loop

`<`: Go left. (going right here would add a `!` but it would not increase bytes as we have a spare whitespace on the left)

`-2:`: Check if top of stack = 2 (end of string). (RTL; duplicate, push 2, subtract)

`_@#`: Terminate program if top of stack = 0 (i.e. next item is 2). (RTL; bridge, (terminate), horizontal if)

`.`: Print top of stack as integer.

Note: I originally had a `$` to pop the leading 0 above the `^` in the main loop, but as per comments, leading 0s are allowed. Changing the `^` to a `v` would be equivalent, unless I were to add back in the `$` at the cost of 6 vs 10 bytes.

Answer (score 6):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 26 bytes

```
:-read(X),format("~2r",X).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/30q3KDUxRSNCUyctvyg3sURDqc6oSEknQlPv/39DI2MTPQA)

With builtin.

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), <s>42</s> <s>36</s> 35 bytes

*-6 bytes thanks to [@Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)*

*-1 byte thanks to [@false](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/65772/false)*

```
N+X:-N<1,X=0;N//2+B,X is N/\1+10*B.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcg9DoMgAAbQqxAnKR8Cav9sS4IHYCaxDC5tTLQQMenm1Wnf@OIa5vDm6TvlbJnruL0ruIe8WSFq1sORKRErnoopeeir3PFljPOUtnIwXuvSMIdXWJdxK4s9Eq7JHvdPgcHAeUoxSCjUaNDiiBPOuOAK9c@6aT2t8g8)

Without builtin.

---

Man, I haven't golfed in Prolog in a while; I forgot how wonky it is to code in it lol. Please tell me if there are any more golfs!

Comment: For the second one you can do `N+X:-A is N//2,A+B,X is(N/\1)+10*B.`

Comment: Or even better, `N+X:-N<1,X=0;N//2+B,X is(N/\1)+10*B.` avoiding one of the `is`s and then combining the two things and using `<1` to automatically evaluate when checking for zero

Comment: @Steffan Da hell is `N/\1`??

Comment: `n&1` in most langauges, it's just bitwise and with 1 (taking the last bit)

Comment: -1 by removing the round brackets: `N+X:-N<1,X=0;N//2+B,X is N/\1+10*B.`

Comment: @false Thanks for the golf... I'm not that good at Prolog lol

Comment: And, Why the read(X) in your first  case `\X:-format("~2r",[X]).` is enough (and portable).

Comment: @false How does that work... I couldn't get it to work without the read(X)

Comment: How does your second solution work? It also needs to be called. So you call it like `\7.`

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 31 bytes

```hs
f 0=0
f n=n`mod`2+10*f(n`div`2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P03BwNaAK00hzzYvITc/JcFI29BAK00jLyElsyzBSPN/bmJmnoKtQko@V0FRZl6JgopCmoIJEtvQAJljZGzyHwA)

I'm unsure why `` f$n`div`2 `` doesn't work as opposed to `` f(n`div`2) ``... I hope someone can explain this to me and help golf this code.

Comment: `3+f$x+y` is equivalent to `(3+f) (x+y)` which is why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

## [Quipu](https://github.com/cgccuser/quipu), 78 bytes

```
2&1@0&2&0&3&
//**[][][][]
1&2&2&++1&/\
>>>>%%  --
\/1&1&  0&
    []  >>
    **
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m720sDSzoHTBgqWlJWm6Fjf9jNQMHQzUjNQM1IzVuPT1tbSiYyGQyxAoaqSmrW2oph_DZQcEqqoKCrq6XDH6hmqGagoKBmpcCkAQHaugYGcHZmppQUyFGr5giaGRsQmEDQA)

#### Explanation

Programs in Quipu consist of several "threads," vertical strips of code that are executed one at a time and also store values. Quipu is missing a lot of features that would have been useful for this challenge: lists, string concatenation, exponentiation... Lacking better methods, we generate the output as a base-10 number whose digits are either 0 or 1.

The first time thread 0 is executed, it loads the input number; subsequently, it divides its value by 2:

```python
    # Previous value of this thread (implicit; initially 0)
2&  # Push 2
//  # Divide
1&  # Push 1
>>  # Go to that thread if the above result is greater than 0
\/  # Otherwise, read input number
```

Thread 1 generates successive powers of 10, starting at 1:

```python
    # Previous value of this thread
1@  # Push 10
**  # Multiply
2&  # Push 2
>>  # Go to that thread if the above result is greater than 0
1&  # Otherwise, push 1
```

Thread 2 takes the current value mod 2 and multiplies by the appropriate power of 10:

```python
0&  # Push 0
[]  # Load that thread's value
2&  # Push 2
%%  # Mod
1&  # Push 1
[]  # Load that thread's value
**  # Multiply
```

Thread 3 keeps a running sum of the values generated by thread 2. This will be our output number.

```python
    # Previous value of this thread
2&  # Push 2
[]  # Load that thread's value
++  # Add
```

Thread 4 tests if the value in thread 0 is still greater than 1; if so, jump back to thread 0:

```python
0&  # Push 0
[]  # Load that thread's value
1&  # Push 1
--  # Subtract
0&  # Push 0
>>  # Go to that thread if the above result is greater than 0
```

Once thread 0's value has reached 1 (or 0), execution continues with thread 5, which simply outputs the final result:

```python
3&  # Push 3
[]  # Load that thread's value
/\  # Print
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Minecraft Data Pack](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Data_pack) via [Lectern](https://github.com/mcbeet/lectern), 355 bytes

```
@function a:b
data modify storage  b set value []
scoreboard players set  i 2
function a:c
@function a:c
scoreboard players operation a i = i i
data modify storage  b prepend value 0
execute store result storage  b[0] int 1 run scoreboard players operation a i %=  i
scoreboard players operation i i /=  i
execute if score i i matches 1.. run function a:c
```

The function is `a:b`.

Takes input in the fake player `i` and the objective `i` (Which can be set using `/scoreboard objectives add i dummy`, `/scoreboard players set i i <input number>`).

Outputs a list via data storage `: b` (Which can be read by `/data get storage : b`).

I'm not sure this I/O format is valid, but this would be the standard way to do that if you were writing a library, although with the objective created by the data pack (and, of course, with more meaningful names).

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 17 bytes

```python
lambda n:f"{n:b}"
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhYbcxJzk1ISFfKs0pSq86ySapUg4msKijLzSjTSNEyMNDUhQgsWQGgA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 1 byte

```
b
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJiIiwiIiwiMTAiXQ==)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>62</s> 54 bytes

```python
i,o=input(),""
while i:i,j=divmod(i,2);o=`j`+o
print o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxLCoAgEADQ/ZxC2qjloqxV4V0EFZooR8J@p7c6wHvpyTNFXRz5YDjnBRUZjOnIQqqqgmvGNTAcUS3G47mRF6i0nMjYxTYEaceYGZWPQriDE38k674M0LXQ6X54AQ)

Just as a way of doing it without any builtins.

Comment: [49 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfnJ@Saquurv4/UyffNjOvoLREQ1NHSYmrPCMzJ1Uh0ypT39bIOt82IVPVKEE7n6ugKDOvRCE/2tAq9j9QF1dqRWqyBsgMTS3j/yZchgZchkbGJgA)

Comment: @97.100.97.109 I thought about that but then for some bizarre reason that I cant explain I went for `divmod` (probably because I have never found a use for it before :)).  Feel free to post it as your own answer if you wish.

Comment: To the downvoter. Care to explain why this deserves a downvote? It provides the requested output, it is the shortest answer specifically for Python 2 and it isn't a copy of or based on any other answer. I'm keen to know what is wrong with it.

Comment: It may have been auto-downvoted by the Community bot, it tends to do that to really short posts unfortunately

Answer (score 3):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 70 bytes

```
[S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][T   N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_integer][T   T   T   _Retrieve_input_n][N
S S N
_Create_Label_BINARY_LOOP][S N
S _Duplicate_n][N
T   S S N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_PRINT_LOOP][S N
S _Duplicate_n][S S S T S N
_Push_2][T  S T T   _Modulo][S N
T   _Swap_top_two][S S S T  S N
_Push_2][T  S T S _Integer_divide][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_BINARY_LOOP][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_PRINT_LOOP][T N
S T _Print_as_integer][N
S N
S N
_Jump_to_Label_PRINT_LOOP]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgQsIObk4QYALwuPihNBAwAnicIJJGAckxQWS5OIEaQRx//83NDI2AQA) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

Outputs with one additional leading `0`. This can be removed at the cost of 8 additional bytes:
[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgQsIObk4QYALwuPihNBAwAnicIJJGAckxcUF0QiigXpBBgDluP7/NzQyNgEA).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Integer n = STDIN as integer
Start BINARY_LOOP:
  If n==0:
    Jump to PRINT_LOOP
  Push n modulo-2 to the stack
  n = n integer-divided by 2
  Go to the next iteration of BINARY_LOOP

PRINT_LOOP:
  Print current top of the stack as integer to STDOUT
  Go to the next iteration of PRINT_LOOP
```

Stops the program with an error when it tries to print while the stack is empty.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 1 byte

```
B
```

Try it at [MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=B&inputs=4&version=22.7.4)

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 0.7](http://julialang.org/), 3 bytes

```julia
bin
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0/59m@z8pM@@/g55CQVFmXklOnkaaRrSJjqGBjqGRsUmspuZ/AA)

## [Julia 1.x](https://julialang.org), 9 bytes

```julia
bitstring
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700qzQnM3HBojTbpaUlaboWK5MyS4pLijLz0iH8XQ56CgVAbklOnkaaRrSJjqGBjqGRsUmspiZEwYIFEBoA)

Prints with leading zeroes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), <s>55</s> <s>49</s> 20 bytes

###### -6 bytes thanks to @RydwolfPrograms

###### -29 bytes thanks to @Jacob

```swift
{String($0,radix:2)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@V9QlJlXoqHxvzq4BMhK11Ax0ClKTMmssDLSrP2vqWFkrqn5HwA)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Does Swift let you remove some of the whitespace, like the space after the comma, or the newlines/indentation?

Comment: @RydwolfPrograms it does, thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: I've never used Swift before but here's [20 bytes](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@V9QlJlXoqHxvzq4BMhK11Ax0ClKTMmssDLSrP2vqWFkrqn5HwA "Swift – Try It Online") (just gathered from [the tips post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/79203/tips-for-golfing-in-swift) and recent golfed answers)

Comment: @Jacob thank you! Is it OK if I update my answer with your solution, or is that against the rules?

Comment: @MrDeveloper Take it, gave it to you

Answer (score 3):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 2 bytes

```
#:
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxSNkKwtiiyZWanJHvkKZmp2CiYGigYGhkbAKRWrAAQgMA)

`#:` returns the binary expansion of a given number y as a boolean list.

Answer (score 3):

## Scratch, <s>70</s> 68 bytes

Puts a list of binary digits onto the [`a` global variable, which is automatically displayed when the program finishes execution.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25520/108687)

Saved 2 bytes by using `([floor v]of((n)/(2` instead of `((n)-(((n)mod(2))/(2`

[image]

Scratchblocks syntax:

```
define a(n
if<(n)>(0)>then
a([floor v]of((n)/(2
add((n)mod(2))to[a v
```

[Try it on Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/810738346)

Answer (score 3):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 50 bytes

```
f(n)=mod(floor(n/2^{[floor(log_2(n+0^n))...0]}),2)
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/58jgg1jumw)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ilmjn4qc3o)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 62 bytes

```haskell
import Data.Sequence
d 0=Nothing
d n=Just$divMod n 2
unfoldl d
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8GCpaUlaboWNx0ycwvyi0oUXBJLEvWCUwtLU_OSU7lSFAxs_fJLMjLz0oHsPFuv0uISlZTMMt98IE_BiCvJtjQvLT8nJUchBWLO1tzEzDwFW4WCosy8EgUVhSQFQyNjE4gczC4A)

A different approach than [Aiden Chow's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/258528/16766); this one uses `unfoldl` from `Data.Sequence`, which is elegant but unfortunately much less golfy.

#### Explanation

`unfold` is conceptually the opposite of `fold`. `fold` takes a function that combines two values into one and a sequence of values, and returns a single value; `unfold` takes a function that splits one value into two and a single value, and returns a sequence of values. Specifically, the type of `unfoldl` looks like this:

```haskell
unfoldl :: (b -> Maybe (b, a)) -> b -> Seq a
```

It takes a function and a single value of type `b` and returns a sequence of values of type `a`. The function must take a value of type `b` and return either a tuple containing one `b` and one `a` or `Nothing`. `unfoldl` applies the function repeatedly to the initial value, taking the first element of the tuple as the new value and saving off the second tuple elements as the sequence. It stops when it gets `Nothing` instead of a tuple.

In our case, both types are `Int`. We want the first element of the tuple to be the input int-divided by 2, and the second element to be the input mod 2. Conveniently, Haskell has a `divMod` function that returns exactly the tuple we want. Thus, our binary converter is just

```haskell
unfoldl d
```

where `d` is a function that stops when it hits `0`:

```haskell
d 0 = Nothing
```

and otherwise returns the result of `divMod` wrapped in a `Maybe`:

```haskell
d n = Just (divMod n 2)
```

Comment: Another way to do it in [62 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8GCpaUlaboWNx0ycwvyi0oUXBJLEvWCUwtLU_OSU7lSFPJs04ryc30yi0uiUzLLfPOBIgpGNXl2BrGK9gZcSbaleWn5OSk5CikQc7bmJmbmKdgqFBRl5pUoqCgkKRgaGZtA5GB2AQA)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 9 bytes

```r
intToBits
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhYrM_NKQvKdMkuKIfw9aRoGmlxpGoYgwgTMgvCNjE00IUoWLIDQAA)

Outputs as little-endian with trailing zeros.

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 18 bytes

```r
\(n)n%/%2^(n:0)%%2
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhabYjTyNPNU9VWN4jTyrAw0VVWNIBJ70jQMNLnSNAxBhAmYBeEbGZtoQpQsWAChAQ)

Outputs as big-endian (standard convention) with possibly a lot of leading zeros.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), 40 bytes

```
{(<>)<>({<({}[()])><>[(()[{}])]()<>})}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v@/WsPGTtPGTqPaRqO6NlpDM1bTzsYuWkNDM7q6NlYzVgMoV6tZa2P3//9/Q3MA)

The other Brain-flak answer looked very long.

## Explanation

The first thing we can notice is that the following snippet:

```
(()[{}])
```

does something very nice. It's equivalent to `1-x`, which when constrained to the inputs of `0` and `1` will give us an increment and mod 2 operation.  So we can calculate the mod 2 of a number by just repeating this snippet that many times starting with `0`.

```
{({}[()])<>(()[{}])<>}
```

This is nice and it can be modified to give us the full `divmod`. Each cycle we add the value of the accumulator we are building. Since it is `1` half the time and `0` the other half this gives us half the value.  The one issue is it rounds up instead of down, so instead of adding `n` each step we add `1-n`.  That is we add 1 when the accumulator is 0 and 0 when the accumulator is 1.

```
({<({}[()])><>[(()[{}])]()<>})
```

Now we add a bit of code to add a new accumulator each step and we can just repeat this divmod process until the div is zero.

```
{(<>)<>({<({}[()])><>[(()[{}])]()<>})}<>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 18 bytes

```java
n->n.toString(n,2)
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY6xCoMwFEV3v@LhlKCGap0q7d6hLh3FIY1RYvUpJlqK@O02VpcHj3su59Z84kFdvFfRcK3hwRXODoBCI4eSCwnp9gI8zaCwAkHuNqnkAEgTGyyOPdpwowSkgHCFFYMbMtPtBYJ@RNdko/rx1VjqgKdOFdBaG9nBLOd0N5XdQKwe1AXlZxuS5XPshyc/jM7xQv@M3fPVRrasGw3rbd80SJTnXsD1kAmi6LFuWX8)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->               // Method with Integer parameter and String return-type
  n.toString(n,2) //  Convert and return the given Integer as base-2 String
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 3 bytes

```
⍘Ｎ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMpsTg1uATITNfwzCsoLfErzU1KLdLQ1FEw0tS0/v/fyPC/blkOAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 Ｎ  Input as a number
⍘   Convert to base as a string
  ² Literal integer `2`
    Implicitly print
```

16 bytes without base conversion builtins:

```
Ｐ0ＮθＷθ«←§01θ≧÷²θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@3NKcks6AoM69EQ8lASdOayzOvoLTErzQ3KbVIoxDIL8/IzElVADIVqrk4A8AKrXxS00p0FBxLPPNSUiuA@gyVdBQKNYGKOX0TCxyLizPT84Iy0zNKNDzzSlwyyzJTUnUUjEBKrLlq//83MvyvW5YDAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｐ0
```

Output `0` by default (not strictly necessary according to the question definition but the builtin version does this).

```
Ｎθ
```

Input the integer.

```
Ｗθ«
```

Repeat until it is zero.

```
←§01θ
```

Output the least significant bit of the integer, moving right-to-left. (`←Ｉ﹪θ²` would also work for the same byte count.)

```
≧÷²θ
```

Integer divide the integer by 2.

Comment: I love the right-to-left printing and overwriting the initial `0`! A very Charcoal-esque approach.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 23 bytes

```
.+
$*
+`(1+)\1
$+0
01
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX0@bS0WLSztBw1BbM8aQS0XbgMvAkMvw/38TLkMDLkMjYxMA) Link includes test cases. Code is taken from the Retina 0.8.2 unary arithmetic tutorial for decimal to unary and unary to binary, except that for decimal to unary, the input is assumed to be decimal, so `.` is used instead of `\d`, and for unary to binary, `${1}` is golfed to `$+`.

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 24 bytes

```cs
x=>Convert.ToString(x,2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY29DoIwFIV3nuLGqQ1IBJ1EWEycNDHBxME41FrwJtCatiCG8OxYiGc5w3d@uFlypcXYGJQl5F9jRZ14vGLGwFmrUrO69wDezaNCDsYy66xV@IQTQ0moYxOfdGgk36G0gYtpt5ZBASmMXZrtlWyFtuFF5TMhXRDTMfHmYuHuGX@RlmlAQAlSfG536DdBtAqieL0Z6P/AzRhVifCq0YojSkHQX2xh4RcEKU1cavCG8Qc)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-n`, 8 bytes

```ruby
p"%b"%$_
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpclm0km6eUuyiNNulpSVpuhYrCpRUk5RUVeIh3AVQaqUJl6EBl6GRsQlEAAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 4 bytes

```
2o?p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/98o377g/39DI2MTAA)

Answer (score 2):

### Scala, 16 bytes

```scala
_.toBinaryString
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##JYw9C8IwFEX3/opL6ZCCih@dhBZ0c3Gpu8T6qpHwGpuHWEp@e2xxOMs9l@MbbXXsbi9qBBfyAvoK8d3j4BzGRAZHOKPEiQVlhVp6w4/koy3a/SzidSXd0bDuh7@LNb1VscBmPbHdFTnarifdPDHC8Nxw000sK59m07CskI2tMpyHNEdIQvwB)
I took some inspiration from the [Java solution's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/258416/85111) boilerplate to hide the type inference elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 3 bytes

```
TBa
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJUQmEiLCIiLCI0IiwiIl0=)

Builtin that converts to binary (TB). `a` is the input integer

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 22 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>n?f(n/2|0)+n%2:""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbP1i7PPk0jT9@oxkBTO0/VyEpJ6X9yfl5xiUJJanFJsYKtQrShgY6CMRCbG@koGBoAGYamZrFcaflFChoQlXkK@WkQ5ZoKIJH8nFS9nPx0jQSV6rzaBL2CxBTXvBQNY00dBaVHbZOUdBSAFmpq/gcA)

Not quite as short as the builtin but wanted to get a short solution doing it more manually. This solution recursively divides `n` by 2 and prepends the remainder.

Explanation:

```javascript
f = n =>          // define f with arg n
  n               // is n nonzero?
   ?              // yes ->
     f(           //   recurse with
       n / 2 |0   //     divide by 2 and floor result
     ) + n % 2    //   append remainder (0 or 1)
   : ""           // no -> empty string is prepended to coerce everything
```

Figured this out from reading wikiHow to convert decimal to binary lol

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 6 bytes

```php
decbin
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwMWlkmb7PyU1OSkz7781F1dqcka@gkqahommnlJMnpK1AhDo6xsaGMBlDA0QUiAZQyQpI2O4PrAmQ5A0EP0HAA)

No PHP answer yet? Surprisingly competitive this time!!!

Answer (score 2):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 25 bytes

```
/O \v$.:2[!<
@Mq/>.2%'0+^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/1/fXyGmTEXPyiha0YbLwbdQ307PSFXdQDvu////hkbGJgA)

This explanation below are still valid, I just reorganised the flow to save two bytes

```
/ M \w.2%'0+![2:.$K/ q O @   Full program (includes a new line)
/ M \                        Reads the argument
     w          .$K          Main loop
      .2%                    Gets the modulus by two of the number
         '0+![               Store the modulus + the char code of 0 to the tape
              2:             Divide the number by 2
                   / q O @   Join the tape, output and exit
```

Answer (score 2):

### Befunge-93, 27 Bytes

```
v
2:._@#<-
&
<_!#: ^#/2\%2:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1NNYtqAQz//8v4zKy0ot3ULbR5VLjsolXVLZSiFPWN4pRNbL6/9/Q1MzCxNDSwtAYSFsaWpgC2abGJhZcAA)

Alternately the following works as long as 0/0 results in a non-zero value pushed onto the stack (this is an option of PyFunge and the default behavior of [this](http://qiao.github.io/javascript-playground/visual-befunge93-interpreter/) compiler online

```
v
2:._@#<-
&
<_  :/^#2\%2:
```

This results in only needing 26 bytes

This is my first post and so if anyone has comments of how I can improve this post feel free to let me know

Answer (score 2):

## Swift, <s>35</s> 28 bytes

```swift
let b={String($0+0,radix:2)}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 13 bytes

```perl
printf"%b",<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvJE1JNUlJx8bu/39DUxNTs3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA0A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 29 bytes

```
?
~:"" 2%!@
 _ ( _ "
 2/);(""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/fnqvOSklJwUhV0YFLIV5BA4iVuBSM9DWtNZSU/v83NDD4l19QkpmfV/xfNwUA)

Handling zero input is nontrivial since loops in Labyrinth require a nonzero value at entry. To remedy this, the code uses bitwise NOT of the input value and repeatedly divides it by 2, which is floor division and therefore equivalent to arithmetic right shift. The loop is exited when the top reaches -1, and it runs at least once to ensure that the second loop is also entered with a nonzero value. As a result, the input of 0 outputs `0`.

```
Entry   ?~
?       Take input  [n]
~       Bitwise NOT [~n]

Loop 1  :_2/)(  [~n ~n/2 .. ~n/2^i] -> [~n .. ~n/2^(i+1)]
:_2/    Copy and divide by 2
)       Test if the top is -1; exit if so
(       Revert the value to continue the loop

Path    ;  [~n ~n/2 .. ~n/2^i 0] -> [~n ~n/2 .. ~n/2^i]
;       Drop the unnecessary zero

Loop 2  (_2%!  [~n ~n/2 .. ~n/2^i] -> [~n .. ~n/2^(i-1)]
(       Invert the parity of the top
        (decrement is chosen to ensure the top is nonzero)
_2%!    Mod 2 and print
        Exit the loop if there is nothing more to print

End     @
@       Halt
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 19 bytes

```python
lambda n:bin(n)[2:]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 1 [byte](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
à
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///wgv//TbgMDbgMjYxNAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
à  # Convert the (implicit) input-integer to a binary-string
   # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Irrelevant note: `â` (convert to a binary-list) isn't an equal-byte alternative, since it (for whatever reason) outputs [in reversed order](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///wov//TbgMDbgMjYxNAA).

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 18 bytes

```
#~IntegerString~2&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X7nOM68kNT21KLikKDMvvc5I7X8AkFGioO@Qru9QbaJjaKBjaGRsUvv/PwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 1 byte

```
ḃ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3w/@GO5v//o010FAwNgNjI2CQWAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 1 byte

```
ɓ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//5OT//wE)

Built-ins ftw

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 4 bytes

```
>bin
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQm1iSoVeQWFScWqSQma9gzcVlZPbfLikz739BUWZeyX8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 15 bytes

```arturo
$=>[as.binary&]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?rZQwan)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 1 [byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
¤
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=pA&input=WzQsMTAsMTIzNF0tbVE)

Shortcut for `s2`  which converts a number to a `s`tring in base `2`

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 11 bytes

```
=BASE(A1,2)
```

Straightforward built-in. Input is in the cell `A1` and can be anything from 0 to 2<sup>53</sup>-1. Formula goes in any other cell in the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

## [GeoGebra](https://geogebra.org/calculator), 23 bytes

```
a
InputBox(a
ToBase(a,2
```

[Try It On GeoGebra!](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/vgbcyt5v)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL(Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <s>9</s> 1 byte <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
⊤
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=e9S1BAA&f=AwA&i=S1Mw4UpTMDQAEUbGJgA&r=tio&l=apl-dyalog-extended&m=train&n=f)

Literally a builtin... What more can I say?

Answer (score 1):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 6 bytes

```
binary
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWy5Iy8xKLKiGcm_qJBQU5lRp5Crp2CgVFmXklQKYSiKOkkKaRp6mpoxBtoqNgaADERsYmsZoQbQsWQGgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 70 bytes

```
	I =INPUT
N	O =REMDR(I,2) O GT(I)	:F(O)
	I =I / 2	:(N)
O	OUTPUT =O
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9NTwdbTLyA0hMuP01/BNsjV1yVIw1PHSFPBX8E9RMNTk9PKTcNfkwusTkFfwYjTSsNPk8uf0z80BKhLwdafy9XP5f9/QyNjEwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```
B
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/p////hkbGJgA)

Lmao my first answer in Jelly. Just a builtin.

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 2 bytes

```
Yb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1f/T8y6X@tVZB1tImCoYGCoZGxSWx1fJCSgq6dglKMtnatqp/WfwA)

Link includes test cases

## Explanation

```
 b # Convert to base
Y  # builtin *2*
```

For fun, here's one which pads to 16 bits:

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 6 bytes

```
YbGTe[
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1f/T8yyT0kNfp/rVWQdbSJgqGBgqGRsUlsdXyQkoKunYJSjLZ2raqf1n8A)

## Explanation

```
 b    # Convert to base
Y     # builtin *2*
   e[ # and pad to length
 G    # builtin *16*
      # with
  T   # zeroes
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Simply](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/simply), 17 bytes

The code simply creates an anonymous arrow function that calls the `&tb` function, and returns the result.

```
fn($x)=>&tb($x 2)
```

To use this function, assign it to a variable and call it:

```
$fn = fn($x)=>&tb($x 2)

echo call $fn(5);
```

---

### What does `&tb` do?

The function `&tb` is a built-in alias to `&tobase`.

This is the result of running `echo &doc(&tobase);`:

```
Documentation for tobase:
Converts the integer $number to the $base.
The $base must be between 1 and 36, otherwise, returns null.
E.g.: tobase(10, 10) = "10", tobase(10, 2) = "1010", tobase(10, 1) = "1111111111".
```

---

### Ungolfed

You can rewrite the code like this:

```
Set the variable $fn to an anonymous function with the argument $number.
Begin.
    Return the result of calling the function &tobase with the arguments $number and 2;
End.
```

Or, if you want it to be more code-like:

```
$fn = anonymous function($number) {
    return &tobase($number, 2);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang) (v2), 29 bytes

```
;=a@;=n*2P;W=n/n 2=a+,%n 2aOa
```

[Try it online!](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/#WyI7PWFAOz1uKjJQO1c9bi9uIDI9YSssJW4gMmFPYSIsIjEyMzQiLCIyLjAiXQ==)

Zero outputs nothing, which is allowed in the rules.

Answer (score 1):

## J 2 bytes

```
#:
```

Some test cases:

```
   #:12345

1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1

   #:33

1 0 0 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## Raku, 8 bytes

```
.base(2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n5ZfpJCTmZdafGi3nl9prkK1QnFi5X@9pMTiVA0jzf@1/024DA24DI2MTQAt)

The above version operates on the current topic, as seen in the demo code. To make it a function accepting an argument, just wrap it in curly braces for another two bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 1 [byte](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ḃ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWix_uaF5SnJRcDOUvWGJoZGwCYQMA)

Comment: almost polyglots with Vyxal. Vyxal uses a b without the dot above.

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 13 bytes

```sh
<<<$[[##2]$1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn938bGRiU6WlnZKFbFMPZ/LVeaggkQGxqACCNjMNvY2BxEmRlbmPwHAA)

Vanilla answer... here are a couple more [interesting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/261370/15940) [variants](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216725/15940)

Answer (score 1):

## [ForWhile](https://esolangs.org/wiki/ForWhile), 25 bytes

`{:[:1&'2/0@1+0$:)@[48+#)}`

Takes argument from the stack and prints to console

[online interpreter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=forwhile&src=ezpbOjEmJzIvMEAxKzAkOilAWzQ4KyMpfQoxJAo0MiAxQD8=)

## Explanation

```
{                       }  \ anonymous procedure
 :[                        \ repeat n times
   :1&                     \ push the lowest bit of n
      '2/                  \ divide n by 2
         0@1+0$            \ increment memory cell 0
               :)          \ break loop if n is zero
                 @         \ read memory at address 0 (n is still on stack)
                  [48+#)   \ print bits converted to characters
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org), 9 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__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-KXv-KBv-KCmeKGp-KGpeKIoOKEguKnu-KWs-KHoeKKouKHjOKZrcKk4ouv4o2J4o2P4o2W4oqa4oqb4oqd4pe04pew4pah4ouV4omN4oqf4oqC4oqP4oqh4oav4piH4oaZ4oaY4oa74per4pa94oyV4oiK4oqX4oin4oi14omh4oqe4oqg4o2l4oqV4oqc4oqQ4ouF4oqZ4oipwrDijIXijZziioPiqr7iipPii5TijaLirJrijaPijaTihqzihqvimoLOt8-Az4TiiJ7iuK7ihpAiCgojIEFsbCBjaGFyYWN0ZXJzIFVpdWEgdXNlcyBmb3IgcHJldHR5LXByaW50aW5nLgojIENhbiBiZSByZW1vdmVkIGlmIG5lY2Vzc2FyeS4KCkRSQVdJTkcg4oaQICLila3ilIDilbfila_in6bin6fijJzijJ_ilZPilZ_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-KHoTPil4viiKkow7cyNSnih6EyNDDih6E4MCIKIyBFbmNvZGUgdG8gYSAuc2JjcyBmaWxlOgojICAgRW5jb2RlVUEgUGF0aFVBCiMgRGVjb2RlIGEgLnNiY3MgZmlsZToKIyAgIERlY29kZVNCQ1MgUGF0aFNCQ1MK)</sup>

```
&pf⇌⋯⋕&sc
```

[Try it online!](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__JnDih4zii6_ii5Umc2MK) Outputs as a list of bits.

### Explanation

```
&pf⇌⋯⋕&sc
      &sc # read line from stdin
     ⋕    # parse string as number
    ⋯     # encode number as bit array, LSB-first
   ⇌      # reverse array
&pf       # print to stdout
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 1.5 bytes

```
``@
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWixMSHCAsqMCClSZchgZchkbGJhABAA)

Built-in.

Answer (score 0):

## [Risky](https://github.com/Radvylf/risky), 1.5 bytes

```
?}2
```

[Try it online!](https://radvylf.github.io/risky?p=WyI_fTIiLCJbMTIzNF0iLDBd)

```
?}2
 }  Convert
?   input
 }  to base
  2 2
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/), 45 bytes

```
import strformat
func b(n:int):auto= &"{n:b}"
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704LzN3wYKlpSVpuhY3dTNzC_KLShSKS4rS8otyE0u40krzkhWSNPKsMvNKNK0SS0vybRXUlKrzrJJqlaCaFFOTM_KBakw0uaAsQwME08jYRBOiEGYLAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [flax](https://github.com/PyGamer0/flax), 1 byte

```
B
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLSexYsGCpaUlaboWC52WFCclF0N5y6INjYxNYqE8AA)

Builtin

Answer (score 0):

### [vemf](https://github.com/selaere/vemf), 1 byte

```
é
```

Represents α as a 64-element list of bits.

Answer (score 0):

## [YASEPL](https://github.com/madeforlosers/YASEPL-esolang/), 76 bytes

```
=d'(=y)""`9!m$d%!yſm!d/(}7,0,9=o-!h)""!u®"y"-=k$u`8!m¥u,"y"!hſm!u-}1,o,8>h
```

YASEPL is a (horribly coded and just stupid in general) esolang I made a while ago in Node.JS. it gets input via a prompt and STDIN. heres the output:

[image: a picture containing the output of the code I just put.]

Answer (score 0):

## [*><>](https://github.com/redstarcoder/go-starfish), 14 bytes

Input is passed in through the `-i` flag.

```
:2%:n-2,:0)?!;
```

```
:               Duplicate the value on the stack
 2              Push 2 onto the stack
  %             Modulo those two
   :            Duplicate the result
    n           Pop and print that duplicate
     -          Subtract the result from our original number
      2         Push 2
       ,        Divide the two
        :       Duplicate that result
         0      Push 0
          )?!;  If the dividend is greater than 0, loop again
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JLErLLM74/9/KSNUqT9dIx8pA017R@v//f/kFJZn5ecX/dTP/G5oDAA)

Comment: I just realized my output is in reverse  If anyone has any ideas on how to get it in the correct order, I'd appreciate it