# Prime decimal representations of prime binary numbers

Tags: code-golf, primes

**Problem Statement**: Consider a number `n` in base-10. Find the smallest base-10 integer `i` greater than `n`, such that both the decimal and binary representations of `i` are prime (when viewed in decimal).

---

**Input**: a number in decimal 
**Output**: The smallest base-10 number greater than `n`, which when viewed in both binary and decimal, is prime.

---

**Examples**: 
*Input*:

- 1
- 3
- 100
- 1234567

*Output*:

- 3
- 5
- 101
- 1234721

*Explanations*:

- 3 is prime. 3 in binary is 11, which is also prime. 3 is the smallest number larger than 1 which satisfies these properties.
- 5 is prime. 5 in binary is 101, which is also prime. 5 is the smallest number larger than 3 which satisfies these properties.
- 101 is prime. 101 in binary is 1100101, which is also prime. 101 is the smallest number larger than 100 which satisfies these properties.
- 1234721 is prime. 1234721 in binary is 100101101011100100001, which is also prime. 1234721 is the smallest number larger than 1234567 which satisfies these properties.

---

Here are your test cases, ordered in ascending difficulty according to my own naive implementation. Please include a [Try it online!](https://tio.run) in your answer:

*Input*:

- `n = 1325584480535587277061226381983816`, a.k.a. `(((((((1 + 2) * 3) ** 4) + 5) * 6) ** 7) + 8) * 9`
- `n = 1797010299914431210413179829509605039731475627537851106401`, a.k.a `((3^4)^5)^6`
- `n = 2601281349055093346554910065262730566475782`, a.k.a `0^0 + 1^1 + 2^2 + ... + 28^28 + 29^29`
- `n = 20935051082417771847631371547939998232420940314`, a.k.a. `0! + 1! + ... + 38! + 39!`
- `n = 123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930`

*Output*:

- `1325584480535587277061226381986899`
- `1797010299914431210413179829509605039731475627537851115949`
- `2601281349055093346554910065262730566501899`
- `20935051082417771847631371547939998232420981273`
- `123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627319639`

If you manage to get the correct outputs for these 5 test cases in under 3 seconds total, your code can be considered. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: The input has an upper bound of 10,000, but the code also has to be able to solve a test case 10^53 times larger than that? Does that mean a solution that uses 32-bit integers and perfectly handles inputs less than 10,000 is invalid?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think the time requirement for numbers of that size is going to disqualify any languages without a primality builtin.

Comment: @water_ghosts Sorry, I was making this question earlier today and forget what I was doing... I'll fix it. A few hours ago I was just putting in a placeholder in my question for test cases I had yet to generate. I forgot to change that arbitrary limit of `n`.

Comment: @Sisyphus. Okay, what do you suggest I change the time limit to? Thanks.

Comment: @RyanRudes if it were me, I would just remove the time limit entirely. What is your intention behind the time limit?

Comment: @Sisyphus I suppose your right, there are no actual intentions that effect this contest. I'll just remove it.

Comment: @water_ghosts Alright, but then I'd have to come up with smaller test cases then, wouldn't I? Or are the test cases just a suggestion and anything that can be proven to work is fine? I'm new to code golf, so I'm not sure how they typically view the test cases.

Comment: VTC as duplicate of just about every prime question on the board.   [Is this number a prime?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57617/is-this-number-a-prime)   It's really just testing if two numbers are both prime with a binary conversion in the middle. It's not that interesting and has been overdone on CGCC.

Comment: @Xcali I was influenced to remove the time limit. If I hadn’t, it would be a bit more due to necessary optimization. So I guess you are partially correct.

Comment: @RyanRudes In case you didn't know, it's preferred that challenge ideas go through the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) first so you can get feedback before they go live. (Don't interpret this as a direct comment on the current challenge; it's just for future reference.)

Comment: @Xcali Oh! This is actually quite helpful. Thanks.

Comment: ... are you actually going to remove the time limit?

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

I saw in the comments that you may remove the time limit, so **consider this as an answer only in case you are removing the time limit**, since it times out even for `1234567`.

```
[ÅNDbp#
```

Explanation:

```
[ÅNDbp#
           Input is at the top of the stack
[          Infinite loop
 ÅN        Next prime
   D       Duplicate that
    b      Binary representation
     p     Is it a prime number?
      #    Break the loop if it is, printing the top of the stuck, which is the next number that match both conditions.
```

[Try on online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/@nCrn0tSgfL//4YGBgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
‘ÆnBḌẒ¬Ʋ¿
```

A monadic Link accepting an integer, `n`, that yields a list conting just one element, the next prime above `n` which is prime and has a decimal-read binary representation which is prime.

As a full program the integer is implicitly printed to STDOUT.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9qZWxsef//4oCYw4ZuQuG4jOG6ksKsxrLCv////zEyMzQ1Njc)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##PY8rTgNgEISv0gNU7Ox7LXfBkAZf1yDAoFAcogpFMCRt0nu0F/mZVGA2m803OzNPj7vdfq3b4fP8@vxw/X6//nycjpev0@86v91ejmthu7HtBiIcah5ZXEwj2r0ljEtplSRU0xrTHEmmpgSiMwN3g0IcxmvrhExKiE0ZvCK1wqoDkHShoaZAG@YjQdbMM8KHITKUtElkUlithAmEBKTVUVVorzRYIbzG6N9q6sRcaPdfo/kPYC4eEUhQiVFRFrkL7lbKuCZ/).

#### How?

```
‘ÆnBḌẒ¬Ʋ¿ - Link: n
‘         - increment n -> k=n+1
        ¿ - while...
       Ʋ  - ...condition: last four links as a monad - f(k):
   B      -      int to binary list
    Ḍ     -      decimal list to int
     Ẓ    -      is prime?
      ¬   -      NOT
 Æn       - ...do: (k=) next prime
          - yield k
```

Answer (score 0):

## [SageMath](https://doc.sagemath.org/), 61 bytes

```sagemath
f=lambda n,p=is_prime:p(n+1)and p(f'{n+1:b}')and n+1or f(n+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJydU9uK3DAMfc9X-C0JTYsulmUPpD_SljI7k0BgJxMSL7Qd5t-rZFkI04dua7CRben46Fjq2-fj5el8dGMztcPyfZqHS3eYqvED1sfx7KaqL2-2OTzdy-3A7Ovs-s2hyN2SF9e6ChvHjUMAW4i9BG0K9zaQSSR6H0HYDCVVCEgUOGKKtoS9syYFBEopofeMhOCR7TRSEkgBBDgpo1cJpMIaBRGCB9yBUACkiOwTiAUx-yDik_ELQhbGICEYgkbaR5mngCBE8qiqGL0GRlYUr4mNUSQmb24ejMCe9GvO0V5ANMp2i4IBDQITAVmyW-T2OFkmDHXR_Zi6U-7Oq34mnqz64at-Svts_iphiCk9-P-PiijJP-C8S0gB_IPA-7WMaDAP7P9FTsYUONXFvOpYfn0h9afSbQZyWRfDZbrO2S0_l8Lmp6XLc3d6mZfhOj4PlyFXlsw66qK3ws5N54bR_Rqmaivuxr19U33YOK7l3le53jbWLWNeOyTf3cfP7rbc3W3-srRt983a5TdUXbvi&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 68 bytes

```
(t=NextPrime)[#//.x_/;!PrimeQ@FromDigits@IntegerDigits[t@x,2]:>x+1]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X6PE1i@1oiSgKDM3VTNaWV9fryJe31oRzA90cCvKz3XJTM8sKXbwzCtJTU8tgvCiSxwqdIxirewqtA1j1f4DVeeVKDikRxsaG5maWpiYWBiYGgMZ5kbm5gZmhkZGZsYWhpYWQMIs9v9/AA)

Answer (score -1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) (145 bytes)

I am the author of this question; this is a non-golfed example if anyone doesn't understand the task. You don't need to upvote this.

```python
from sympy import isprime
for case in range(5):
  n = int(input())
  i = n + 1
  while True:
    if isprime(int(bin(i)[2:])) and isprime(i):
      print (i)
      break
    i += 1
```

It runs in approx. 2.79 seconds on [Try on online!](https://tio.run/##RU/NTsMwDL73KXxstYt/4jiZtLfghjh00EEETauuE9rTF28DcYns79eZr@vHVGXbTss0wvk6zlco4zwtK5TzvJRxaE7TAq/9eYBSYenr@9Bqt28AKhwcWttS58vadp1DxaEKOyCfvz/K1wBPy2W4iZ07/SW2N9ex1LZ0z7x/6Tro69s/2T30AL7XFRz43Y/L0H8@smB3ANo2ElZNISRU8cHYDCMxR0mUkz@xIcuGhJxzphCEmDCQOJo4K@aIipJNKJhGNhVLSoQxIDUckTiRhIzqUpEQVUMmxKjsYkGN0X2WuGHnFZUwcSAzoxQsComRBsvi7YmFg8sCellDLEGjJU8j8qMcI6VIbqTMyP6Ju/5exH6r4A8)

Comment: Runs much faster if one tests the smaller number first, [TIO](https://tio.run/##RY89bsMwDIV3n4KjjSz8EUUpQG7RrejgtE4jtJYNx0GR07ts0qKLQH58fI@ab@t5qrJtp2Ua4XIb5xuUcZ6WFcplXso4NKdpgdf@MkCpsPT1fWi12zcAFQ6O1rbU@bq2XeeoOKqwA/L661w@B3harsOP2GenP8e2dNDXt//WTY6lOn7m/UvXPfQAPq0rOP7tj8vQfzy8YHcA2jYSVk0hJFTxwtgMIzFHSZSTP7Ehy4aEnHOmEISYMJA4TZwVc0RFySYUTCObiiUlwhiQGo5InEhCRnWpSIiqIRNiVHaxoMboe5a4YZ8rKmHiQGZGKVgUEiMNlsXTEwsHlwX0sIZYgkZL7kbkRzkjpUi@SJmR/RN3/T2I/VbBbw)

Comment: If it is non-golfed, then it would be better to put it in the question body as a reference instead. Answers should make an attempt at the winning criteria