# The Most Wanted Prime Numbers

Tags: code-golf, sequence, primes

Output a sequence of all the primes that are of the following form:
`123...91011...(n-1)n(n-1)..11109...321`. That is, ascending decimal numbers up to some `n`, followed by a descending tail, all concatenated.

### Background

Recently, Numberphile [posted a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKlVNFOHJ9I) about primes that follow this pattern.

### Output

```
1 -> 12345678910987654321 (n=10)
2 -> 123...244524462445...321 (n=2446)
```

No more terms are known, but it's likely that there are infinitely many.

Comment: In other words, the subsequnce of [A173426](https://oeis.org/A173426) filtered by primality.

Comment: Two questions:
1. Is the output format flexible?
2. Is a probabilistic primality test ok, or is a deterministic test required?

Comment: @cubiclettuce Use standard sequence output formats (click the tag for more info). I'd say that a deterministic test is required.

Answer (score 12):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
∞η€ûJʒp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8c9sfNa05vNvr1KSC//8B) Times out on TIO without printing a single number because the [primality test](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/f34df35b53d2b8d82c7e8132fe0f03c72107598d/lib/commands/int_commands.ex#L196) is too slow. Takes 77 seconds locally for the first number and will never† get to the second number.

```
∞η       Prefixes of [1, 2, 3, ...]
  €û     Palindromize each prefix
    J    Join each into a number
     ʒp  Filter: keep primes
```

Local output:

```
05AB1E git:master ❯ ./osabie programs/mwp.abe
["12345678910987654321"
```

† in the lifetime of the universe, the test is \$\mathcal{O(\sqrt{n} \log{}n})\$.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
ŒḄV©ẒƊ#®
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARsA5P9qZWxsef//xZLhuIRWwqnhupLGiiPCrv///zE)

By [default sequence I/O rules](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/sequence/info), this inputs a value `k` and outputs the prime corresponding to `k`.

This is a monadic link `f(k)` that returns the prime. It also outputs the `n` value for that prime as a side effect - this should be considered a function that returns the prime. I've included a 9 byte version that doesn't output anything extra below.

```
ŒḄV©ẒƊ#ṛ®
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9qZWxsef//xZLhuIRWwqnhupLGiiPhuZvCrv//MQ)

---

Both can handle \$k = 1\$ on TIO, can't handle \$k = 2\$ or above.

### How they work

```
ŒḄV©ẒƊ#® - Main link. Takes k on the left
     Ɗ#  - Find the first n such that the following is true:
ŒḄ       -   Bounced range of n; [1, 2, ..., n, ..., 2, 1]
  V      -   Evaluated as an integer: 12...n...21
   ©     -   Save this in the register
    Ẓ    -   Is this prime?
       ® - Print n and return the register
```

The second uses `ṛ®` instead of `®`. The `ṛ` causes the program to discard the value of `n` rather than printing it, and then `®` returns the register.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 213 bytes

```python
def A(n):return int(''.join(str(d)for d in range(1,n+1))+''.join(str(d)for d in range(n-1,0,-1)))
i=5
w=0
y=int(input())
while 1:
	p=n=1;exec("p*=n*n;n+=1;"*~-A(i))
	if p%n==1:w+=1
	if w==y:print(A(i));break
	i+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYxLDoIwFEXHdhUNieGVj6ExTkregKWgFKmaR1NLKhO3XgsLcHjPPTl29dNM5xgHPfIOSCin/eKIG/KQ56fHbAje3sEgxtnxIXHuerprkBWVUojyr0S1rJqqTp5gBi8sYMNW3NqG7OIh4TCZl@ZSsYNFQtnqj75BZgukgloqE8mKb92BSe7BjNweCVGqkJ59B8RVWbc1d6m9Ot0/05WEGOUP)

Probably should be correct. If you find bugs then comment the answer.

Upvote [Lynn solution of prime checking](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/57682/106959)!

Comment: I may be misunderstanding something, but where is `i` updated? It seems that we will always print `A(5)`...

Comment: no, infinite loop because the i don't increment.

Answer (score 0):

Here I used the Miller-Rabin Primality Test to approximate if the number is in fact prime.

```
import math
import random

def miller_rabin(n, k):

    # Implementation uses the Miller-Rabin Primality Test
    # The optimal number of rounds for this test is 40
    # See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325576/how-many-iterations-of-rabin-miller-should-i-use-for-cryptographic-safe-primes
    # for justification

    # If number is even, it's a composite number

    if n == 2 or n == 3:
        return True

    if n % 2 == 0:
        return False

    r, s = 0, n - 1
    while s % 2 == 0:
        r += 1
        s //= 2
    for _ in range(k):
        a = random.randrange(2, n - 1)
        x = pow(a, s, n)
        if x == 1 or x == n - 1:
            continue
        for _ in range(r - 1):
            print(_)
            x = pow(x, 2, n)
            if x == n - 1:
                break
        else:
            return False
    return True

def constructNumber(n):
    numberArray = []
    for i in range(n):
        numberArray.append(str(i+1))
    for i in range(n-1):
        numberArray.append(str((n-1)-i))
    return int(''.join(numberArray))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(miller_rabin((constructNumber(10)),40))
```

[Miller-Rabin Python Source](https://gist.github.com/Ayrx/5884790)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! This site is for competitive programming, so we require answers to make a serious attempt at golfing. Make sure to read our [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips?tab=Votes) questions if you want some hints! Also, since this only seems to approximate whether a number is prime, it's wouldn't be valid (it's cool though!).